# An apology to our community, and next steps

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, moderation, code-of-conduct

*I’m David Fullerton, Stack Overflow’s CTO, responsible for the product, engineering, and community teams.*

I joined Stack Overflow in 2010 because I believed in the vision and mission of Stack Overflow. I wanted to be a part of building a community where programmers come together to help one another learn and share their knowledge with one another. I loved how the site was run in the open, in collaboration with its community, and moderated by members of the community.

I’m here nearly a decade later because I believe we can continue to build this community together and make it an even more welcoming and inclusive place than it is today.

In the last few weeks, we made a series of mistakes, both in our actions and in the ways that we communicated those actions. In doing so, we hurt people who believe in that mission and who want to help us make the community welcoming and open to all. While Sara and others were on the front lines of that, I was personally involved at each step along the way and ultimately responsible, and I’m deeply sorry for the hurt that we’ve caused.

First of all, we hurt members of our LGBTQ+ community when they felt they couldn’t participate authentically and we didn’t respond quickly or strongly enough in supporting them. Worse, through our handling of this situation, we made them a target for harassment as people debated their right to express themselves and be addressed according to how they identify.

I am responsible for that, and I am deeply sorry. We absolutely support the LGBTQ+ community, and we’re committed to making our community a place that is open and welcoming to everyone. We’re working on an update to our Code of Conduct which we’re sharing with moderators for feedback tomorrow and the rest of the community later this week. We’ll also work on making more resources and materials available to our moderators to help them support members of the community as we all learn together how to be more welcoming and inclusive.

Second, we hurt a longstanding member of the community and an important volunteer moderator. She deserved the benefit of a private, comprehensive process. In the absence of a clear process for handling this kind of situation, we should have taken inspiration from our existing [Moderator Action Review Process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/146719). We made a decision to act quickly, which I personally approved, but in doing so skipped several critical parts of the process. In acting quickly, we also acted at a time which coincided with a Jewish holiday which she and many other members of our community observe, and we should have taken that more into account in the process.

I’m responsible for that, and I’m sorry. We’ll be reaching out to her directly to apologize for the lack of process, privacy, and to discuss next steps. We’ll keep those discussions completely private unless we both agree to share any of it with the community.

We’ll be sharing with our moderators this week our proposed processes for handling situations like this in the future. This includes a process for handling moderator removals, and a process for reinstating moderators who wish to be reinstated.

Third, we hurt the moderators and members of our communities. Community moderation is the backbone of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, and our moderators are a vital part of us creating a more welcoming and inclusive place. We need to be working *with* our moderators and community, rather than working against them, in order to create the kind of community where everyone feels welcome and able to share their knowledge.

I’m responsible for that as well, and I’m sorry for the hurt that we’ve caused. Going forward, we will be working with the community to overhaul how we gather input and feedback from our moderators and members of the community to make sure that your voices are heard and involved in the process, not just informed after decisions have been made.

Finally, I want to apologize again for all of the pain we have caused. I am more committed than ever to creating a welcoming and inclusive community across Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, and the mistakes we made over the past few weeks made that worse, not better. I know we have lost the trust of many of you, and that trust must be re-earned over time by more than just words. That starts this week with some of the concrete steps we are taking with the moderator removal process and the Code of Conduct changes, but the hard work will continue for years. Those first steps are:

- On Monday, October 7, we’ll be sharing a second draft of an update to our Code of Conduct with all moderators for feedback
- On Thursday, October 10, the update to the Code of Conduct will be announced publicly
- By Friday, October 11, we’ll share the processes for moderator removal and reinstatement with moderators for their feedback

Looking forward, Stack Overflow is just beginning this new stage in its growth as a company. One of our top priorities across the entire team is to continue to make the community more inclusive and welcoming.  We recognize that the community is the heartbeat of Stack Overflow, and we deeply appreciate all that you do. We know that our moderators care deeply about the future of our community, and we’re committed to involving you more as we evolve. We have an incredible opportunity to impact the world, and we hope that you will continue to join us on that mission.

Thank you for listening, and thank you for your patience with us as we continue to work our way through this.

*This post was written with the input and support of Sara Chipps, Tim Post, and the community management team.*

---

*[Email was sent to Monica on October 8.](/a/334646)*

Comment: What happened to all the comments?

Comment: @BartSilverstrim Openness happened.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Openness, sure, but don't forget *inclusivity*. It makes people feel included when their comments are deleted.

Comment: Technically, talking about the gradual but steady descent of the question score might have been off-topic. It might have been unique in that it first reached several hundred positive before diving under zero.

Comment: @DavidFullerton did you delete the 115 comments that were here before? Can you comment on why?

Comment: @DavidFullerton: How many downvotes would it take before a message gets through to you guys? Do you have a number in your mind personally? Is it smaller than infinity?

Comment: @Mehrdad You can delete posts and comments and the downvotes never happened! It's great!

Comment: Man, this is going to end up more negative than it ever was positive.

Comment: Those ones who thank this post immediately after it's asked, what do you think now ? It's really ironic !

Comment: This gives a whole new meaning to censored.

Comment: is it time to slowly transition to a new platform? let's not forget that SE does _not_ exist without "us", right? hell, they are not _even_ get paid!

Comment: @DavidFullerton: I use the Internet since 1996 and I've seen many preposterously unjust actions and many preposterously hypocrite "apologies", but this one and Sara Chipp's one are undoubtedly in the Top5. But since I can't help being polite even to people who may or may not deserve it, I'll use the "please" word in << Please, retract this - and reinstate Monica ASAP >>

Comment: @TeemPorary wonder who are the other four in the Top5? Would like to compare what SE did to other cases.

Comment: @Anothervote you mean deleting comments? No it's not. **comments are temporary**. I know and accept this for long years, and fine with it. When comments pile up below a post, it's common to remove them. It's cleanup process, not censorship.

Comment: Notice how this post is now at -134 despite originally having positives in the hundreds. There is a reason for that. You have to actually followup your talk with actions (or, at the very least, more talk). Hopefully it's evident by now that we aren't playing along with this game any longer. Too bad: I was one of those whose now-deleted comments were positive and optimistic and thankful. Way to totally ruin a brief moment of goodwill between us all.

Comment: @Shadow Context matters.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit while I'm also pissed at the lack of response, removing my comments doesn't add any fuel to it. And posting more comments isn't the way to get a response. I believe mods are talking with staff in TL, and at this stage, that's what important. The "Monica Event" is a very strong case and awful mistake, but I no longer think SE as whole need to fall or rise based on a single person and/or mistake.

Comment: @Shadow If you think that SE has only offended one person and/or only made one mistake, you have not been paying attention!

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica I was not unaware of the omissions, but I gave David the benefit of the doubt, hoping to contribute to ending the "cycle of violence". Nothing more, nothing less. Unfortunately, this optimism was not rewarded, as the "missing links" did not follow in subsequent days and weeks.

Comment: @mag I read it very carefully, thank you, at the time, and [said myself that we have a long way to go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334585/155739).

Comment: fair enough @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @Shadow: It's only "temporary" because they say so, not because logically there's any reason it has to be that way. And the ridiculous thing about "comments are temporary" is that they're often overzealous about moving them to chat, where they suddenly become even more *permanent* than posts. But regardless, as mentioned above, context is everything.

Comment: Your site didn't allow me to downvote, but it took my upvote. It's now telling me I can't change it to a downvote unless the question is edited. Ugh.

Comment: Your words still mean nothing, even if you delete mine. Reinstate Monica.

Comment: David has now lost more reputation from this apology than he has gained, which is surely a metaphor for SO during this fiasco with the CoC changes

Comment: @Eugene IANAL but the contents is CC-BY-SA...

Comment: @Dweeberly "discussions" implied actual, you know, collaborative participation.  What I received was one message alleging but not supporting violations but I could apply for reinstatement, and then no further engagement -- no answers to my questions, no discussion, nothing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, I think that's terrible and I find  Mr Fullerton "apology" insincere especially when suggesting discussions will be kept "complete private" when that seems to be part of the problem to start with.  Clearly discussion isn't Mr Fullerton's strong suit.  It is a shame that a site based on open dialog seems to have a CTO opposed to it. You clearly have support and I hope SE will take note.

Comment: Cheap talk, if I ever heard any.

Comment: @JoKing Probably the real reason for the rep recalc.

Comment: @AnothervoteforMonica and anyone who wishes to retract their upvote, there have been edits, please come back and update your vote. :)

Comment: @Eugene check my profile. Slowly but surely.

Comment: It would be great if you would include references to a lot of these claims, even if they're perhaps known to many here (not me). So e.g. who, when, and how did you hurt people of the lgbtq community? What moderators did you hurt and how? etc. Also, (and I'm guessing) making everything more inclusive by including the "right" ppl, excluding the "wrong" ppl, and going along with all this because of current political trends, clearly against the will of the users (who makes this community), is not inclusive in the first place.

Comment: Trust No Company.

Comment: Please drop a note again when the question is edited... thank you.
I'm sincerely sorry I did not check the date and the answers before the initial vote.

Comment: Is there any update on this?

Comment: Apologies are good at making the apologetic person feel like a good guy. Monica is the hero of this story

Comment: By posting that, you guys are digging your own grave

Comment: @rodolphito An "_All-in-one voice and text chat for gamers that's free_" seems not to be a Q&A platform, does it? I'd be thankful for an alternative. ATM, however, I'm not aware of any comparable.

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica yes, it is not. It is the platform where we are coordinating a replacement. You can also check https://forum.codidact.org/

Comment: @rodolphito Perhaps it's a good idea to mention this at the link in your profile and to add a link to the forum there, too. With the current text it seems to be a link to an already existing alternative.

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica done, i had set up that profile before the forums were even started. Was badly out of date.

Comment: Why I down voted: This apology seems insincere, late, and sometimes a "oops, sorry" just is not good enough. Especially if not followed by any actions. The whole thing leaves a very bad taste, which this apology post has failed to even remotely wash away.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Has or will there be any personnel changes in order to avoid another "series of mistakes"?

Comment: I read "responsible for the product, engineering, and community *dreams*."

Comment: Nice try, but you can't censor your users forever

Comment: David, a self-serving "apology" is not desired here. I think you need to scrap your Code of Conduct and let the community manage things, as they have successfully been doing so before your management started burning the whole thing down.

Comment: Odd that this site is for the community, the community is clamoring for the reinstatement, and StackExchange **executives** are still clinging to the "we're right so shut up" attitude. This is really being handled in the worst way possible.

Comment: // , You guys pulled a "welcoming and inclusive" with Monica Cellio, just the same way Wilfrid Laurier dealt with Lindsay Shepherd.

Comment: Remove those who didn't respect Monica's privacy

Answer (score 1632):

## Before "apologizing", you need to come clean: [did you lie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334268)?

(Edit: Post has been deleted. See [web archive link here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191122202333/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology/334268#answer-334268).)

Earlier, you (Stack Exchange) wrote:

> We removed a moderator for repeatedly violating our existing Code of Conduct and being unwilling to accept our CM’s repeated requests to change that behavior.

However, **Monica [disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248#comment1092882_334248)** that she had received repeated requests to change her behavior.

Clearly one party here is lying, and much of the community believes that party is Stack Exchange.

#### So—did you lie, or not? Your "apology" is meaningless until you clean this up.

Comment: Well said.  Sadly, I doubt the company will say a peep on this, on the advice of their corporate legal team.

Comment: Given the unwarranted nature of making a press release about a community moderator without having first followed the appropriate steps for removal of said moderator, and the *completely* unwarranted step of publicly using the moderator's real name in that press release, I would suspect that the lawyers will be advising that SE make a retraction in order to minimise their exposure in the event that they are sued.  Having attempted to make good SE's negative remarks about Monica prior to any suit against them being filed by her would go a long way to reduce their chances of being found liable.

Comment: @MontyWild - What sort of suit could be brought?  I'm not disagreeing, I'm asking because I'm interested to understand this idea better.  Thank you.

Comment: @aparente001, well... Monica has claimed mental distress, as well as harassment from some of those who have read the press release, amongst other things.  I am not a lawyer... but I believe that these are actionable wrongs that SE has committed against her, should she choose to file suit against them.  Still, even if they issue a retraction, harm has still been caused, so if they do issue a retraction, it had better be sooner rather than later.

Comment: @MontyWild - Hmm.  I'm not sure one can sue simply because of mental distress.  If you're thinking about libel/slander -- I suspect it would be an expensive endeavor and my impression is that those cases are a huge amount of work, and it's not easy to prevail and get a worthwhile outcome.  But I'm not an expert.  Anyway, thanks for following up.

Comment: @aparente001, actually, my reading of US law is that under certain circumstances, the plaintiff need make very little effort to successfully bring a suit of defamation - consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defamation#Defamation_per_se.  If this case meets any of the criteria, and Monica chooses to sue... SE's chances aren't too good, IMO...

Comment: @MontyWild - I've only ever studied one such case, so I admit I only have one data point.  It was a case in a paralegal class I took a couple years ago.  Besides reading the decision, I also skimmed the brief prepared by the complainant's counsel.  It was a huge undertaking.  But I may be extrapolating unfairly -- as I said, I only have that one data point.

Comment: @aparente001 Personally, I doubt it will come to the point of a suit being filed, since it appears that SE has awoken to their collective error, and in any law suit, only the lawyers are guaranteed to win... but that's up to Monica if SE can't sort matters out with her to her satisfaction.

Comment: @MontyWild - In the case I studied, the complainant's win meant a great deal to him.

Comment: "Clearly one party here is lying" - No, it's also possible that there's a misunderstanding and both parties believe they are correct. Maybe SE staff gave warnings but were never explicit enough for Monica to realize that's what they were. I still think that SE handled this in about the worst way they could and refused to even consider that Monica may have not perceived things the same way, but I find this answer to be needlessly antagonistic.

Comment: @DavidK: You realize virtually *all* the evidence available is stacked (hah..) against SE? Like (a) those who *were* in the Teacher's Lounge [dispute SE's account](/q/334248#comment1093119_334268), (b) Monica is not oblivious and she's *pretty damn sure*, (c) her entire character and past history *also* back her up, and (d) SE has refused to back up its accusations or even respond, to name a few. Yeah, it's not *physically impossible* that there's a misunderstanding—and do note that I asked it as a *question* —but if you feel both sides sound similarly credible.. you've *got* to be kidding me.

Comment: @DavidK IANAL, but I've always seen courts using the *reasonable* person test. (I've done Jury Duty.) Would a *reasonable* person conclude this was just a simple "misunderstanding" or would a *reasonable* person reach a different and more likely conclusion? It's not about whether something is or isn't possible, even in principle; it's about whether something has been shown to be true beyond *reasonable* doubt. For ex: Is it possible for a tornado to go through a junkyard and produce a working space shuttle? Sure, there's an infinitesimally small but non-zero chance. Is it likely? Not at all.

Comment: I'm with Mehrdad here. I simply won't trust or respect SO, Inc in general and Sara Chipps in particular until something definitive is said about Monica's case. While the apology is a positive step there is definitely an element of pro forma in it. To me it is not a resolution of this crisis.

Comment: Very much agree with you, Mehrdad, and have [expanded the analysis a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834) below, since the rest of the apology is also problematic.

Comment: Part of the problem is these statements beeing out there, uncontradicted, is continued and unneeded harm against a real person that has not only not been rectified, but it looks like no rectification is forthcoming.

Comment: @Mehrdad I dispute both Stack Overflow _and_ Monica's accounts, to varying extents. I'm with DavidK on this one.

Comment: how ironic would it be that Monica find someone to help her pro-bono on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It’s much easier for me to trust and believe someone who has been effectively communicating and moderating for ages, and harder for me to trust people who copy and paste non-apologies that insult my intelligence on several stacks. Basically, we *know* Monica. We’ve seen Monica post and moderate and chat in several contexts and that’s why we trust Monica. When Sara Chipps started posting, I had to click on the profile link to have any idea of the context, and in a “Monica-said/SO-said” situation, I’m going to believe Monica.

Comment: SE has yet to tell me what specific things I said (presumably in TL on Sep 18 during the CoC-change discussion) were violations of the current CoC.  I found the leaked transcript, reread everything I said (those leaks contain everything I said that day, and for that matter that week), and I still can't see it on my own.  (Plus there's the question about those alleged warnings/requests from CMs.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I've been trying *very* hard to avoid injecting many of my own opinions and thoughts publicly here, out of a fear that it could risk making things toxic for you, which is the last thing I'd want. But as someone who can be rather cynical, I will say that I do not that surprising in the least, and I feel you're just a little (read: *very*...) optimistic about this whole situation. (If you might find it more helpful to chat about things privately, just let me know and I'll be happy to find you a way to reach me. Though I'm a nobody as far as this site goes... just an active user.)

Comment: Hey @MonicaCellio, since your answer on the other question was deleted, if you'd really like them to answer it, I suggest making it into a new question and linking to it in the comments in the FAQ. The sooner you do this the more people will see it.

Comment: @Mehrdad a CM told me in the Tavern not to bother.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: It seems you have 2 disjoint options here. If getting modship back is more important to you, that would be just quietly doing what they said in the email, though I suspect you will have to abide by whatever they say that way. If getting them to address your concerns is more important to you (with your modship being potentially sacrificed in the process, despite any [claims](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7958569#7958569) to the contrary, which I have no reason to trust anymore), that would be posting your concerns on Meta (the sooner, the more visible)...

Comment: @Mehrdad, there's another option here.  Just walk away.  Several concepts should be made clear to everyone here by now:  1. This is just a company, nothing special.  It's not a "community", it's not a "way of life", its nothing "new", and it's certainly not immune to anything else *any* company experiences.  2. Being a moderator, whether paid or not, is `just a job`, not something of any exhalted nature.  If you like making places better, there are a myriad of places in the world that could use your **OBVIOUS LEVELHEADEDNESS far more than this site.**

Comment: @Mehrdad if they hadn't *libeled* me, I'd probably have walked away by know and let the bullies win.  But reinstatement is a necessary first step toward clearing my name, here in the land of "guilty until proven innocent", so here we are.  If they'd shown some restraint and acted [in accordance with what they *say*](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/03/stack-overflow-ignores-its-own-rules.html), things would likely be very different now.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: To be honest, I can't say I see how that might help. To those of us who know you and trust you, there's nothing to clear in the first place. To the others whose view of you is now tainted, I imagine asking SE to reinstate you would be seen as a concession or confession. I could be wrong though... I imagine you have plans for how this might play out.

Comment: From @MonicaCellio's [blog](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/13/stack-overflow-silence.html) "Sometime in here, I am told, a community manager told moderators (via a post on the private team) that I have been told what the CoC violations were. This is not true." ...Another lie?

Comment: @Mehrdad I've been publicly smeared, including being listed on some "modern villains" site (!) and being discussed on hate sites.  It's disgusting.  A lot more needs to happen to clear my name, but a first step is reinstating me, which has the effect of reversing SE's action.

Comment: @Monica: Holy cow, that sounds scary... I'm sorry to hear that. If it ever turns out I might be able to help in any way, please let me know.

Comment: There's a "real-life villains" wiki (serial killers, mass murderers etc.). Someone had created an entry on Monica, that has now been deleted. But when google searching, you find remnants: ... "is a Moderator that had to be removed as she violated the Code of Conduct. She misgendered people and this is not okay. Also we're notified to..." More can't be found, but it's indeed scary and shows how the lies spread about Monica are perceived outside of SE (i. e. as the truth).

Comment: Looks like Boeing all over the place... higher ups lost complete touch with the engineers that made them a great company.

Comment: He's just saving face, that's why the details are still murky. I agree that he needs to clear this up, but the apology is fake, I wouldn't expect any kind of clarification like you're requesting.

Comment: @AnneDaunted, I'm pretty sure that entry in the real-life villains wiki was meant to be sarcasm. "She misgendered people and this is not okay" is not something that you would write if you actually believed it. I guess the entry was likely created by alt-right people. (You could argue that that's actually *worse*, but I just wanted to clarify that.)

Comment: @PoorYorick I couldn't read the whole article. But being featured there, whatever the intention of the author, is bad enough. Also, I have seen (serious) attempts at answering questions that were even more poorly phrased then that sentence, so I wouldn't rule out that they actually believed that she had misgendered people and just didn't know better how to put into words why she deserved an entry there.

Comment: And still nothing?  I have deleted my profile in the communities where I had participated.  Maybe not much of a loss for SE - only a few thousand points in a couple of communities.  Other than keeping this profile, to keep tabs on what is happening here, and benefit from content others have posted, I will not participate until this is resolved.  I am glad others will benefit from the content I have already posted in those communities, but I will not benefit a company that treats people like this by giving them additional content.

Comment: They've stated seperately that they are [unable to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335508/monicas-situation-continues-unresolved-is-se-hoping-the-problem-just-goes-away#comment1105379_335607) why they can not reinstate Monica. So I think it's pretty clear they've been told by legal that they can apologize, but not publically state or perform any action which would seem to factually contradict what was said to the register. At this point, doubt this is ever answered, as they seem to value the potential legal issue more than the actual harm this is doing to the community.

Comment: @BroSlow: Yeah I saw that comment. I'm not sure what to make of it because all it said was that Shog9 is unable to answer that question at that time, which would make sense if they were trying to come out with an official response (Shog9's answer seemed to imply they're trying to do things more slowly). Or it could be like you said, where none of them ever say anything. To be honest I don't really see legal issues (I don't see who can sue them except Monica, and she already knows the truth regardless of what they say) but I think they're likely avoiding PR damage from admitting they lied.

Comment: Additional "did you lie" situation: I have heard that employees have told moderators several times that I have been shown the alleged CoC violations.  **This is false.** But the error is easily corrected; they can send them to me at any time.  Remember SE, the claim was repeated CoC violations after repeated warnings, so that's what you need to show me.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Once a month or so has passed after their latest legitimate attempts to make things right with you, I would really urge you to mail (certified) their legal department a cease & desist letter for the defamation. That will probably (hopefully) get their attention. If not, you can then decide if you want to sue them or not. But the way this is going, this is completely insane. (You might even consider asking on Legal.SE what your options are!)

Comment: @Mehrdad - Things have started to move.  Monica is seeking legal representation and is soliciting monetary contributions for her legal expenses.  https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users

Comment: @aparente001: Wow I see, thanks for the update!

Comment: If they did they will not admit it. Not good for business

Comment: @ColleenV: I'm reverting your change. You made it so that it can be interpreted as if "you" refers to him individually. The whole edit was pretty unnecessary too.

Comment: The linked post has been deleted, but it can be found in the Internet Archive at this URL: https://web.archive.org/web/20191020051643/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes You may wish to update the post.

Comment: @SRM the Internet Archive URL doesn't point to a post by Monica. It points to a post by "Cesar M" and the first couple of replies to that post aren't from Monica either. And since the "original" (real) post was voluntarily removed by the author (at least we are told so by the place-holder there), this very short reply to Fullerton's post has lost much (if not all) of its substance, IMHO. (I am still eager to figure out what the actual issue of "denigration" is beyond the abundant (counter-)accusations, expressions of hurt feelings and apologies not (fully) accepted.)

Comment: You can't rewrite the history, http://web.archive.org/web/20191122202333/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology/334268

Comment: The linked "did you lie" post has been deleted.  Voluntarily removed by the author, of course.

Comment: Never mind, reading the web archive post now.

Comment: Read it.  Wow...

Answer (score 1361):

I was optimistic when you made this post; this was a much more positive message than the "apology and update" that preceded it.  The test of your will to address these problems would have come in the actions that follow and in their timeliness.  Acknowledgement of errors is important but incomplete.  **Unfortunately, the follow-through was severely deficient.**

> We’ll be reaching out to her directly to apologize for the lack of process, privacy, and to discuss next steps. We’ll keep those discussions completely private unless we both agree to share any of it with the community. (October 6 21:00 UTC)

I received email from David Fullerton on October 8 at 15:10 UTC.  The email repeated the accusation that I violated the code of conduct, again without specific citations.  David also claimed that I was warned and quoted two messages from Sara Chipps in TL which do not sound like the warnings David says they are.  The message referred to an upcoming reinstatement process and said I could apply following that process.

That same day I asked, since that email repeated the assertion that I violated the *current* CoC, to be told what specific actions did so.  I have asked this question several times since September 27 and **have yet to receive an answer**.

Having heard October 11 as a target date for the new policy and having heard nothing further, I sent David email on October 13 at 19:30 UTC asking for the process and how to trigger it.  Two days later, on October 15 at 22:30 UTC, I received a reply from David, saying that they were finalizing the process that week after receiving feedback and would send it to me when it was final.  Given the ongoing harm being caused by Sara's public, defamatory accusations, I [asked if things could be expedited](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/15/stack-overflow-delays.html).  I received no reply.

On October 21 at 20:00 UTC, I received email from Tim Post (not David) alerting me that the new processes would be posted soon and I could apply for reinstatement.  I *still* have received no answers to my questions about what the specific charges are.  [There are serious flaws in the reinstatement process that call its fairness into question for my case.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336236/162102)

I had hoped SE would prioritize resolving this matter, especially since this post admits to serious failures of process (and also because of the ongoing harm to me).  Given those serious failures, I [still think](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334427/162102) the correct thing to do is to reinstate me now and *then* discuss whatever the problem is, but SE says their due-process-lacking decision stands and my only recourse is to apply for reinstatement under a flawed process and a presumption of guilt.  Meanwhile, the defamatory statements [continue to do me harm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/162102).

I am **not satisfied** by the followup from this post.  It has now been more than a month and SE has taken no actions to mitigate the harm they have done me.

Comment: *sigh*  It would have been really nice for you to wake up with something in your inbox.  "We **are** reaching out to Monica" sounds a lot more proactive than "We **will** reach out to Monica", indicating an awareness of the priority in addressing this failure of communication...

Comment: @Magisch I will be *very* disappointed if they wait days before even contacting me to apologize and talk about plans.  It would call David's sincerity into question.  I think his intentions are sincere and I look forward to seeing them backed by action.  First steps ASAP will go a long way toward rebuilding trust.  The whole problem won't be solved in one conversation, but we can *start*.

Comment: Yom Kippur is tomorrow evening. 24h seems appropriate for a message. Lets see how the will handle it and keep the word.

Comment: @aloisdg Yom Kippur starts tomorrow evening.  It's also a *big* holiday.  By analogy, scheduling a meeting late in the day on Christmas eve with a devout Christian (who has obligations that night and not just the next day) would not be ideal.  Today would be *much* better than tomorrow; trust me.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Sorry that this happened to you. I hope everything is resolved in a manner that helps address the hurt that you've experienced and enables you to continue your wonderful participation in the communities you've been such an important part of.

Comment: Thanks @JoeFriend; I appreciate the support.  I hope so too.

Comment: Just for clarity, if they *do* reach out to you tomorrow, will you be online at all?  (If not to answer, at least to update *this* answer with the fact that they've reached out?)  Or is this holiday one where you will be offline entirely?

Comment: @Wildcard I will be online (intermittently at times) until a couple hours before local sunset.  If I'm contacted late in the day I'll do my best to update this post before going offline for Yom Kippur.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Given what has happened, *why* would you (or anyone else in your position, for that matter) want to re-engage with them? I'm *not* saying you should or shouldn't. I just want to understand your PoV on *why*, b/c to me, it would seem to have passed the point of no return, like trying to go back to an abusive relationship, and would've probably warranted legal action, based on some of your comments about emotional distress, reputaional damage due to (AFAIK, IANAL) libelious claims, danger due to doxxing, and other details mentioned elsewhere. So, why? Is a sunk-cost fallacy likely?

Comment: @code_dredd Monica is best placed of all of us to indicate to the company what remedial actions she feels are warranted, or at the very least to get some closure on the whole debacle. It's hard to imagine why you _wouldn't_ want that, though I do agree that at _some_ point you have to cut your losses.

Comment: I consider it likely that given the fallout over this matter,  SE are going to proceed with caution.  I would expect that there will be a considerable amount of internal discussion before they settle on a course of action.   Just because SE's CTO has issued an apology doesn't mean that those to whom he reports will have exactly the same opinion.  Given the potential for legal action against them, their terms of service notwithstanding, the possibility exists that their legal counsel has recommended silence until all the potential ramifications can be considered.

Comment: I would hope they would at least reach out to Monica and say, "I apologize for us not following our process and for how we publicly responded to your dismissal. I recognize that hurt you. I apologize. After the holiday, would it be amenable for us to sit down, have a meeting about this, and see if there's a way forward?"

Comment: @GeorgeStocker that would be a good start, and something they ought to be able to do without lawyers.  So far there's been no contact at all.

Comment: I am baffled that SE is failing you — and there-for us, the community — again.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker IANAL but seems to me that saying that “their public response to her dismissal hurt her” could add weight to any potential libel suit.  Frankly, I think they *are* guilty of libel against Monica, and I’m not even a litigative type.  So their slowness in proceeding to contact her disappoints but doesn’t surprise me.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker but the current CoC does not mandate singular "they".

Comment: @GeorgeStocker “stated pronouns” includes  neopronouns, not just “they”. Monica was demodded for suggesting that some of us can write well enough to avoid pronouns altogether and not make it seem weird in a chat room full of people already hurt by SE’s ham-handed handling of LBGTQ+ issues. There have been mods that have said unequivocally bigoted things directly to individuals in that room who weren’t demodded.

Comment: To amplify what @ColleenV said, people in that room said things *to and about me* that clearly violate the *current* CoC. They remain mods.

Comment: I don't want to go to court.  I want SE to **talk with me**.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if the legal discussion could migrate elsewhere.  I'm getting pinged on all of this.  Thanks!

Comment: Monica ... since I don't feel I can say what I want without reprisal, I'll just say: I'm sorry you've been put through this. My thoughts and prayers are with you.

Comment: Please respect the author of this post and take tangentially-related content [to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1365/discussion-on-answer-by-monica-cellio-an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-step).

Comment: **Everybody, including Stack Overflow Inc.:** Yom Kippur will start very soon for me.  Can we please all try to make Yom Kippur a less-evil day for me than Rosh Hashana was?  Let's not have another day of defamation, personal attacks, and the like when I can't object, ok?

Comment: The point is, that **you are not helping** and both Monica and Catija have expressly asked people to rein in the unhelpful negativity on comments to this answer. Cease and desist. This is not the time or the place to be a keyboard warrior.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I got to say a few things.  I first want to say I truly believe your story more than theirs.  I truly think the whole situation you were put in is crazy.  I do think they ruined some of your reputation whether online or in real life.  I think you have been diligent...but I think you are causing unneeded stress in your own life.  I think its time to move on.  They will not I repeat they will not reinstate you.  This is known.  You are practically begging for a job that pays you nothing & has done nothing but bring pain to you.  As unfortunate as it is the right move is escape!

Comment: @JonH if this needs repeating, the right move is not to shrug it off and say *good riddance*.  Although Monica has the overwhelming support of her communities and of Meta, where she participated with great enthusiasm and equanimity, her character has been tainted. Her future income might be affected (if it hasn't been already) whenever a future employer Googles her name. Reinstating her as a mod in at least *one* community (IMO) would do a lot to repair that damage.

Comment: I am disheartened by the delay in making this right. I hope that no-one is assuming that if you are ignored long enough all of this will go away.

Comment: "Moving On" is a great response to all sorts of internal SE controversies.  SE made that impossible this time through their actions.  The difference, compared to all the other nonsense tempests in teapots that happen here, is that this time SE engaged in _bullying_.  They went to the media and used their corporate weight to discredit Monica by impugning her reputation.  It is and should remain a millstone around their neck until they undo the harm they inflicted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA although reinstating her would help, as she could use that as a point to support her explanation to anyone who bothered to ask after coming across the info that is currently out there in the media, I don't see it as actually _repairing_ anything. How many people are going to see it and ask her about it or put the effort to do follow up research vs. how many will see it and decide they have seen enough.

Comment: The longer Monica goes here without any kind of satisfactory response, the more I'm convinced this apology was entirely insincere, and just a "let's pretend to be a bit humble to sweep this under the carpet" post.

Comment: @MonicaCellio If at some point you are compelled to take legal action, I sense that many of us would happily contribute to something such as a GoFundMe campaign to offset your costs.

Comment: @berry120: It wasn't technically insincere, it just [didn't say what most people thought it was saying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834).

Comment: @MonicaCellio: It's outragous that they _still_ haven't called.

Comment: @berry120 It seems insincere enough at this point to deserve my downvote

Comment: It's over, stop waiting.

Comment: @EricWang - What do you mean?

Comment: @ColleenV - Trying again with the chat room idea.  I've made a "gallery" so the room doesn't get hijacked.  I hope I did it right and you can get in....  Here is the link: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1378/recapping-personal-discussion.  I've been studying what Monica wrote on Friday and I think I've made good progress.  I am hoping to check my understanding.  I would value your presence in the conversation -- if she and you have time.  It doesn't have to be today of course.

Comment: @ColleenV - You're a good listener, for starters, and you have a warm heart and a pretty cool head.  I trust you a lot.  See you tomorrow.

Comment: Monica, thank you for keeping us updated. @DavidFullerton, I assume you know the community is following this post to see how this is resolved, but if not -- I at least have it bookmarked and am checking back regularly, and I'm sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: How did you get the idea you would need to apply to be reinstated?  Is there some guesswork in that, or was there something explicit from someone?  // Would you be willing to submit an application for reinstatement?  (I don't even know how one would do that -- especially taking into account their wall of silence....)  Although I don't think you *should* have to do that, I hope you will, because I feel that the whole network is not able to move in any direction with this hanging over us all.

Comment: Do not apply to reinstall, it's not your fault.

Comment: FWIW, surviving moderators have been told the reinstatement procedure would take two weeks.

Comment: @gerrit two weeks until it is shared with the public or two weeks to actually go through?

Comment: @Magisch I believe they mean: from the moment the ex-moderator requests reinstatement until the moment the ex-moderator is informed of the result of the procedure.  I don't know about the time from decision to implementation (which hopefully should be short) or about any public announcement.

Comment: However I don't think applying for reinstatement is possible until the proposed new procedure becomes official.

Comment: @aparente001 David's email said they are developing a process and then I can go through it.  The implication is that SE is unwilling to reverse their due-process-violating firing of me instead.  David has not sent me the process yet, so I don't know how to initiate it.

Comment: Be wary of the reinstatement process (RP)! Pure conjecture but makes sense and also explains SE's inaction:. They neither reinstate you, nor actually apologize, they keep the accusations secret. They hope that they can solve it all at once, in their favor. If you go through the RP and are reinstated, the purpose of that process might simply be for you to (implicitly) plead guilty. Then they could point at the RP as confirmation and justification for their earlier actions. You'd plead guilty, have learned your lesson and promise to do better. You wouldn't really clear your name that way.

Comment: @AnneDaunted - That's where mediation can play an important role.  For, for example, to agree that if the company gets to sweep their mistakes and omissions and hypocrisy (and whatever I left out) under the rug, then Monica gets to come out with a clean slate, which could involve a statement of exoneration such as, *Monica's positions and actions were blown wildly out of proportion; in fact we found that she did nothing to fan the flames of the conflagration we created; our company scapegoated her and nevertheless she kept her cool throughout. etc.*

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Have you started to look at the procedure described at JAMS, Inc., that I posted?  It's at the bottom of the Mediation page from last week.  To get formal mediation, one files for arbitration and then checks the mediation box.  If you do that, you don't get an arbitrator -- you get a mediator.  And you don't go to court -- you do the mediation in an office conference room or over the phone. // You don't have to wait and wait and wait indefinitely for them to design their procedures at snail's pace -- filing as soon as it's clear that mediation is needed would give you leverage.

Comment: So what I'm saying is that this is a process *you* can initiate.  It means stepping out of the jail of passivity SE has put you in.  You'd be taking positive action toward a resolution.  Although other SE members can't join you in the complaint under the rules of the terms of service, once a date has been set, demonstrations, picketing, etc., can begin.  Which we really need to start doing.  The inaction and just going around in circles nipping at each other is so damaging.  "Fight Club" to distract us from political action.

Comment: @AnneDaunted I have no intention of pleading guilty to something I did not do. aparente001, I'm aware of the mediation process, thanks; it's one option I'm considering.

Comment: I understand that, but I guess that that's the intention behind the new process. And it needn't be explicit, maybe that you just agree to the CoC (to not violate it, enforce it etc.) so they can make it look like they reinstated you because your stance changed, so it must have been in violation of the CoC before and so they were correct in firing you etc.

Comment: I cannot resist the impression that all this is the–unfortunately–well-known ego game in the variant: „I am the C...x...O of the 40/145ᵗʰ top-visited web site worldwide and you (all) are unpaid volunteers who are silly enough to generate revenue for us.“ This is superficial, shallow, childish, unprofessional and it is...human. The only consolation that often remains is that this human race will disappear from this planet once.

Comment: I can’t help the feeling they are stalling the conversation while someone on the staff is desperately digging through all your posts on the network to find something objectionable.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Firing you was a gross mistake. The only way to fix that is to give you moderation privileges back. ASAP. And issue statement to the press clearing your name. And then if they feel you are violating some rules you deserve proper process where it can be decided whether or not that is true. You have incredible patience and I feel like company is abusing that. Don't let them.

Comment: Just saw your updates. Very curious how the process will look. The cynical side of me almost expects the appeals process to come with a gag order of sorts, preventing you from posting disparaging comments about SE on the site.

Comment: @Mehrdad I have seen a draft of the process, and I believe that the CM team has worked very hard to create a robust and fair process. If the company commits to following that process, it's a step in the right direction and pretty much the only reason why I haven't resigned yet. As you can probably tell from my profile image though, if they continue to not do right by Monica, it won't be enough.

Comment: @ColleenV nice image, thanks!  Is the process controlled only by the CMs, or do higher-ups get veto power?  Are there provisions for avoiding conflict of interest, like having the people who decided to remove a mod rule on reinstatement appeals?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I can't take credit for the image, I saw it on J.R.'s profile and had to have it :) I don't feel comfortable going into a lot of detail, but there are controls in the process to avoid conflicts of interest and most important points in the process don't rely on one person's judgement. I still have concerns that senior staff will just bypass the entire thing when it suits them, but I'm waiting to see. If I had seen this process a month before everything that's happened, I would have a very positive opinion of it.

Comment: @Monica FYI if you haven't seen: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335607/312691

Comment: @ColleenV Where can I get that image? I need to change my profile...

Comment: This whole situation is completely absurd. You've been mistreated @MonicaCellio. Hope you are doing okay.

Comment: @ThomasMyron Sorry it took a while, I wanted to make sure the person I got the image from was OK with it being shared - the verdict is to share it freely: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGuXb.png

Comment: @MonicaCellio am I reading too much into Tim Post's seemingly throwaway statement about never ever reinstating certain ex-mods? See my post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335769/328829).

Comment: @Chappo David told me that I can apply for reinstatement when they finish the process.  That doesn't mean they won't immediately reject me, of course -- everything about this so far has been done without transparency, integrity, or honesty, so who knows?  I *hope* Tim is talking about things like ex-moderators who did major, unrepairable things like misuse PII or destroy lots of content, but I don't know more than you do about what he said.

Comment: @MonicaCellio it is *extremely disturbing* to me that David say you can *apply* for reinstatement.  As far as I can tell *they* need to *justify* your removal; the fact they're placing the onus on you sounds like they are still trying to blame you.  Now they're trying to craft a situation of saying "we told her she could apply" which puts them in a position of power to refuse.  It's a common psychological tactic.  What I think we still need to demand details on *why they removed you in the first place*.  If we can't trust the removal process, why trust the reinstatement process?

Comment: @cegfault yeah, I've been asking for that information for more than three weeks now.  If the forthcoming processes don't come with transparency, I won't trust 'em.

Comment: Start legal proceedings - i.e. sue them.  They will not reinstate you without that ridiculous demand that you apply, because that would be admission of guilt, and I bet they have consulted with lawyers who told them not to.  They are still hoping they can legally weasel out of this.  Don't let them.

Comment: @AgapwIesu: While I share your sentiment about the requirement of "applying", i.e. "kissing the ring" - it's not at all clear that a legal procedure would help matters. I'm not saying it won't, I'm saying you're suggesting this too frivolously. You need to be a lot more specific about what such a procedure will demand, what the venue should be etc. Suing is serious business with many potential negative ramifications as well.

Comment: @einpoklum - There is nothing frivolous about the suggestion.  I have only sued anyone once, and that was an insurance company that failed to pay after their client totaled my car, and only after four months of back and forth with them.  They kept lying, putting me off, trying to bully me into accepting a few minor repairs even after I had documented two shops said the car was a goner.  Sound familiar?  The lying, putting the offended party off, trying to get away with band-aid fixes?  When it gets like this, it seems the only thing a corporation will listen to is legal action.

Comment: "Sound similar?" <- No, quite dissimilar actually. Lying is extremely common in many situations...

Comment: @MonicaCellio "_That doesn't mean they won't immediately reject me, of course_" - Well, if they do that, I would assume there would be a "few" more moderator resignations.

Comment: My fear would be that they are requiring the reapplication because as a part of the process, they have added a waiver that says you must abide by the result and cannot sue over the decision, or must agree to 'arbitration'.  That should be a non-starter.

Comment: *sigh*.  I miss you, Monica.

Comment: So I have revised my opinion about the process. I think for a while I was desperate to find signs that all this wasn't what I thought it was. As this drags on, it has become apparent to me that Stack Exchange is implementing a process to obscure the fact that they don't want people who express political views they don't like being community moderators. We moderators agreed they could remove us at any time without warning at their discretion, so they're within their rights to do that. It would be better if they just admitted that's what they did instead of pretending it was something else.

Comment: It's hard to explain their behavior any other way.  If they were purely acting out of corporate mercantilism, they would have fixed the problems by now.  This feels like a form of [nearly] religious zealotry, a conviction that it would be wrong to even consider the possibility they made an error.

Comment: Want to see inappropriate posts from people higher up than Monica? Read everything Shog ever said. He renamed a chat room "rape room". He used obscenities against users. Monica is the picture of sweetness, light, and amicable behavior

Answer (score 658):

As a user who goes by ‘they’, I appreciate your acknowledgment that despite your *intent* to make users like me more welcome, your *actions* backfired:

> Worse, through our handling of this situation, we made [members of the LGBTQ+ community] a target for harassment as people debated their right to express themselves and be addressed according to how they identify.

But you are responding only to the straw that broke the camel's back.  **Between the many words of apology, the only specific actions you're offering here are reinstating the moderators and publishing the code of conduct update.**  These are good steps to rectify SE Inc.'s mistakes around the CoC and Monica, but they don't address any deeper issues of governance and respect for community behind many of the other issues [fueling the blaze that this one spark set off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965):

- **Mandatory binding arbitration**—an abuse of the contract of adhesion that Stack Exchange, Inc., requires all users to sign.

  Incidentally, according to [your own statements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310758), you require anyone opting out to provide their legal name *up front*, which is not very friendly to queer people like me who write only under a name that is very much not my legal name—the very people you say you're trying to support with the CoC changes.
- **Animated ads**—in July you tell us [animated ads are against your policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387222), and then three months later you [backtrack without explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334144).
- **Fingerprinting users for tracking**—no matter how many laws or industry standards the practice doesn't break, profiting from mass surveillance is morally wrong, and when we [asked you about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331960), you gave us only a [condescending response about audio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332229).  If you must display more relevant targeted ads, you should limit them to be relevant to the questions and answers on the page.
- **License changes**—in 2016, when you wanted to change the license on source code published here, you [asked for our input](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080), and you [listened and responded to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956).  But this year, when you wanted to make a much more modest change from CC-BY-SA 3.0 to CC-BY-SA 4.0, you [quietly changed the Terms of Service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089), possibly in [violation of your own license to the content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333094), without explaining the process or making an effort to consult us, the users who granted you a license to use our writing in the first place.

Perhaps if you actually want to establish legitimate trust in the company, Stack Exchange, Inc., should have some elected representatives of the moderators and of the users on the board of directors—or perhaps if a welcoming community and a living repository of knowledge is incompatible with the commercial goals of the venture capital funders, the Stack Exchange network should be spun out into a different governance model altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the summary, I was unaware of many of these and knowing makes a big difference to me. I will follow this and the other issues closely. Thanks again

Answer (score 636):

### tl;dr: I believe CTO Fullerton is mostly candy-wrapping, not back-tracking from, SE Inc.'s problematic conduct.

To my fellow Meta.SE users: I am surprised at those of you who view this post as a proper apology and worthy of gratitude. I will try to explain why I believe Mr. Fullerton has apologized for the wrong or the minor things, while in fact doubling-down on the more serious problems or transgressions.

#### Continued over-hyping of the inclusivity issue

Mr. Fullerton apologized first and foremost to *"members of our LGBTQ+ community"* – not to the entire community, or to Monica Cellio and the other affected moderators, as though the recent upheaval has been due to how *"they felt they couldn’t participate authentically and we didn’t respond quickly or strongly enough in supporting them."*

This repeats the claim of there being a non-inclusivity crisis that requires forceful urgent action (i.e. sky-is-falling type of situation). Mr. Fullerton is indicating SE Inc. will find for itself the same legitimacy for inappropriate actions as it has over the past few weeks.

Now, I do not want to dismiss the issue of LGBTQ+ inclusivity on SE. It's not trivial and should not be ignored but it, and they, have been used in a rather insidious fashion to legitimize and morally-enforce conduct on SE Inc.'s part which is authoritarian, unilateralist and dismissive of broadly-held perspectives of the community. Much of the non-inclusivity or non-welcoming aspects of SE at this moment are the result of *that*, irrespective of any LGBTQ+ related issues.

Also, when Mr. Fullerton described the undesirable consequences of SE Inc.'s actions, he emphasized hurting:

- > those... who want to help us make the community **welcoming and open** to all.

Well, the community is open to all (OK, to be fair: to English-speakers who are able to browse websites). Different SE sites are more welcoming, or less welcoming, but there is an ongoing debate regarding the extent, severity and justifiability of the non-welcoming aspects; Fullerton's choice of words re-enforces a fixation, or at least an excessive focus, on this issue.

If you think I'm exaggerating, just note the same phrase being written again and again:

- > we [will] all learn together how to be more **welcoming and inclusive**
- > our moderators are a vital part of us creating a more **welcoming and inclusive** place
- > I am more committed than ever to creating a **welcoming and inclusive** community
- > One of our top priorities across the entire team is ... to make the community more **inclusive and welcoming**

The incessant repetition of this mantra is a definite sign IMHO of an artificial focus or over-hype.

#### No justification for more CoC commandments

Mr. Fullerton writes SE Inc. intends to amend the Code of Conduct. Why? I mean, personally, I believe it should just be rescinded, but what is this supposed to even help with? I'm not a moderator, so maybe I missed it, but I have not heard any argument in favor of a further tightening of the code of conduct.

Thus, one of the key actions that's supposed to improve the situation is at best mysterious and of unclear benefit, and at worst – expected to worsen things on SE even further than with the original Code of Conduct.

#### Cellio's dismissal still in effect.

(I don't know Ms. Cellio, and I don't think I've even interacted with her as a mod and probably at all.)

Mr. Fullerton apologized for Cellio having been hurt; and for the process of her termination as a moderator having been flawed; but he did not indicate she will be reinstated. That means SE Inc. is doubling down on the legitimacy of the termination, flaws or no flaws. This is saying "we should have kicked you out more nicely".

That won't do. When you skip due process, your resultant actions should be null and void, or at least canceled.

Mr. Fullerton seems to indicate that Monica will have to undergo a process for being reinstated. That too is inappropriate. Maybe that process is reasonable, maybe it isn't – but it certainly shouldn't apply to her, now that it is agreed that her termination process was fundamentally flawed.

#### No retraction or justification of the claims against Ms. Cellio.

Despite Mr. Fullerton's apologetic tone, he has not retracted the claim that Monica Cellio had broken the (existing) Code of Conduct repeatedly. If she hasn't – please acknowledge that, Mr. Fullerton; that's definitely something worth apologizing over. If you insist that she has – and you should know, since by your admission you were personally involved in her dismissal – you now owe it to the Meta.SE public to list those breaches and explain why you found them sufficient for a dismissal.

#### Planned actions not essentially different than before apology

Even before Mr. Fullerton's post, we all knew SE Inc. was planning an updated/expanded Code of Conduct; and Sara Chipps has also talked about a "moderator removal process" (although we [already got one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/196834), so apparently an amendment). This was the plan when SE Inc. was "riding the high horse". How is it different now?

Mr. Fullerton could have said SE Inc. has reconsidered the changes it was planning to the CoC and the moderator removal procedure, and will now present different documents than they had planned before. He could have explained how those differences are to help curtail SE Inc. excesses – like his own, and how they would be binding in a way which prevents such arbitrary unilateral actions in the future. That may have helped to restore trust.

Comment: Yes, there needs to be more. We are left reading between the lines, parsing every sentence ad infinitum for clues, etc. Monica's and Sara's descriptions of what happened are not reconcilable, even taking misunderstandings into account.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: TBH, I didn't need that much parsing to smell something off about the post. I gave it the once-over to look for what's actionable and went "wait, I thought he was apologizing here..."

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I would appreciate your thoughts on this reply. I don't actually believe that there has been much progress with this post.

Comment: I rather appreciate this analysis. When I first saw this and the overwhelmingly "positive" responses to the OP, I was a bit confused myself. I'm not saying the apology is completely trash, but it still feels a bit contrived. Yeah, I'm sure it *was* contrived to a large extent, but my point is that I'm not so sure about its overall sincerity in apologizing for a wrongdoing. This helps to crystalize some of the things I wasn't able to identify myself - possibly because of my lack of substantial connection to SE in general.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat Sara made such a hash of things, folks were probably just relieved to see a more measured and thoughtful response, even if it had some issues. There are a lot of people who are very invested in SE and really want to find a way to  make things work.

Comment: @ColleenV: But aren't you saying most people will just be content to hear some compliments and soft words regardless of the material content? :-(

Comment: @einpoklum Yes. It's human nature that when you're really hoping for something, you will see anything that hints that it might happen as a positive. I have usually regretted hanging on to something too long due to nostalgia, but I think it's only fair to wait to see what steps the company will take. But, I'm not going to wait too long before I make a decision about what I'm willing to put up with in exchange for being part of the community moderate.

Comment: Given context from seeing this going down over the course of months, I have to disagree with the majority of this answer. I'd love to elaborate on this, but I can't really – hopefully Stack Overflow will release a clarification at some point.

Comment: Indeed - I think people are relieved to be _able_ to stop sounding like bitter ingrates for just a moment, and have a genuine moment of human empathy. Whether history ends up showing that the post was genuine or not, I think it's good for all of us to take a moment and be nice over it. There's no need for further vindictiveness. Let's stop chewing each other's ears off, give David the benefit of the doubt for just a second, and take it from there. We want it to be a signal of positivity, so let's not ruin that from the outset by automatically being negative.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: But there is (almost) no doubt. While the post is not phrased in a forthcoming manner, it is clear in its bottom line. Other than the mystery of what's in the new CoC - there are no questions in my reply.

Comment: To be clear: timing aside, I agree with what you've said here. If the world ever needed a perfect example of how going 500% too far out of your way to pander to every possible need of the minority results in _actual, real, practical hurt_ for the majority, this incident is it. Of course nobody will learn from it; that's not in vogue.

Comment: See also [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps/334665#comment1096480_334551). This apology might be a turn around, but there's a *long road* before SO.Inc will have my trust again (the community? Its people, there's good, there's bad, but I've generally never had a problem). So yes, I'm still skeptical.

Comment: I might just have to upvote this post and award it a 500 rep bounty if we don't have any confirmation that the Stack Exchange team kept their word regarding the first two bullet points. As for my comment in bold–now deleted–calling users not to downvote the letter of apology, I was thinking of Monica's delicate situation. She's being incredibly patient, smart and diplomatic,  so I didn't want  users' angry raw emotion to influence negatively the team's decision. Yes, sometimes a little sugar-coating is necessary in life, e.g. the ends justifies the means, but my patience is wearing thin.

Comment: I am somewhat disappointed that they haven't contacted Monica yet. That hints that they'll probably do so after finalizing the moderator removal procedure and releasing the CoC update, which is unfortunate.

Comment: This is right: `"When you skip due process, your resultant actions should be null and void, or at least canceled."` The meaningful apology begins with reinstating Monica Cellio and unambiguously and **publicly retracting** all unsubstantiated defamatory accusations made publicly against Monica. Then we can progress to _next steps_.

Comment: There is one objective difference between what the apology says and what position SE held previously: they intend to run the new CoC by moderators and take their input before implementing it. Previously, the CoC changes were *described* to the mods, not *shown* to them, and from the accounts we have, it seems they (the changes) were not really expected to incorporate any mod/community feedback.

Comment: "Mr. Fullerton apologized for Cellio having been hurt; and for the process of her termination as a moderator having been flawed; but he did not indicate she will be reinstated." Curiously, her name is never mentioned. For someone who followed the events, it's clear that it can only be Monica (also because he mentions a Jewish holiday and uses the pronuns "she" and "her"). Sara mentioned her actual last name to *The Register* to confirm it was her, yet in this "apology" published on MSE, her name is omitted.

Comment: It goes to demonstrate that a different public figure will elicit different reactions.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought when reading this. "We stand by everything we did, sorry it hurt you, we'll improve the messaging/timing next item." is the message being promulgated. The problem is the actual actions; the messaging and timing are totally ancillary.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: I had another comment here, but it was mysteriously removed, so it's difficult for me to reply to your comment.

Comment: This answer really needs more attention. It is calling out the CTO for trying to sweep all this under the rug without actually changing or fixing anything.

Comment: Update: They emailed Monica. [She isn't satisfied with their email.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334646/154726)

Comment: @Mehrdad: How very "surprising"...

Comment: @einpoklum: Also see [this](/q/334551/334646#comment1097103_334646), which is also news to me... just when I thought this couldn't get any worse.

Comment: @Mehrdad: So, they were ganging up on her in that "lounge" chatroom, then accusing her of being a CoC criminal. Nice.

Comment: This answer provides a great summary of why I didn't click the upvote button on the CTO's post. More than anything, it seems like an instance of internal coaching: _Let me show Sara how to issue a public apology._ So yes, the language of this apology is much, much better – but we're still not any closer to righting the wrong.

Comment: I agree with this answer, since I havent been much active on SE.Meta I cannot weigh in on this issue, but there is a good case to be made about this being an insincere apology, and a charade to still the crowds.

Comment: Nice catch... Sara Chipps also repeats the "welcoming and inclusive" mantra in the [The Register](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/) report

Comment: @fredsbend What can I say... I'm ahead of my time.

Comment: Yes, this isn't a proper apology, this is corporate babble, buzzword bingo stuff.

Comment: What's interesting, it looks like this comm is still one-way comm. I can't find comment replies to this topic from officials. Although maybe it's just mine bad F3-fu.

Comment: Sorry to see that my benefit of the doubt was, ultimately, proven to be misplaced. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Welcome to the ranks of the bitter ingrates then...

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica I hope there are T-shirts, at least?!

Comment: I love to read about "they felt they couldn’t participate" all over the place on Stack Exchange after moderators have ignored  all my flags and deleted my comments where I showed that I'm being stalked (by those who are interested to delete my content with no reason -- I proved it multiple times, but all proves are being deleted) during weeks and months but I didn't stop so they have muted me and then messaged (or it was automatic, does not matter) the staff so I've got an anonymous message saying that (after 10 years) I should leave the SO because I started asking tough questions.

Answer (score 588):

I'm a quiet (now resigned) moderator who just sits in her corner in The Workplace, keeping flag queues under control, trying to maintain a community that I care for. I don't spend time in meta.stackexchange, I just do - or did - what I was elected to do by my community four years ago.

I was one of those who resigned in the wake of the terribly handled situation that started bad and got worse. My resignation had nothing to do with not supporting the *intent* behind the new CoC; I have used the preferred pronouns for LGBTIQAP+ folk for years, be they new terms, existing terms, or terms that traditionally are used in other contexts. This had nothing to do with my decision.

What I objected to was the way in which the whole thing was enacted. For something that was private, it got very public and no doubt felt very, very personal for Monica. She was held up as the bad guy, she was slapped down when she was offline for days for her religious holiday. I honestly don't know what happened in private, nor do I even want to know. What was *publicly* visible was bad and placed a very poor light on SE and their ability to manage people. Which is all the more ironic to me, being a mod for "The Workplace," which by its *very nature* is about workplace conflict resolution.

So I will say that this apology is the very first attempt to address that poor behaviour honestly. It's a start. I hope that the promised behind-closed-doors arbitration with Monica is done with proper intent to a real resolution, not just lip service. If that means that both parties agree that Monica remains un-modded, then I can live with that decision. But please, take the time to do this *right*, because so far nothing has been.

And until such time as there is real, *public* visibility of addressing what was done badly, my diamond shall remain in the drawer.

Comment: *She was held up as the bad guy* ... that sentence +1

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times, but a +1 is all I have. This is extremely well-written, thank you. Using the pronoun that someone asks you to use seems like common decency to me. It's the least I can do and I will happily agree with any Code of Conduct that requires it. Firing someone because they violated the "intent" of a yet-unpublished CoC is another matter that has nothing to do with pronouns or grammar.

Comment: Nicely written Jane. I don't personally participate in the workplace but interpersonal conflict ends up being a large part of my day job (project manager/scrum master) and watching all this unfold has blown my mind...none of the basics of dealing with problems like this were done.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm the most apolitical person you'll find, but wrong is wrong. While many have perceived my actions as only being because Monica is a moderator, my stance would be exactly the same irrespective of who they are. My actions are _for_ my community and its members, not in spite of them. I never want to see this happen to anyone again, and SE _must_ accept that they need to address this properly and do better in future. Don't let there be a next time.

Comment: I _am_ one of those letters and I find what happened to Monica outrageous. It has been like watching a train derail in slow motion and made me not want to participate on the site. I doubt I am the only "regular" user who feels that way. This is a start, maybe even a good start, but there ought to be _real_ consequences and _real_ change. Monica ought to get her diamond back as a matter of course before any process starts.

Comment: @NateBarbettini: Just to be clear, I think Monica also supported the *intent* behind the new CoC: to make sure nobody is misgendered by using the wrong pronouns for them.  But Monica as a writer objects to singular "they", and wanted to honour intent the CoC by *never* using any singular pronouns, including "she" or "he", when moderating.  The debate that got her fired was apparently over sentences that could have been phrased to use a pronoun: the new CoC apparently implies they must.  See [her comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update?cb=1#comment1094626_334257)

Comment: Thanks, @thebjorn. I'm *at least* one of those letters ("LGBTIQAP+" is new to me, but my sexuality and gender are all over the place, so I must be in there somewhere!), and I'm horrified by what happened to Monica. So are other ... um, gender-nonconforming? ... users who have commented. You're not alone. By abandoning anything resembling the legal notion of *mens rea* - which, although admittedly difficult to apply, is firmly based on common sense and natural justice - this Code of Conduct inevitably becomes unjust and arbitrary, and succeeds only in fuelling the bigotry it pretends to oppose.

Comment: it's a shame that you got banned

Answer (score 384):

This apology <strike>seems to be sincere but</strike> leaves me <strike>with questions. I am not</strike> overly cynical <strike>and believe people can decide to do better and move on from there</strike>. This appears to be doing that.

**One elephant left in the room:**

The real concern is dealing with the gravity of statements made **to the press** against someone working for SE voluntarily. Specifically, as of now, the top google search item for Monica's name is an accusation from SE "the company" about Monica being unwilling to comply with a code of conduct against bigotry. That's not going to look so good in a job interview.

For the foreseeable future Monica will have to face questions that come with being "the person SE accused of being a bigot" resulting in her having to explain how this really wasn't the case and to please see so-and-so additional reference that clarifies it.

Even in the (<strike>in</strike>conceivable) event that SE upholds Monica's dismissal, for the sake of current mods *and* for anyone else considering becoming a mod and volunteering their time and energy for SE, please notify all users how this public statement against Monica is being handled so that we know **it's safe to invest our time and energy here** and if something like this slips it *can* be handled.

<strike>I trust that it</strike> probably <strike>won't</strike> happen again <strike>but just want to make sure.</strike>

**EDIT (11 Oct 19):**

After [recent sentiments forwarded by the Director of Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335173/se-inc-director-of-public-qa-retweets-bad-faith-misrepresentative-tweet) and the prior *two weeks* of poor community interaction, I am really starting to wonder if this is some kind of (very mis-guided) technique to increase exposure for SE... it's getting pretty old, and it's a real shame Monica is dragged into it.

Based on some [SEDE analysis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335163/how-often-is-gender-actually-used-in-comments) it seems this whole shenanigan isn't really going to produce much difference to warrant this HUGE, dramatic network wide policy change anyway.  On SO there are **0.658%** of comments in a month that use a non-neutral pronoun and the VAST majority of these arguable could have been used *correctly*.

Can't we just keep flagging things we find offensive? Do we really need to [lose a significant portion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) of our moderator power to pre-emptively handle **0.01%** of posts that a flag can handle anyway? (providing there are still mods to handle flags)

Well I guess we do if we want to increase SE exposure as being the "vanguard" of "inclusion and respect".

Personally, the CoC change hardly effects me, I have used a non-neutral pronoun twice in the last 8 years, woops. (If you're curious [you can check yours here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1124222/user-specific-gendered-comment-count)). So I really don't have a problem complying. I just can't credit this violent change and heavy-handed treatment of this issue as anything other than a public relations campaign. It certainly couldn't be a "mistake" as Mr. Fullerton says above.

Not to mention a campaign that is still [being pushed heavily on other platforms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335173/se-inc-director-of-public-qa-retweets-bad-faith-misrepresentative-tweet) despite [all the collateral damage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper).

Comment: "I am not overly cynical and believe people can decide to do better and move on from there." They can but will they? Only the future can decide how sincere that was.  I like to judge people by their actions not their announcements.

Comment: @Trilarion very true. The huge delay for even initial contact mentioned by the OP is not looking so great right now. Elephant is bigger than I thought or maybe tied up with the CoC feedback?

Comment: *"For the foreseeable future Monica will have to face questions that come with being "the person SE accused of being a bigot" resulting in her having to explain how this really wasn't the case and to please see so-and-so additional reference that clarifies it."* I think [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps#comment1095769_334551) says it all. Apparently people hoping to avoid misgendering with the backing of a written Code of Conduct are "trolls with a disgusting cause".

Comment: @Renan Are you sure you interpreted that comment correctly? I took it to mean the complete opposite.

Comment: @Renan I also read it as Monica is now being harassed by far-right trolls who want to hold her up as a martyr of their cause.

Comment: I can't agree that the timing of reinstatement is "inconsequential". To reinstate her now, even if it meant firing her again later, would be the real admission of wrongdoing on SE's part. Reinstating her later, after some review would appear to be doubling down on their initial response. It's a matter of _huge_ consequence.

Comment: "I ... believe people can decide to do better and move on from there" As Bertrand Russell wrote, the definition of "belief" is "that for which there is no evidence".

Comment: @Renan incorrect.  I'm being targeted by extreme bigots who want me to join their cause to make the world safe for straight white American men or the like.  (Those folks tend to hate Jews too, but I guess they overlooked that.)  I moderate anonymous comments on my blog (didn't need to before!), so trust me when I say that you are not seeing what I'm seeing.  There have also been comments on SE (now flagged and deleted).

Comment: Really? People use their status on SE on their resumes?

Comment: @Kristopher If you're applying for a Developer position, and your interviewer is a developer themselves, then it's quite common for them to request links to your Github or StackOverflow profiles

Comment: +1 and that database lookup you linked is some kind of magic to a simple folk like me.

Comment: "I have used a non-neutral pronoun twice in the last 8 years, woops. (If you're curious you can check yours here)." Interesting. Apparently I have used them dozens of times, but almost exclusively in quoting others. One time was to refer to a hypothetical example actor who had already been named "Tim" by the OP, and one was to refer to Raymond Hettinger of the Python core development team. Other than that, the last time I "messed up" was in 2014, when I used "s/he" as an impersonal pronoun for a hypothetical person. Genderless writing really isn't hard (although my 2012 self didn't care).

Answer (score 264):

> - On Monday, October 7, we’ll be sharing a second draft of an update to our Code of Conduct with all moderators for feedback
> - On Thursday, October 10, the update to the Code of Conduct will be announced publicly

Is that really enough time to gather and iterate on feedback? If you have a "release date", and somebody finds a "bug" on Wednesday, the 9th, what then? Do you publish the new CoC anyway? What's the rush?

Comment: Exactly. It was just this sort of haste that caused the last, um, little hiccup.

Comment: Presumably the implementation date will be somewhat after the 10th, and as the pseudo-MIT licensing fiasco showed, they *can* react quickly to objections by delaying the implementation.

Comment: Indeed.  The CoC was not the actual problem, the underlying issue has been afoot for years.  Afaict, management ought to think about what they can do to make SO employees successful again.

Comment: I don't understand the rush, either. Sara Chipps posted her infamous "apology" in the TL for the moderators there to see it ahead of time, but for some reason only waited *6 minutes* before posting it for the public. If she'd waited a little longer for feedback maybe it wouldn't have been quite such a disaster.

Comment: That was my immediate reaction as well. The timing suggests moderator input is a formality, not a genuine attempt to integrate feedback. And the fact that this is the only actual action in the post makes the whole post seem like appeasement rather than genuine apology.

Comment: TL;DR I'm staying

Comment: Sonic the PRHog Says: "Gotta post fast!"

Comment: The obvious answer is that there will be no changes to the CoC. It will be posted to meta for people to feel involved but nobody will care about the responses. It's been made clear before that the contents of the CoC are not up for discussion in any way.

Comment: Agreed. Danger of too fast. And were the people from communities supposedly protected by these new CoCs who volunteered to work with SO (for example during the annual survey when asked if would help SO going forwards) engaged with? I haven't seen mention of this but haven't scanned all the traffic on this subject.

Comment: @Null Fully agree, though the word disaster is a 
understatement - that poorly phrased 'apology' was rather a infernal cataclysm..

Comment: Remember also that Yom Kippur lasts until midnight on the 9th. To highlight (to me at least) think of this like SE announcing major changes on Christmas Eve and will release their decision on Boxing day. Might sound like it makes so difference except the lady at the heart of this is a practicing Jew.

Comment: if you know beforehand that you will not amend the CoC as a reaction of community feedback then yes, it is enough time. There is nothing in SEs past behaviour that makes me think that there is the slightest chance that they will listen to us this time.

Comment: @sth You've been proven right by today's series of events.

Comment: Thank you for the generous bounty you awarded an answer of mine yesterday and for acknowledging its small role during this era of conflicts. The bounty was totally unexpected.

Answer (score 238):

<s>Thank you.</s>

Comment: To the mod(s) that completely cleaned up this comment thread: that was a poor move...

Comment: @code_dredd There was stuff that should've been got rid of, and it's difficult to selectively clean up threads whilst continuing to appear impartial. That aside, I do miss some of them.

Comment: *"it's difficult to ... appear impartial"* Not deleting the comments is also a valid option, especially if there're concerns about partiality, such as this question. Also, if they wanted to "appear impartial", then they would've had to not only delete the comments, but also your "answer", b/c [we've known since at least as far back as 2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/08/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer) that "thank you"s posted as "answers" have always been frowned upon. (Im)Partiality is revealed by the rules, when/how they're applied, and by being consistent (i.e. no double-standard).

Comment: @code_dredd That's talking about thank you answers posted by the user who asked a question, to thank an answerer. And I don't doubt that, if the comments were deleted by a mSE mod, it was an impartial action. Can we take this to chat?

Comment: I'm fine taking that to chat if you feel so inclined. My response times may vary, though.

Comment: I thought changing ones answer/question like this was not allowed? Should the original answer be restored? "It's fine because Joel Spolsky did it that one time. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116918/404278"

Comment: I'm going to have to replace my upvote with a downvote here, as it's been over a week with no significant results... Sadly, this has been yer another instance of empty words.

Comment: @Cerbrus They're designing the process for removing moderators, and actually asking for our input before making it public this time – ironically, that's serving to hurt their image even though it's a better process and good precedent. (I'll be honest, though; I'd prefer it if they'd done more than what they've done by now. But these words aren't entirely empty, at least.)

Comment: For reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/337495

Comment: -1 because after seeing the two tier reinstatement process, I cannot possibly allow Fullerton &Co to even grasp at any numbers that appear to even marginally support them. I encourage others to downvote this “Thank you.” message too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I understand that sentiment perfectly… but why do you say "two tier"? As far as I can tell, [there's only one tier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336175/308065) to the process, since everybody's treated the same.

Comment: Ironic, do people still want to thank and up vote now? Or, they just want to down vote this twice now?

Comment: @EricWang I've had downvotes every day since the day after I posted it. I'm mildly surprised how many people have been downvoting it, and even more surprised that it's still above the majority of answers here.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm not surprised that people would down vote it now, just like how the question change from +500 votes to -90 downs.

Comment: I will retain my upvote since this was one of the rare occasions where these words made perfect sense and should be considered on-topic. I won't let SE's further (in-)actions influence my vote in retrospect. EDIT: thinking about it, these words now get a whole different and cynical meaning.

Comment: Any reason, why this “no answer” wasn’t deleted by moderators?

Comment: @MiFreidgeimSO-stopbeingevil This is meta. You'll have noticed that there wasn't a question, either. (And I'm not certain I condone this answer any more, but I'm leaving it up.)

Comment: The information in this “post” may be acceptable in Meta as a comment, but not enough for the answer.

Answer (score 223):

From this post you've clearly shown that you still know how to engage with the community so I'm genuinely interested regarding why this sort of statement wasn't drafted originally and you opted to go with the original one which caused further controversy?

Did you really think the original one would go down better (sort of testing the waters so to speak to see how compliant people are)?

---

If you are in an answering mood, to quote [Sébastien Renauld](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/205798/s%c3%a9bastien-renauld):

> There's something that still doesn't sit well with me; you said you wanted to act quickly on a moderator removal. **What was the risk that required fast action?**

(emphasis mine)

---

<sub>This is not me bashing, I'm genuinely interested in the thought process (or lack thereof) behind it.</sub>

Comment: In the worst-case scenario, this apology could be an attempt to cause a cover-up of that earlier, more controversial post. I'd like to assume that's not the reasoning.

Comment: That "risk that required fast action" almost certainly isn't something they can say in public. They haven't even told the mods, and there's plenty us mods can't tell the rest of the community.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Still, something about this apology doesn't sit right with me - it took them well over a reasonable amount of time to post this. You can't sit here and tell me that's not even the least bit suspicious.

Comment: @connectyourcharger I've been drafting something similar to just _parts_ of this letter, and I haven't managed to get it finished. Just _writing_ the damn thing would've taken hours and hours, and a corporate bureaucracy known to be terrible at making decisions on top of that?

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm not looking for the specifics *for this case*. I'm looking for causes that'd force a break in flow and procedures.

Comment: Because this one required a professional consultant to write it and is not cheap. They didn't know how bad things were until after the first update flopped. Once the C-suite is involved and needs to make a statement, you pay money to make sure you don't screw up.

Comment: @StrongBad Good observation. Every bit of the post smells of pro work. Even the timing and the lovely family picture is suspect.

Comment: @berendi _"suspect"_? I'm pretty sure that has been David's avatar for awhile now. I can't tell if you're being sarcastic here.

Comment: @StrongBad well if it is pro work, [George should get a cut](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334263/176101)

Comment: @connectyourcharger Never ascribe to malice what you can ascribe to mere negligence and ineptitude.

Comment: @StrongBad Do you have any basis for thinking this was written by a paid outsider beyond thinking it'd be the sensible thing for them to have done and/or how the text of the post itself feels to you? Given that you're a mod, it's hard to tell whether you're going on inside information the rest of us can't see or are judging from the same surface appearances visible to the rest of us.

Comment: @MarkAmery no mod info. I also didn't mean my comment to be an insult or take away from the apology. It still takes work from SE to come up with the themes and solutions. The pro only guides and process and polishes the text.

Comment: @StrongBad Roger. My take, for what it's worth, is that this is unlikely to be an outsider's work. There are skilled writers on the CM team, and no reason to bring in someone else to do their job.

Comment: Most writers (who have any substantial body of work) have certain "tells".  They're hard to describe explicitly (usually you don't *notice* them consciously), but I see a couple SE folks' hands in this message.  I don't think they farmed it out.

Comment: @berendi That's a rather cynical accusation. See https://web.archive.org/web/20190331035403/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146719/david-fullerton - that photo is months old.

Comment: Would it be cynical, ironic, or something else for the 'official' apology to be flagged as violating the Code of Conduct.  Not to tear open an old wound, I'm coming to the controversy late and have been trying to catchup.

Comment: @KellyS.French ironic. Definitely ironic. But, to be fair, as we've seen, SE likes others to follow these rules, but don't you dare try to hold them to the same standards.

Answer (score 203):

I was a moderator, who's [just resigned](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9355/31503) due to the erosion of trust I feel has happened as a result of this issue.

But, there are some things to note as it relates to the above apology...

This apology has come not a moment too soon.... for the past days, almost a week, now, moderators from across most sites have collaborated on communicating our concerns to the SE staff. We have been working "in plain sight" of the SE staff (using the TL to collaborate).

The apology above addresses most, if not all the concerns that we have raised as a group effort.

The timing of this apology appears to have been in a race to beat our statements about the issues.

Note that the SE staff have not been collaborating, corresponding, or feeding back in any way on our collaboration, but appear to have just been observing.

While the apology above indicates the desire to collaborate with mods again, there has been nothing of the sort in the past few days, so I expect there to be an interesting discussion tomorrow .....

Update: ArtOfCode's meta [post sharing the statement signed by many moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334575/241497)

Comment: +1 for linking to ArtOfCode's meta post. That's helpful to know about. I like the quote from the letter: *"Ultimately, we want to feel that we are safe to disagree with Stack Exchange, even on matters of major policy."*

Comment: This didn't age well. :-(

Comment: “the apology above indicates the desire to collaborate with mods again“. A month later, do you still believe in “the desire to collaborate”?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim - I resigned a while back, and I am out of the loop (or as much or as little as I was in it at the time). I don't know what's happening. I am still active on Code Review site, but for the most part, I am ignoring Meta for my own sanity :) It has been nice to not have to worry.

Answer (score 182):

While this apology is a good first step, there are still some serious issues that remain unresolved.

1. Monica Cellio should not have had her moderator status removed without due process.  I believe that she should have her moderator status reinstated wherever it was summarily removed, pending action to be initiated by SE by the *appropriate channels* to have it removed , or pending Monica's request that it be removed once more should she no longer desire to be a community moderator.  Should neither party now desire that Monica's moderator status be removed, she should not have to apply to have it reinstated.
2. Monica was mentioned by her real name in a statement to the media made by a SE employee.  As the nature of this statement was negative, there may be further-reaching consequences to Monica than her alleged infraction (whatever it was) likely warranted.  Certainly, *no-one* has accused Monica of any wrongdoing other than a supposed breach of SE's code of conduct, so, since using her name in a negative fashion in a press release was unwarranted, Stack Exchange has a duty to issue a retraction and apology to Monica via the same media outlet through which they made their first, unwarranted press release.
3. I believe that this entire matter was caused by the hasty, ill-considered and unilateral actions of a single Stack Exchange employee, or at most a small number of employees.  I would hope that the employee(s) will be disciplined appropriately, and if their employment with Stack Exchange continues, that they will not remain in a position in which they may repeat or compound their recent mistakes.  I would also hope that whatever action Stack Exchange takes with respect to the employee(s), it will not be publicised... a mere "We have taken appropriate disciplinary action against the employee(s) responsible," from SE will be sufficient; there is no need for this shameful matter to receive any more of a public airing than necessary.  However, the employee(s) responsible have caused a great breach of trust between SE and the community upon which it relies, and the continued involvement of the employee(s) in question with the community is unlikely to help to restore that trust.

**EDIT**

4. The Stack Exchange platform needs to be modified so that it does not allow community-elected moderators to be removed from their post(s) unilaterally by any one person, *even an employee of Stack Exchange*.  The only mechanism by which a moderator should be able to be removed is by the established process for removal of a moderator.  Of course, a person with database access could override the user interface's restrictions, but in my experience as a software developer, no developer would have any legitimate reason to alter live data in such a manner without orders.

Comment: I presume a process to remove a mod should involve a suspension of mod powers during an inquiry. It makes more sense that Monica should be placed *there*, then the process continues as it should have originally. Kind of like being arrested, then you have a trial.

Comment: `Stack Exchange has a duty to issue a retraction and apology to Monica via the same media outlet through which they made their first, unwarranted press release.` **YES**

Comment: @fredsbend, at present there is no such mechanism, though it seems to be a reasonable feature to add in order to prevent a genuinely misbehaving mod from doing any further damage.  However, I would add the suggestion that the mod so affected would still *appear* to be a mod until voted out of office.

Comment: Point 4 seems like a moonshot.

Comment: @Richard, True... but recent events have shown it to be necessary.   Had such a feature existed already, we wouldn't have this post or any of the others that led up to it.

Comment: @MontyWild - You might as well ask for a unicorn

Comment: I'm not agreeing with this post. Whatever happens to Monica should be discussed between Monica and SE. I agree that SE should comply with (1) and (2) *if* she so wishes, but that kind of follows from the apology as well. Similarly, I think that how this is handled internally is up to SE. We don't know how this was handled internally before this and how hard people have been affected - even if that was (at least partially) their own fault. SE must of course avoid repetition of the incidents, but *how* this is done is internal policy, not something we should try and dictate.

Comment: They didn't "issue a press release to a media outlet", The Register reached out to them for comment and they provided one. Quite different things.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes re "I agree that SE should comply with (1) and (2) if she so wishes": she so wishes.  We can *then* discuss further changes, but as I said in a [post on Friday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334427/162102), we need to roll back to the last good state before the process failures.  *Then* we can talk about how to proceed from there.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Right, as I indicated, I wanted you to be in control rather than somebody else making up your mind for it. If you've made up your mind then I'm all for reinstating you before anything else. And I presume you indicated this to SE, which means the communication has started. I'm sincerely hoping it is not a false start.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes there has been no communication from SE yet.  All I can do is make my wishes known here.  (I also sent in a "contact us" form about this, though I've no idea if anybody looked at it.  All of my attempts to contact them in the last two weeks have met with silence.)

Comment: I don't agree with point 3. Stack Exchange is responsible, Mr. Fullerton as CTO is responsible, and acknowledges this. If an employee took a wrong decision, that may be due to many different causes: too much workload, insufficient or improper training, insufficient internal procedures, etc. If SE would proceed with "we've fired employee X" and then then they'd be trying to shift blame to an individual employee where the company is responsible, again seeking a scapegoat. In my opinion, that would only make matters *worse*, not better.  Stand up for your moderators *and* your staff, please.

Comment: Speaking as a programmer: Point #4 is more or less impossible, at least for a project like SE.

Comment: @phyzome, also speaking as a programmer, point 4 is *by no means* impossible.  Not necessarily easy... but not necessarily all that difficult either.

Comment: @gerrit, All I ask for in Point 3 is that Stack Exchange discipline their staff.  I don't care - or even want to know - whether they fire, reassign or re-educate... but the events in question have shown that at least one employee showed poor judgement that has endangered another person, and has brought disrepute to the company, and such actions typically attract disciplinary action.  For SE to fail to do so would be indicative that such behaviour is condoned... and if they condone such behaviour, do any of us want to be involved with them any more?

Comment: OK, maybe I overstated my point. No, it's not technically impossible, but the cost/benefit ratio of that kind of system is usually so high that it's impracticable. I think it's a rare org that can manage to not have a hands-on DBA. Perhaps I should have said "unachievable" instead.

Comment: @TylerH So what if The Register reached out to them?  "No Comment" is a valid response, as is (to a lesser degree) "We removed moderator status from a person whom we will not name for reasons of privacy...".  To give a response which *named* the de-modded person was *irresponsible* at best.

Comment: @phyzome, The DBA should not be a person who interacts with the community, so any request for a direct data change with respect to one user would have to come from another employee whose responsibility is community interaction... and a good DBA would be asking "Can't you do that through the UI?  No?  Then why should I do that on *your* say-so?"  Additionally, many companies make live data off-limits to manual modification, in order to change live data, all sorts of hoops must be jumped through to push a change from a dev environment, through testing, to production.

Comment: As to the cost/benefit of my Point 4, had such a feature existed, Monica would not have had her name publicly dragged through the mud in direct contravention to SE's own protocols, a great many community mods would not have resigned or gone on strike, and SE wouldn't have suffered a great reputation hit.  If it were up to me, such a feature would be top priority right now... SE *can't* afford a repeat of this debacle.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Hi Monica. I can only express my disbelief that you haven't been contacted by SE yet. I guess we have to force their hand on this too, or take other drastic action. Have a good holiday, and I hope to see you back as <> soon.

Comment: @MontyWild I'm not saying what Stack Overflow the company did was fine; in fact I'm shocked that Sara didn't immediately redirect the company to their legal or PR department rather than issuing an unsanctioned, unreviewed response herself. I agree the response from Sara is terribad for *myriad* reasons. What I'm saying is they didn't *reach out to The Register* and say "hey have we got a scoop for you"; The Register reached out directly to Sara by email, soliciting a comment.

Comment: @TylerH, That's completely irrelevant. Regardless of who reached out to whom, *a statement was made to the press that included Monica's name in a negative light.*  In pretty much every company in which I have worked, it has been drummed into every employee that unless your job description is "Press Liason", *you never say **anything** to the press other than 'I can't comment,  you should talk to X'.* where X is whoever is responsible for that.

Comment: @MontyWild It's not irrelevant, it's literally the entire point of my concern. There is a big difference between "an employee made a statement in response to a direct inquiry via email" and "SO contacted a news company and gave an interview".

Comment: @TylerH, Then we'll have to agree to disagree.  As I see it, a statement was made to the press. It doesn't matter who instigated the statement,  since the end result was that Monica's involvement in what was up to that moment a private dispute became a matter of public record, and not in her favour either. How do we really know that it happened that way?  For all we know,  someone might be lying about who approached whom.

Comment: “this entire matter was caused by the hasty, ill-considered and unilateral actions of a single Stack Exchange employee.” Do you mean the  Director of Public Q&A at Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 154):

[image]

This is a plot of the total score (upvotes minus downvotes) of this announcement. The difference from the previous day's total score is shown in green (positive, above the y-axis `0`) or red (negative, below the y-axis `0`).

---

On the left, we believed your apology. We thought you were sincere and wanted to fix this.

On the right we realised you were just saying this to pacify us again, and do not care about the community. Your words were empty, and simply there to get our guard down and then spring the CoC changes on us.

This is *not* how to handle a community. If you're going to make promises like this, stick to them.

Comment: I think it's backwards and upside down.

Comment: -5 pts – no axis labels. Also, without freehand red circles, I have no idea what the text is referring to :P

Comment: @divibisan just for you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsbn4.jpg

Comment: It took me quite a while to figure out what this plot is. Please include an explanation.

Comment: @Tim Oh! It's so much clearer now! You'll have my upvote once 5pm rolls around

Comment: I feel like a [waterfall chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_chart) could be a better visualization.

Comment: @Giuseppe https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1fQg.png perhaps

Comment: I don't understand what the blue color mean

Comment: @wada the blue in the graph is the overall score of the post.  Eg, if you have 100 upvotes and 10 down votes, your score is +90 (the upvotes minus the downvotes is 100 - 10 = 90).  At first there were significantly more upvotes than downvotes, hence a positive score.  After a few days this turned into a rapid downvote trend until eventually there were more downvotes (and hence a negative score).

Comment: Time to update the chart.... The downvotes continue to flow.

Answer (score 142):

This is the third time now SE has failed in gathering feedback from the moderators on this topic.

The first time was when you dumped the announcement into the Teachers' Lounge (TL).

The second time was when you posted the previous non-apology to the TL, ignored all feedback and just posted it on Meta only 6 minutes later.

The third time started very well, the draft of the CoC change gathered a lot of feedback, and that feedback actually was incorporated and the language was changed.

What we didn't know at that time was the content of the FAQ that was published along with the actual CoC change, we didn't even know there would be one. And that one contains all the meat of the change, all the controversial details that we had already discussed in thousands of messages in the chat.

None of the feedback of the moderators changed anything about the actual rules that SE wanted to enact, as those are not actually encoded in the language of the Code of Conduct. All the feedback SE actually asked for was entirely about the language and the packaging of the changes, the substance remained entirely untouched.

Comment: Spot on. I didn't get to see behind the scenes for what wording changed when, but no matter how much language they dress it up in or sugar coat it to be easier to swallow the fundamental thing they are trying to accomplish is unchanged. Even if it's harder to see in the "letter of the law" of the final CoC wording the spirit that produced it hasn't changed as evidenced by the faq.

Comment: Exactly. All the bad parts just went from the CoC to the FAQ.

Comment: And the helpful comments SE staff made in chat didn't make the blog or the FAQ. Really quite bewildering.

Comment: Very much this. This whole thing started with a decree from SE to moderators. Eventually, we got back into a collaborative mode. I think the actual, textual changes to the CoC reflect input from a good number of mods from different communities with different backgrounds. We were aware that there would be a blog post introducing it, but not a FAQ. I'm sure we could have identified major gaps or questions that people are most upset about and given SE a chance to clarify or correct or reconsider before dropping it on the world.

Comment: To top this off, the amount of rude comments and chat messages has gone significantly up compared to "normal". this was apparently mishandled in multiple ways. Again.

Comment: When the director of q/a personal kpi is how much people they can ignore, there's no much hope https://twitter.com/SaraJChipps/status/1182650441882058752?s=09

Answer (score 137):

While the whole thing is a breath of fresh air, I wanted to underscore one of the points

> Third, we hurt the moderators and members of our communities. Community moderation is the backbone of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, and our moderators are a vital part of us creating a more welcoming and inclusive place. We need to be working with our moderators and community, rather than working against them, in order to create the kind of community where everyone feels welcome and able to share their knowledge.

I really wish this had been said sooner. As I [said elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334015/an-open-letter-on-the-state-of-curation-and-moderation) SO has been really heavy on the "smack moderators down to make new users feel welcome". Curators and moderators should not be your enemy (least of all a top contributor who is well respected) and this week we've been close to that.

Comment: Speaking as a moderator who felt personally betrayed these past days, I don't care how long it took, I'm just happy it arrived.

Comment: "smack moderators down to make new users feel welcome".

Both provide the same number of clicks. Same number of ad impressions. So to an idiot investor, they are worth the same. They are trading moderator good will for a broader userbase which will give them a short term boost in revenue.

Comment: It's not that we wanted it said sooner as such. We wanted it said instead of Sara's post. Now, it has arrived. That's good. Let's give them time to do as they have said.

Answer (score 126):

Whatever that you do with the new CoC, just:

- Don't be heavyhanded or take offense from things that most users think are normal behaviour or that could be done out of cluelessness instead of malice.
- Making everything peaceful and nice is more important than making a war just to stand an argument, regardless of whether the argument is right or not.
- Doing it right is more important than doing it hastily.
- Don't forget that many people don't speak English well, and we even have a few sites that aren't on English after all.
- Listen to all your moderators and users. Even when they disagree or defend what it seems to be strange for someone be defending, there are valid points worth considering.

Answer (score 125):

You *look* to be owning your statements here.  You *look* to be owning what happened here.  You *look* like you wish to improve or make improvements to this somewhat broken system already.

This is a **positive step** in the right direction, so I'll play nice and share about what you're going to expect from me as a power user, and one of the users who has been hurt by this.

You don't have my trust because **I don't have any patience to wait for these communication improvements anymore**.  The good will and credit that Stack Exchange has been exercising [has already dipped negative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386324/1079354), and yet again the expectation here seems to be that I should take your word that things will get better and I should be patient while you work through these changes.

By and large there have been earth-shattering events that have happened between the Welcome Wagon and all of this mess, which have widened a rift between how power users see the company listening to their feedback/pleas/cries for help and the overall goals of the company itself.

To put it bluntly, while a lot of the angst over the last week or so has been about the way y'all dismissed a moderator (which you own and are making amends for now), there's been a brewing tension over how users just [don't feel like they're being heard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373160/1079354), and I wonder if some of this boiled over into the whole circumstance.

But I call it out here and now because I see shades of the same.  The power users of the Stack Exchange Network definitely deserve a seat at the table to help understand how the changes to the CoC would impact their site.

Your timeline for rolling out the new CoC is *incredibly* aggressive.  So much so that I'm genuinely unconvinced that there hasn't been enough thought or input to how technical Exchange sites are going to be assisted with this.  Put another way, on Stack Overflow (where I'm primarily based), I would edit out any mention to another user's orientation or sexual preferences **as noise**; when you're programming, the compiler/interpreter which is giving you a bewildering error doesn't care who you are, and I see no value in doing so either in that context.

Note that I don't have a problem with the alleged rule change at face value.  I'm perfectly fine with ensuring that people of all walks of life are respected and treated with dignity here.

But I take ***extreme*** umbrage to edits which pertain to gender made unnecessarily on a technical Exchange site.

With that said...I'm going to make this brutally clear.

## I will permanently cease participation if I cannot help cleanly enforce this new CoC.

If applying the rules can no longer be consistent on the site I'm most familiar with, then participation with my reputation level becomes fundamentally impossible.

Comment: Yes, the new CoC timeline is aggressive, but they don't really want questions about it or any feedback other than "looks good and I fully support that." When Monica had questions, you can see what they did to her. They aren't undoing that.  Her experience remains a warning against anyone else trying something similar in the future. A few days is plenty of time for what they are actually looking for.

Comment: If you don't want an answer, don't leave enough space/time for anyone to question it. Then you can respond to criticisms with, "why didn't you speak up *before* we implemented it?"

Answer (score 109):

> ## Update 6.11.19:
>
> ([Related update, 30.10.19](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333992/332043))
>
> For those of you who either don't pay attention or missed it, someone leaked info about a future change announced on the internal moderator team. It was initially posted here on the network, but currently lives on through the internet archive and Reddit (r/stackoverflow).
>
> While I'm not going to link it directly (or mention any details aside the existence of a leak, because I'd like to keep this answer alive), I believe this change would've been received about as badly as some of the other major changes in the current environment. Presented later, it might've been fine, but presenting it without resolving the existing issues is basically pouring gasoline next to a spreading fire, thinking "it won't come here!"
>
> The change is likely to spark another controversy, and once again risk the targeting of another underrepresented group in tech. SE's intentions are good, but once again, the execution is (would've been, technically) awful.
>
> The CoC update - intended to protect LGBTQ users - sparked events that made it less safe for us. SE was once the safest place on the internet, and I really liked it because it wasn't a safe space. It was a place where different beliefs, opinions, and not to forget identities could live together - differences aside. At least on technical sites (samples from SO, SU, AU, vi.SE), but also meta (samples from MSO and MSE).
>
> Unfortunately, the CoC change brought out the worst aspects of people because it turned into a complete mess of multiple problems that were bundled up into a massive ball of frustration and anger. Off the top of my head, Monica's removal (central aspect), the problems Aza mentions, the (at one point) "future, mysterious, unannounced CoC change", as well as ads, and the underlaying frustration caused by a lack of communication, and for many at least core users, [frustration with old, unscaled systems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385023/6296561), the change of the SO front page to what can only be described as a paywall for people who aren't users, and probably more I've left out. Throwing more onto this pile of crap isn't in anyone's best interest at the moment.
>
> Moreover, [SE isn't responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334575/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators#comment1122325_334575) and I'm starting to doubt many of their statements. There are still a few staff members that interact with the community in an outright exemplary way - and I need to mention this because, in spite of a lot of things being crap at the moment, not all the people are awful. This is speculation, but I believe some form of management order is messing up a lot of the communication.
>
> But to the point: Shog and Yaakov are the employees I'm talking about. Yaakov is taking point on the post notice rollout - a rather major change in a heated climate, but it's still handled fantastically. Shog generally has an ability to calm down heat, at least in my experience. Additionally, posts involving Shog (notably the 3 close vote experiment) rarely gets ignored. The research results were delayed, but when people asked about a status, they actually got answers. It's not like with the deadlocked open letter situation, in which it appears SE is ignoring the letters, mainly because the person involved (Sara) is unresponsive. There's been multiple requests on a status, all of which have been ignored.
>
> I'm not trying to hang out Sara here, but on another post where she was involved (in all fairness, along with Tim Post - but a recent comment has made me doubt whether he actively ignored comments or not. The comment is completely unrelated, but it established some trust), concerns were ignored. For those who aren't aware, [this is the question, well, specifically change I'm talking about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387546/6296561).
>
> We can only speculate why this happens. Automatically blaming management isn't a good idea, nor is it constructive, but when there's a clear difference in responsiveness depending on which employee, I do get suspicious.
>
> My weirdly phrased point: On the 30th, I decided leave within the next two weeks. I'm still here for the next week, because the network has become a slight addiction I need to manage. The reasons for that are mine alone, and I won't discuss these.
>
> I've tried being nice, I've tried being provocative, I've tried expressing frustration, and I've helped create pressure - none of these things have worked so far, and I'm getting tired of it. The only thing that can turn the situation around is SE, but I currently have no belief they'll take the situation under control.

---

> **Note:** Since this answer was posted, things have taken a different direction. Feedback from moderators on the CoC [got ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335133/332043), communication is still broken, lots of critical posts go unacknowledged, [a tweet from the director of public Q&A caused further drama](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335173/332043), communication between Monica and the company has [allegedly broken down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334646/332043), and the situation has overall gotten significantly more heated. To top this off, a shortage of moderators let the worst people continue because things simply cannot be handled fast enough. This isn't the moderators' fault - the problem lies in fewer mods and an ever-increasing stream of content.
>
> I still stand by what I've said in this post, but the situation didn't go the way I expected. This is also why I added this note. The CoC release was handled about as horribly as the problems leading up to this situation, which has caused significantly more hate and toxicity, not just against LGBTQ, but against users in general. The apology seems pretty pointless now, because they did the *exact* same thing *again* with no regard for consequences, and without thinking about all the people on the other end of their actions.
>
> [It's time for this to end](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333992/332043), and it appears that the only way to get you (Stack Overflow, Inc) to listen is by applying pressure. I'll be continuing my strike until I see real, good-faith attempts to resolve this situation, as well as attempts to restore communication between users/mods and the company, preferably before the community gets damaged beyond recovery.
>
> And I'm going to say it a last time; you still have a chance of recovery, but you need to start taking action. If something is delayed and you know it is, say so publicly. And try to listen to people suggesting alternatives to improve the CoC further - you can still refine the details to allow users to survive if they make mistakes, make it technically possible for mods to enforce, and let users help without losing the intent behind the change. We want to help you, so please talk to us before everything starts collapsing. Until you do, people will continue to be angry, and either intentionally or without knowing it in a pure venting mode hurt real people. Regardless of who the CoC update aimed to help, it doesn't help anyone when the community turns on itself.
>
> Old answer:

This announcement earlier would've saved a lot of drama. Nevertheless, thank you for this.

The two initial attempts and rumors about the CoC did spark a lot of unwelcoming behavior against LGBTQ. I came out a couple years ago thanks to a user here on SE, and even after I came out with a name and avatar change, and when I (unrelated) later changed my avatar with a trans flag overlayed, no one reacted in an unwelcoming way.

I honestly expected a lot worse back then - as in some of the comments posted around this massive drama surrounding CoC discussions. But even in spite of that, most of the people I've run into on meta on my posts have actually been supportive (as in asking if they have questions and in a way that's, well, perfect). Hopefully, this will calm down now. And thank you for acknowledging that the way it was handled caused damage not just to LBGTQ, but to users and anyone else caught up in this. It might not undo what happened, but this is hope SE has a future.

I need to say this though; this announcement was a lot more than I expected. Fantastic apology aside, you laid out a schedule for future events, including the heavily debated CoC change. I'd love to see more of this in the future too. And hopefully, this is the beginning of an era with working communication between users and the company.

And, again (and I cannot say this enough):

## Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for having the courage to be publicly engaged throughout this process, which must have been difficult.  I've appreciated the posts & comments I've read from you over the past week.

Comment: Thank you indeed. Your engagement and feedback helps educate and give a more rounded view.

Comment: I've got a few (some very vocal!) trans friends and never knew there was a specific trans flag, thanks for educating me. Also want to reiterate @gung's comment above.

Comment: @DavidG you're welcome :) If you're interested, there's actually [a bunch of flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_symbols#LGBT_pride_flags) for other identities too (not just gender-related). I have no idea if that's a complete list or not, but it covers quite a few of them.

Comment: `The moderator reinstatement procedure has not been posted` - This is false. It has been shared with the moderators and we have provided feedback. Some of this feedback has already led to revisions and more clarity in the process for both removing and reinstating moderators. This is exactly what was promised in David's post.

Comment: Whatever you're referring to seems to have been deleted from /r/stackoverflow as well.

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica nope, it's still there. I'd link it, but last time I did (but to the internet archive though), it got nuked.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl, was it quite old?  I assumed you were referring to something recent, and I didn't see anything within the last couple weeks that was moderator-only on SE.

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica it was posted 3 days ago by u/LookWhatIFoundOnMeta

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl, oh now that's weird -- I can see it when I go to that user's profile, but r/stackoverflow/new doesn't list it -- it jumps straight from a post 13 hours ago to one seven days ago.  And moreover the link on the post to the screenshot seems to be broken.

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica eh, that's new reddit screwing up. Log in, or use `old.reddit.com` instead. No idea why that happens

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl, ah that did the trick, thank you!  I'm not much of a redditer so I didn't know that old/new reddit was a thing.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica answered. I'll definitely have to revise it tomorrow, when I'm more awake than now :]

Comment: @Zoe, thank you. Upvote this when you see it, & I'll delete it.

Answer (score 95):

> - On Monday, October 7, we’ll be sharing a second draft of an update to our Code of Conduct with all moderators for feedback

Given what happened to the last moderator who provided feedback... what exactly do you hope to accomplish with this?  Your past actions will inevitably have created a powerful chilling effect that will choke off honest feedback and discussion.  What guarantees can you provide that this will not happen again?

Comment: Nothing. Fullerton is telling us SE is going to do what they were planning to do anyway.

Comment: Can one of you brave mods ask whether writing in a gender-neutral fashion, so as to not misgender anyone, is acceptable under the new CoC?  I'm curious  :)

Comment: @kbelder since they still haven't answered Monica's questions (and have not contacted her as promised)...well, we'll see.  I think that this answer at least shows enough *awareness of how it will be received* (i.e. opposite of tone deaf) that I doubt they will follow through with a Thursday publication of the CoC changes, simply because of how bad it would look.  But, we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: @kbelder: As best as I can determine, it was asking that exact question that led to the firing in the first place, which seems to point to "No" as an answer.

Answer (score 92):

A move to welcome, but I wonder if any of it would have occurred without a massive community backlash.

It shouldn't take a moderator mass-exodus and overwhelming criticism to set things straight. If the staff truly has the community's interest at heart, they'll do it right the first time - or at least not massively betray claimed principles. Whether or not staff acted out of fear of loss or genuine regret isn't straightforward, but props to the community for not putting up with executive abuse.

Answer (score 92):

I see apologies for:

- hurting members of the LGBTQ+ community
- hurting Monica Cellio
- grossly offending many other mods and regular users
- stirring up a firestorm of drama

I see no apologies for:

- firing someone for merely asking clarifying questions about a planned CoC change
- publicly accusing that person of repeatedly violating the current CoC (seems libelous to me)

While you seem sincere about improving the things you apologized for, I get the impression that the things you didn't even mention - publicly denouncing someone's character after punishing them for merely questioning a potential policy change - are working as intended and will be par for the course from now on. You just want to do those things without anyone raising a fuss, like a child apologizing not for hitting their friend but for leaving a bruise that could be shown to a parent. You're not promising to stop hitting. You're promising that next time you'll use a sock with a bar of soap in it.

But hey, judging by all the praise this question is getting, it looks like your strategy is working beautifully, so... full speed ahead!

Comment: That's because "mods" are deleting negative comments. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334617/151144

Comment: @ChankeyPathak - That just links to the main question, as far as I can tell. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 77):

After reading through all the (good) answers, I would like to point out a (to me) scary part of this apology:

> We’ll keep those discussions completely private unless we both agree to share any of it with the community.

Translating this into normal language, this means: "We will talk to Monica in private, but only if she agrees to an NDA to keep it secret unless we give express permission."

This secrecy smells more like an attempt to silence Monica rather than an attempt to make right - I would be very careful to accept this if I were Monica.

The honest thing would have been to either reinstate Monica and let her decide if she wants to resign and (very) publicly retract any disparaging remarks about her and explain why she didn't get due process, or to come forward with proof why breaking the process was warranted, *at the very least in private to Monica, without any conditions attached*.

The fact that this hasn't already happened simply means this apology isn't one.

Answer (score 76):

Honestly, even as a conservative Christian with firm beliefs on sexuality, I haven't spent enough time thinking through how I can best speak with truth and love to those with a transgender or queer identity. I need to do that, and I'm grateful that this debacle is reminding me of that.

But here's what I do know:

- I will not [compel speech](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2233/15316).
- I will not enforce a CoC that compels speech.
- I will not agree to moderate a site if I am expected to compel people to use specific language that they are morally or otherwise unwilling to use.

If you don't want people like me moderating your sites – even if we have no personal objection to using "preferred" pronouns – that's fine.  Your site, your rules.  But you must realize that for some of us, this is about much more than how you mistreated Monica and others in the community.

Answer (score 75):

Thank you. Better late than never.
I just want to point out one thing about the new CoC:

> we’ll be sharing a second draft of an update to our Code of Conduct
>   with all moderators for feedback

**Shog9** has mentioned it in [Teachers Lounge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teachers-lounge) (TL), but how will the discussion process be going relatively to international sites? Will we have a chance to participate in this? Will we be able to discuss it on our local Meta sites?

Comment: International feedback is essential if there's anything related to pronouns in it.  More than two-thirds of the languages used on SE (French, German, Hebrew, Italian, Latin, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish, and Ukrainian) have a feature called "grammatical gender", while Japanese pronouns are very different from English ones.  It's very easy to accidentally write a code of conduct that requires non-grammatical or insulting writing in another language.

Comment: **This.** This has been a question I kept meaning to ask during this whole hullabaloo. Thanks for bring it up.

Comment: @Mark maybe a bit off-topic, but how are Japanese pronouns so very different? I see the usual ones: 私・私達 (I/we), あなた (you), 彼 (he), 彼女 (her), 彼ら (them). The usage conventions might be different (omitting most instances of first person or second person pronouns, for example). (Unless you're talking about gendered first person like 僕・俺, etc.)

Comment: @muru, the [usage conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_pronouns) are rather different: not only can you drop pronouns in many situations, you switch pronouns based on the relative status of the speaker and the audience, and on the desired level of formality and/or contempt, not to mention dialectical differences.

Comment: @Mark So what your saying is that pronouns in Japanese can *actually* be offensive.

Comment: Just an idle thought about cultural and language differences: I'm pretty sure that native Japanese speakers aren't offended by being referred as 彼女 (if not misgengered, of course), which is literally translates as 'he-woman'. While some foreign Japanese speakers may probably find it offending that the "base" pronoun is "he", while "her" has a "woman" part added almost as an afterthought.

Comment: Whatever is enforced about pronouns should be extended to names and adjectives when writing in Spanish, where they are usually gendered. The problem is that they don't have a neutral form. Well the grammatically masculine form used to be considered appropriate for neutral style but that seems to be no longer the case.

Comment: @Yaant, I'm pretty sure that native Japanese speakers would be offended if that's the wrong pronoun for the level of formality involved.  Japanese pronouns can be translated into English as "I/you/he/she/it/they" (with some loss of meaning), but blindly translating English pronouns into Japanese is likely to be ungrammatical, offensive, or both.

Comment: @fredsbend: That's not just Japanese. Both French and German have polite forms for pronouns (vous/Sie). From what I understand, not using those forms when it's called for can be reason for dismissal in Germany.

Comment: No, they're also pronouns. Unlike he/she/they, vous/Sie are second-person pronouns - like the English "you". All the gory details: [T-V distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T–V_distinction). The equivalent of "Mister" would be "Monsieur/Herr", but none of those are pronouns, they're honorifics.

Comment: @Goyo in English the masculine used to be "inclusive" non-gendered style (as in "mankind" means women too) but this seems to be forced out of favour these days.

Comment: @gbjbaanb, "mankind", like most English-language words that include "man", comes from the Old English "mann", which was gender-neutral.  The masculine "vir" has nearly vanished from the language, surviving only in words like "werewolf"; the feminine "wif" survives as "woman" ("wif-mann", female human).

Comment: I think that, if the new CoC includes anything specifically about pronouns, it would be quite easy to make it language-neutral. The rule could simply look like this: `When using gendered pronouns about another person, use ones that in your language are correct in regards to that person's stated gender`. I've noticed that people often overcomplicate matters of gendered pronouns, which creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @Meeep rus language doesn't have neutral pronouns at all. We have "оно", which literally could be translated as "it". And that's it.

Comment: @Suvitruf I'm Polish, and it's similar here. With my rule suggestion, a Russian (or Polish) speaker would simply use pronouns normally, like they normally do in Russia (or Poland). If someone says he is male, use the male pronoun. If someone says she is female, use the female pronoun. In any other case, write in a way that people typically write when gender is unknown/unclear. Basically, my rule suggestion says that you should speak the way you normally do in your language.

Answer (score 74):

## This apology is meaningless, and Stack Exchange Staff is lying to the community again.

So first, you mess up. Badly. You hand out a half-handed apology where you *slander* Monica even though she has not violated the old *or* the new CoC. Then you issue a new apology [while still clinging to the lie that Monica did anything wrong.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334605/612952)

But then there is yet another problem: we have one staff member "apologizing", but another staff member appears to be doubling down by [retweeting this tweet.](https://twitter.com/bitandbang/status/1182389562846384129)

This apology is a bald-faced **LIE** to try and cover SE, as evident by the fact that SE is publicly retweeting stuff like this.

Comment: The lack of professionalism all the way up the chain is what gets me.  It's appalling.  I've got to assume some SE employees are internally cringing at this behavior, but what are they going to do?  Express disagreement, and get Monica'd?

Comment: Why would SE forbid staff their own oppinion?

Answer (score 68):

This letter, while addressing the community at large, has precisely 0 mention of Monica's name. There better be a good reason for that.

Consider the effects of negative press already released outside of the Stack Exchange network sites. Consider how that affects her public-facing reputation when someone does a google search of her name in the future. Now consider that at the time of this official apology posting, there has been no retraction/amendment/refutation of the previously issued negativity which reaches a similar or greater audience in an attempt to restore Monica's public-facing reputation.

Posting an apology on just this site to quench the rage of just this site's nameless crowd is one thing, but fixing the mistake which had, and will be continuing to have real effects *outside* on a single named individual, is a more important step, which has not been yet made.

Comment: An apology without restitution for the wrongdoing is purely lipservice.  Is SE apologizing for their treatment of Monica, or not?  If they aren't, this means nothing.  If they are, they need to fix the issue... or this means nothing.

Comment: Yeah - don't do better "next time," do better *this* time.

Comment: There is a very good reason for it: The fact that Fullerton is telling you they're doubling down on their decision, and in fact, not changing anything much from their previous plans. See my [longer reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834) below. Anyway, +1.

Comment: I took it as they're finally respecting the privacy she deserves and that they should have given her in the first place.

Comment: Publicly naming her once was wrong, and probably illegal. You don't fix that by repeating it. However much input anybody other than David Fullerton had in creating this apology, you _know_ legal counsel has gone over it before it was published. Naming her again is the first thing they would have vetoed.

Comment: @Xander and Auspex yeah that makes some sense in a legalese way even but it does not explain why they have not even made hints that they will be addressing the mistakes they made. They mention her gender and religious affiliation to confirm who they are talking about when they make no offer to correct the situation. Not nice at all.

Comment: +1 for _"....but fixing the mistake which had, and will be continuing to have real effects outside on a single named individual, is a more important step, which has not been yet made._" It's disastrous how long this (process) is taking.

Answer (score 63):

David,

While I appreciate this response and believe it is a good and necessary start to begin repairing the relationship between SE and the community—assuming the words are followed up promptly with concordant actions—I'm still concerned about the underlying motives for the whole thing and the implications of that for us moderators. After reading Monica's relevant post in the mod stack and the relevant portions of Monica's and Sara's activity in the TL, especially the original and newly updated CoC changes and Sara's (lack of) response to Monica's questions, I don't see how a reasonable person with access to that information could conclude anything but that it was a direct personal attack to force Monica out. How can the moderators believe SE will never treat another one of us like this again?

Answer (score 63):

Doubling-down on your already quadrouple-down of going forward with exclusionary changes to CoC and complete lack of admitting wrongdoing for the actual problems at hand are enough for me to see it's time for me to go.

You apologized for not going far enough in the wrong direction.

I can not trust a man that will not admit when he's wrong. You've just let on that this is a core problem at SE including the very top, and that no amount of user feedback will change the direction.

I had hope. This killed it.

To quote some sharks, "And for those reasons, I'm out."

Answer (score 61):

That looks more like an apology. Thanks for writing something that is not canned and does actually give info on what to expect next (dates, at least). I feel like we're a little bit less in the mud there.

I can't guarantee October 7, 10 and 11 will be all peaceful, but people might have calmer minds when they know *when* to expect, if not *what* to expect.

Not all is forgiven but there's improvement.

Comment: This doesn't look more like an apology. This is an apology.

Comment: @AndreasDeak it's a way of wording. Had I said that aloud I'd have made an approval sign as I did. (Meaning: yes, it is an apology)

Comment: @AndrasDeak This looks like a professionally written apology. Includes all required parts of an apology, repeated, as if it were written by a committee, using an apology textbook. But is it sincere?

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Time will tell if it was sincere and if it is part of an effort to fix the immediate and also underlying problems.  I choose to be optimistic -- but when I've been let down so colossally, I temper that with a bit of caution.

Comment: Yes, we can argue whether the apology is sincere and if we trust the company. It's still an apology though :P

Comment: @AndrasDeak yeah, after so many replies to the other post they figured it out how to write one :P

Comment: @AndrasDeak This "looks more like" in comparison with the previous "apology." Whether or not it *is* one depends on SO.Inc

Comment: @AndrasDeak not from my reading (its corp speech...almost to the point where I had to re-read it to see if its wasn't something like the few programs I've made which auto-generate stuff like this). But then, I've had this conversation with them before (SOD, 2 posts here, chat) and read their apologies before so maybe I'm just too jaded anymore to ever believe them.

Comment: This is a not an apology, *Mistakes were made, I approved them, my bad ...* is not an apology. It is just placating those that want something they can claim is an apology. Notice he **never** actually lists what **he** thinks the mistakes were. At least Sara let the cat out of the bag with *Sorry for doing this on Friday*, which was the non-apology for not sorry for what she did, just when she did it. This is a non-apology, *I am really sorry this causes me all this trouble I was not expecting* apology.

Answer (score 59):

Thank you.

Thank you for what you said.

I'm not a moderator, so most of your word don't directly impact me, but, as a non-binary person this does:

> First of all, we hurt members of our LGBTQ+ community when they felt they couldn’t participate authentically and we didn’t respond quickly or strongly enough in supporting them. Worse, through our handling of this situation, we made them a target for harassment as people debated their right to express themselves and be addressed according to how they identify.

So, thank you for acknowledging that. I will be able to sleep in peace tonight knowing that I have still a place here. Knowing that I'm still welcome, knowing that the higher authorities still have my back (or at least, they are trying to).

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly has SOi *hurt members of our LGBTQ+ community*?

Comment: @RonJohn I haven't seen much hate against LGBTQ+ on here until this whole mess happened. In the past week, I've seen more than in the past two years. See also the last sentence of the quote: `Worse, through our handling of this situation, we made them a target for harassment as people debated their right to express themselves and be addressed according to how they identify.`

Comment: Don’t all people here refer to each other by username mentions anyway?

Comment: @Mabedan - Based has on the hundreds of comments that was one of the concerns.  If specifically asked by a user to address them a specific way, could another user continue to address them by their chosen username, instead of respecting their wishes to be addressed differently.

Comment: @RonJohn I have seen really transphobic stuff in the last week. Thankfully most of it has been deleted, but I still saw them and it still hurts. I also felt like I **had** to defend my rights. I hadn't felt mike that here before.

Comment: I was completely unaware of any drama happening on StackExchange and after reading this apology, some of the comments and some other posts about the incident that were linked here, I honestly still have no idea how actions taken against a moderator by the staff have caused (or could possibly cause) harm to the LGBT community. What exactly did SE do that was inherently harmful LGBT people specifically?

Comment: @Lawyerson It's a good question that could us a details answer. Unfortunately, I don't have the energy to answer you. If you care enough, you could ask a separate meta question. Otherwise, let just say that the way they deal with all of this put a big red target in our (LGBTQ+) backs and unleash a lot of transphobic stuff on us. (sorry for the repost, my comment add several grammar error that made it hard to properly understand)

Comment: While I myself am not LGBTQ+, my understanding is that this entire incident over pronouns has called attention to the fact that there are LGBTQ+ users on the site. The increased visibility has brought out latent queerphobia from some other users. As a result, LGBTQ+ users have faced increased harassment because of the attention called to them due to recent events.

Comment: Even if how someone self-identifies is irrelevant to the technical matter at hand, if someone wishes to be identified in a certain way (e.g. using "they/them/theirs" pronouns), respecting that person requires respecting that choice.

Comment: @dimitarvp their bungling of the whole situation, starting from declaring a policy that *could not work as written*, then over-reacting to questions, then doubling down with public accusations, has emboldened the haters and invited malicious compliance and just generally made life ugly for the LGBTQ community SE was supposed to be protecting.  It's ugly and painful.  See [this message from a queer mod](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2243/1993).  For every mod who's been hurt by this, hundreds or thousands of users probably have.

Comment: @rlee827 I have no problem respecting anyone's self-identify. My point was -- and I didn't elaborate, please accept my apologies for it -- that in the regular Q&A setting in the StackExchange network, the communicational exchange is, at best, 2-3 replies between two people. This really leaves no space and time for inserting self-identification and its deserved respect. It's like this: "How do I do X?" -> "Try Y or Z" -> "Thanks, that works". In such an exchange the LGBT aspect of a participant is irrelevant (or it should be; I realise there are a lot of unreasonable haters out there).

Comment: @MonicaCellio This brings in a much-needed additional nuance to the matter (which I am not really that well informed about). I am very thankful for the link!

Comment: @dimitarvp **1** Sure, on the technical sites, matters of gender identity rarely arise, although you should be aware that on those sites many women intentionally use gender-neutral or even masculine  user names because they feel they won't get fair treatment otherwise. **2** Following on from Monica's remarks, over the last week there has been a lot of anti-LGBTQ+ sentiment expressed on MSE (& I expect also in many chatrooms), ranging from mildly disrespectful remarks through to blatantly nasty transphobic / homophobic stuff that is against the old "Be Nice" policy and the current CoC.

Comment: @dimitarvp (cont) Some of the anti-LGBTQ+ stuff has been said in a diplomatic way, so you have to read between the lines to see it. But the worst stuff is as plain as day. That bad stuff is now deleted, but due to the huge amount of activity & the scarcity of mods, some of the bad comments persisted for hours, and received upvotes.

Comment: There was even a "question" posted here on MSE by a member who primarily posts on science sites (where he has several thousand rep points) which was basically a proclamation that he henceforth refuses to interact with any trans members. It was deleted in under 10 minutes, but it was still very unpleasant while it lasted.

Comment: I’m reading through these posts and I get the general idea but unsure what exactly happened. Could anyone summarize what happened in a few sentences?

Comment: @Rich https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334417/400547

Comment: As a member of the Lavender aka Queer aka LGBTQ(etc) community who is not trans or nonbinary, I did feel personally attacked in the aftermath of this.  No one said anything personal to me (almost no one) but I felt it all the same.  It was enough to send me into panic attacks and needing a leave of absence from my moderator position.  The hate is real.  Having Monica back as my co-moderator will help tremendously.

Comment: @PM2Ring How was that an attack on trans people, when he would have clearly been trying to condem the unworkable policy and thuis avoiding getting caught by it. Not every criticism of the policy is evidence of hate because yoyu've "read between the lines" and come to your own perception of what the poster meant they were saying.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Either way, it's a bad thing, and shows how counterproductive the policy is, and how it hurts trans users (as well as the "majority").

Comment: @gbjbaanb I assume you're replying to my last comment, which mentions the member who posted the proclamation that he refuses to  (knowingly) interact with trans people. It was distinctly hostile, with no reading between the lines required. He described trans women as being in one of two categories. 1: men suffering from the delusion that they are women, and 2: men pretending to be women (using pretty avatar images) so that young men will be nice to them and upvote them.

Comment: @PM2Ring not that one, the one before it where you admitted you had to "read between the lines" (hence my quote) to find evidence of hostility - I suggest that such evidence is not present in 99.9% of the cases (the 0.1% of loons out themselves easily, we have Cyn saying that nobody said anything but had panic attacks over it anyway. This stuff gets blown up out of proportion too easily and ends up affecting the most sensitive souls.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I agree that it's possible to misread or over-react to such things, especially when emotions are running high. I certainly accept that it's valid to criticize the new CoC (now that we've seen it) as being unworkable, or too extreme for a significant percentage of the site members to feel comfortable adopting it. But the posts I was talking about are those where the poster objects to trans inclusive language because it clashes with their values &/or religion. Eg, those using phrases like "family values".

Answer (score 54):

Thank you.

Please never forget this: no single act can repair this breach of trust. This cannot just be the end of an old conversation, but also must be the start of a new one.

When that trust is rebuilt, it won't look the same, and it certainly won't behave the same, as what we had before. But what we had before was limited, harmful to some, tiring to others, joyful to no one, and needed to be excised*. That process could have been easier, but the Stack is now one surgery in. I hope the Stack + community can grow and adapt into a new, better form. And I hope you won't look back with rose-tinted glasses on a form of trust that existed only by accident, and broke upon its first real challenge.

Make this new way deliberate. Make it better. Make it whole.

All the best.

---

* *(I want to make clear that I am* not *talking about Monica -- I'm talking about culture exclusively.)*

Comment: Absolutely! The old phrase goes, "Forgive and Forget," but I would say, "Forgive and Learn!" Big Dave has made the apology, and has not tried to duck his responsibilities in causing the harm. Let's accept that (until we have a reason not to) and try to move on to a better, wiser, more informed future. I'm pretty new here, but I love the whole Stack site and don't want it to start falling apart because of arrogance/ignorance in its upper echelons.

Comment: @Adrian: "...and has not tried to duck his responsibilities in causing the harm": What good does that do, if he doesn't also act to fix it? Apologizing is cheap, that and fifty cents will buy you a cup of coffee any day of the week. The important part of an apology is the part where you fix your mistakes. And on that, there's been utter silence for a week now.

Answer (score 54):

Much better.

We have a long way to go, and [I still want to see licensing addressed](https://kera.name/articles/2019/10/mistake-overflow-one-companys-catalogue-of-errors/) (at least acknowledged), and some of this post kinda goes into "you guys are harassing people" territory which seemed a bit like the wrong time and place…

…but, nitpicking aside, this is the response that we hoped for and that should have been given to begin with.

Although it does not in itself undo anything that's happened, I absolutely thank you for it, and hopefully it's the start of improved relations to come.

Comment: Heh, someone's going around downvoting every post that says "thank you". Person, you are not helping.

Comment: Have an upvote for the great off-site writeup. Btw I wasn't aware of the data breaches at all.

Comment: For what it's worth, I received a mod message from "moderators", who were actually employees — it couldn't have been an elected mod, since they made claims based on data they don't have access to. They straight up accused me of mass-downvoting people and twisted my own words to try and make it sound bad. This all comes very soon after I ask for clarification on the license change. If that's not harassing, I'm not sure what is.

Comment: @jhpratt - I would agree that would be harassment.  I suspect I will be silenced for making that statement.

Comment: Excuse me, @LightnessRacesinOrbit, but I disagree. Saying "thank you" for an apology that is too little, too late, and makes absolutely no promise to set things right, deserves a downvote.

Comment: @Auspex You haven't explained how you're helping by casting it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I assume the intent is to promote the answers that say a fair bi more than "thanks" so they rise to the top. As is the intention of the voting system, the "noise" gets downvoted to the bottom. Its not about popularity, its about useful content.

Comment: @gbjbaanb The intention of the voting system is _not_ tactical voting by casting downvotes on undownvote-worthy material to "cheat" your way to making your upvotes count double.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No one said anything about making votes count double. They simply explained to you how downvotes are helpful: they push down the low quality content, allowing the higher quality content to rise up. Like it or not, some people find your comment to be low enough quality to downvote. I personally do not find your comment to be helpful, as it brings up a completely different issue, and does not note any of the flaws in the apology.

Comment: I will also add that I sometimes include comments when I decide how to vote. If I see someone doing something to mess with the system, I downvote to discourage such actions, as it is my only means to do so. If you try to tell people they are bad to downvote you, I see that as an attempt to influence the vote. It not only tries to make future voters feel bad for wanting to downvote, but also encourages people who agree with you to feel outrage and thus want to upvote what they wouldn't otherwise. It's not helpful to the purpose of SE to do anything like that.

Comment: @trlkly I reserve the right to make a comment on this page that doesn't "note any of the flaws in the apology". That's not all we're here for. Frankly it's not at all what we're here for. Also your rambling about "outrage" is just ridiculous.

Comment: What we're _here_ for is Stack Exchange: where the principle is high-quality answers are upvoted, poor quality answers are downvoted. I haven't downvoted anything that said "thanks" but provided real substance. And in any case, SE's own system "doubles" my votes. Not having enough rep on Meta, my downvotes don't get reported, so only my upvotes are visible.

Answer (score 51):

I have been thinking about writing a reply for days now. I came back to this post multiple times, trying to write down what I feel I have been telling you for too much time now.
I am tired of seeing the same movie being played week after week. And I hope you too are. But I am already getting ahead of myself.

Before I start, first let me thank you for this post. I will be honest, I am not entirely satisfied with this post - and I would have liked it more if a [previous "attempt" wasn't made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology?page=1&tab=active#tab-top). But I am not here to discuss the last incident. There is plenty of that already and I think that there isn't much more to add to further clarify *what* was done poorly. At least nothing I can think off now.

I am not even there to argue if the firing was deserved. I don't have access to the actual facts, and sadly an almost perfect work was made so that now there are different contradicting versions of the story. In an odd way, this reminds me of [Rashōmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashomon), no offence intended. Either way, I am not in a position to judge.

**What I am here for is to ask you to please try to not make me watch this same movie again in 6-8 time units.**

I have been on Stack Exchange for... at least 7 years now. And during those years I have seen an exponential increase in the free drama we get every week.
Mind you, it is not like we didn't have our fair share of problems 7 years ago.... it is just that at the time they resonated less. I remember Shog9 getting angry "because some chatrooms are surprised that they don't get to not-be-nice" and I even remember him shutting down some of those rooms... but at the time Stack Exchange seemed to lack a defined structure to handle those "Be Nice" problems. Employees picked their "small" fights to fight and that was it. Or at least that was the impression I got back then.

And then something happened. I am not sure **what** was the root cause - IMHO all of this was started by the financial problem Stack Exchange was experiencing at the time and the unexpected attention April Twitter post brought on the network: something had to be done to cleanse Stack public image, and it had to be done fast. I am not asking here for you to agree with this interpretation, but what I hope we can agree on is that an unclear point in time some years ago, something moved inside Stack Exchange.
Suddenly, no longer Stack was a mere observer of the "Unwelcome/Not Nice" problems, stepping in only when something really intolerable was done (assuming they actually noticed it, I saw users quit after being harassed multiple time in the chat rooms, with almost no consequence for those responsible). No, now Stack Exchange decided it was time to act. To stop just trying to fixing holes in the hull and instead try to trace a route that didn't cross so many asteroids fields...

**It was the start of the "Welcome Wagon".**
And mind you, it was a good idea: we needed and still need something to be done for our network to become a better place. But... something clearly got wrong along the road. The change brought fear, endless arguments over trivial things and simple miss understanding and with it a lot of drama and fights. But again, I am not here to try to convince any of you of where I think an error was made.

What I do want to do is bring to your attention a pattern I notice in all this mess.
We had an interminable list of incidents in the latest months.... yet every single one follows the same "monster of the week" script like this was a poorly made TV show.

- An incident happens: usually it is either because a) the staff didn't communicate something they were doing, someone noticed it anyways and then posted an angry "You tried to slip the ads under the carpet!!" meta post or b) something bad happened because either the staff handled something without enough care or didn't react well enough to an unpredictable external issue.
- The Meta storm starts, for days the Staff ignores it.
- a poor answer is posted, usually skipping over many questions the community made
- (optional: the answer says that "We learned not to ship on Friday and that next time the process will be better")
- the war still rages, and now the community is split between users that want to be fine with just the answer that was given and people who now are even angrier because they think the answer is just a joke.
- time passes and nothing gets solved until the issue is no longer discussed (often because some chat room mod /owner decides to no longer discuss it in the room and ask others to do the same. Not a solution, yep, but can be understood in order to stop the pain I guess?)
- in a few weeks... return to the first point for the new episode in the Meta show.

Yep, sometimes fate like a wonderful show maker gives us some "unexpected" plot twist... What will happen this time?? Maybe a staff member will make a passive-aggressive threat to a user, telling him that "we could show you a form where you can request account deletion if you like"? Maybe a user will think that it could be funny to pour more fuel on the fire by using leaked e-mail addresses to send other users spam?? Yet the basic story is still the same.

And this happens again.. again... again... every single time wearing out the heart of the involved users like a water drop that consume a mountain over the years. Some users quit and get replaced by new, still "mint-condition" hearts - and the cycle continue.

I think we have a problem there. A big communication problem. This is has turned in a "blue team VS red team" mess - the only thing missing are the stadium hooligans chanting. And based on some messages I saw in the past I am not even sure.

I get everyone is frustrated.
I get your minds and hearts are tired.
I get you are angry.
**But this is going nowhere.**

I am asking you. All of you. Staff and users alike. Stop.
Stop acting like you hate each other.
Stop hiding stuff from each other.
Talk. And I said talk... screaming over each other like we do now only results in more rage.

And staff, please.... if you really hope to regain the trust you lost over too many small incidents, please...
Start acting faster. Reply faster. Problems won't go away if you ignore them long enough. The fact people stopped talking about an issue does not mean it is solved.
And when you reply, be sure **everyone** is aligned on your replies. Lately whenever an employee talks  I don't know if they are talking for themselves or if their messages have actually been agreed upon before posting... Too many conflicting views to be had, too many contradicting messages to be posted.
Stop resetting character grown at every new episode: this is not a poorly made Carton Network show. I will be blunt: I have lost track of **"how many times you learned to not ship on Friday evening"**: Monica, addresses shared with Amazon to fulfil a swag delivery, ads implementation, poorly tested April fools... the list is too long now.
Stop hand-waving valid concerns users express on the meta like they don't know what they are talking about. I agree that you get a lot of "just because" hate comments, but you should also agree that probably not everyone out there on a development-related tech site is claiming to be worried by fingerprinting ads just because they are making up things to make you look evil.
Again, you need to talk. Talk inside the company and talk outside the company. I had the - hopefully wrong - impression that even inside the company there is no agreement on how things are being carried out. It is worrying for us when your own employees comment that they don't like where the ship is going.

Wonder what? **There is only one ship here, and if it sinks all of us will.**
Users need the company if they want to have a site to post on.
And the company kinda needs someone to actually post content.

......
Or you know, we may just stop pretending a community even exist. We can go on separate roads and try to pursue our own, personal goals. But if we have to come to that, please just shut down this parody of "community" Meta has become. I am bored to watch the same episode again and again.

---

### Please, give me a plot twist and stop this painful Groundhog Cycle every day on Meta has become.

---

Comment: *the only thing missing are the stadium hooligans chanting* ... are they missing? Aren't those the voters? Or even the sub-reddits and other fora that host users that are more knowledgeable like we are? What does -1000 mean? Or +500 if only 50 users expressed their feelings?

Comment: @rene as I said:  "And based on some messages I saw in the past I am not even sure.". I assume that you too have seen the not-so-nice words that have been exchanged back and fort in the past. I wouldn't focus on the number of votes: that is just a way to know how "passionate" the feedback was.... but we don't get only votes - we get actual name-calling and insults.

Comment: It's a self reinforcing feedback loop. Users feel like they aren't consulted anymore and that staff doesn't care, so they lash out. Staff feels the pain of getting a thousand pings with 500 differently worded comments on how they're wrong, and thus stop participating entirely except where absolutely necessary. Neither side is willing or able to break the cycle.

Comment: Oh, I know, @Magisch, it is a tantrum spiral by now. Hence the need to break the Groundhog Day loop.

Comment: '*Neither side is willing or able to break the cycle.*' - @Magisch, if users break the cycle it means not caring about any changes made to the system and not posting regarding them. If SE breaks the cycle, it means acknowledging their most dedicated users and at the very least, hearing their opinions.

Comment: *Lately whenever an employee talks I don't know if they are talking for themselves or if their messages have actually been agreed upon before posting* — maybe SE should consider posting from a pseudonymous group-managed "community team" account?

Comment: @gerrit I think that has been discussed previously but ultimately it wouldn't change anything really. The issue here is lack of communication (and when communication is done it's done terribly) not who's communicating it.

Comment: @gerrit that is an option, but as Script47 already said it would just work to "protect" the employees who are getting insults (and sometime even personal threats) for the posts they *have to* make. It wouldn't probably do much for cases that have one employee post a reply and another one posting another, conflicting reply soon after.

Comment: Contrary to "be sure **everyone** is aligned on your replies"... I think it would solve a lot of problems if the staff would argue with each other in public rather than private.  That would allow the community to be directly involved in the decision-making process, and that's the whole point isn't it?

Comment: @Brilliand I didn't had that type of disagreement in mind. What I wanted to avoid were scenarios where an employee says "we are doing this because A"  or "we are doing A" and a few hours later some other employee posts a different, contradicting version of the story (like "we will never do A and are doing B instead"). Since this already caused **a lot** of anger in the past, with many members of the community reacting to this like they where purposely lied to... you will probably agree that is not the best option to stop all the Meta fighting we get.

Comment: I downvoted this for a very good reason... a word picture to illustrate... In a marriage, one spouse hits the other with a baseball bat, hard.  The one that was hit starts demanding the other own up to it and undo the damage as much as possible.  The one that hit makes apologies but takes no real action.  You do not go to them and say "I am asking you. All of you. [spouse 1 and spouse 2] alike. Stop."  After reading this answer, in its totality, to me, that sentence seems to sum it up best, and I find it is not an appropriate answer to what has happened.

Comment: @AgapwIesu I would advise you re-read the answer if you didn't already. I am **not** writing just about this single incident. Over the course of the last year we had a lot of similar issue (which is also the central point of my answer here) and every time it ended in the same way. Some time the staff used passive-agressive words. Some time the community overreacted and showered them in insults. I stand my point - unless both sides stop hurling insults at each others and start talking we are not going anywhere.

Comment: @AgapwIesu also, as a side notice, next time could you please use an example that does not involve beating spouses? The current one isn't making me feel very comfortable...

Comment: About your answer not just dealing with this specific incident.  I did get that, from my first, and second readings, and other partial readings.  But this "question" is about a specific instance, and that is part of the problem with your answer, you are going off to a broader topic.  While related, the broader topic brings in so many other factors and changes their relevance to such a degree that it dilutes what's going on here.  If your answer was a separate post of its own, I'd upvote it in a jiffy, because you are right, generally, everyone needs to take a step back.  But in this case...

Comment: And you are right about the word picture.  Bad choice.

Answer (score 51):

Until Monica is reinstated as a moderator, you clear her name in a follow-up article with The Register, and you take back the disastrous changes to the CoC and try again by asking for feedback from the community before making official changes, I can only conclude that your apology is hollow and insincere.

Answer (score 50):

#### First of all...

## Thank you.

#### But...

- ...how did it get this bad in the first place?
- ...why wasn't the new CoC proposal floated in front of the community, and placed in the hands of the people of Stack Exchange to decide whether to put it in place, and in what form?
- ...what action, if any, is going to be taken (has been taken?) against those who ran Monica out of Modville on a figurative rail, publicly spat on her good name, and quite possibly endangered her in real life (looking at you, Sara Chipps)?
- ...when are the staff going to stop dictating policy from on high, rather than acting only on well-supported proposals from the community (mandatory arbitration, forced [and illegal] relicencing, etc., etc., etc.)?
- ...how and when are we going to change things so that the staff answer to, and serve, the community, rather than lording it over them from on high?  (At the very least, having the staff members be elected by the community, rather than chosen by the great disembodied hand, would be a necessary first step.)

Comment: Staff members are employees. They are not elected, nor should they be.

Comment: @tchrist: Why on earth shouldn't they be?

Comment: @sean How would that work? Even if you wanted the community to be involved in (or even responsible for) the recruiting process, I don't think it is compatible with important legal requirements (think private information in CVs etc as well as background checks performed by HR). But anyway, if you honestly think they *should* be, that would be a highly unconventional position where I would expect you to argue why that is your position, rather than the other way around.

Comment: "[...] possibly endangered her in real life [...]" — how do you figure? Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: @SQB: death threats for openly being for/against trans is not unknown, and Monica Cellio isn’t an alias or a user name.  It’s a name that can be looked up and matched to an address.  It took me approximately a minute to get what I presume is that address. Non-specific language is used for a reason, and not just CYA. And according to the article by Thomas Claburn in the theregister.co.uk when asked to confirm that Monica was the mod in question Chipps said SE plans to “even more explicitly cite misgendering users or moderators as a violation”.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeAeL0K86DI ;)

Answer (score 50):

This is a very good first step, and drastically better than the previous doubling down on the mistakes by SE. But the important part are the actions that follow in the future, as this apology acknowledges. This post stopped the situation that was quickly spinning out of control, but it doesn't solve anything unless followed by the right actions.

For me, the proposed actions are a necessary step in order to fix this mess, but they're not sufficient by itself. One aspect that creates significant uncertainty and doubt for me is that even now I don't understand how we arrived at this point. I don't understand why SE behaved in this way, and I especially don't understand the mysterious source of urgency. Without understanding this, I don't know how SE could convince me that this won't happen again.

It wasn't a single bad decision, SE doubled down on their mistakes several times. It wasn't a simple mistake, it looks from the outside like a very deliberate decision. And it's impossible to distinguish right now whether SE actually changed their stance, or just gave into the increasing public pressure.

I'm not saying it's impossible for SE to rebuild the trust, but it will be difficult and it will take much more than this apology.

Comment: I can think of at least two completely different scenarios that could have driven the perceived urgency and doubling down behind the decision because they _cannot_ reveal them. There may be others. In either case I'm okay with the fact that they can neither tell us the full scenario nor backtrack on it the way we would like to see. What they **can** do is do some legwork to rescind the public defamation by acknowledging that the urgency did not stem from the hitherto publicly accused side, then go out of their way to make amends in other ways.

Comment: @Caleb I hadn't thought about that aspect of it at all! I'd like to know your speculations (in general terms, of course, not mentioning anything that might be *sub judice*). I can only think of one scenario, but then, I've never been very streetwise! By the way, I'm trans (or TOCOTOX, "too complicated to explain", as someone used to call this sort of thing on the Usenet newsgroup soc.bi, a long time ago), and I'm not a Christian, but I thought your statement [Brothers, I must go…](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718/) the single best thing I've read on this whole sorry business.

Answer (score 50):

I've really struggled with how or whether to respond to this. I think others have already expressed my feelings in one way or another, but I fear that maybe SE will miss the message if they don't hear it from enough people.

For background, I'm a pretty active user; nearly 10 year veteran; top 2% on SO; I participate on Meta; vote in mod elections; attend SE events; have SO stickers on my computer; and fill out those developer surveys. I'm not a mod. The closest I came was considering running once. I'm just a slightly above average regular user who cares about this site, sometimes maybe more than I should.

> We’ll keep those discussions completely private unless we both agree to share any of it with the community.

First, you need a better and more public apology for Monica. I'm glad that you finally figured out that this process should have been private from the beginning, but that ship has sailed. You dragged a moderator's name and reputation through the mud... you gave up the luxury of privacy. I can understand why SE corporate would really like to hide this now that it's blown up, but you can't just wish this away from public view, especially not under the guise of suddenly caring about Monica's privacy.

You need to apologize to Monica, by name, for failing to follow a fair process and jumping to judgment too quickly, and you need to put it out as a press release. **Then**, and only then, can you move forward with private conversations. At the very least, let Monica decide whether she wants a public apology. I bet that she'll be more gracious than you have been.

> Worse, through our handling of this situation, we made them a target for harassment as people debated their right to express themselves and be addressed according to how they identify.

Moral zealotry leads to collateral damage, always. Your intentions were honorable, but I see nothing in this apology that recognizes that the root issue here was an attempt to micro-manage a very diverse community under the pretentious and patronizing notion that a group of people needed your protection.

It's commendable to encourage honest and open dialogue, to give everyone a voice and to draw boundaries around acceptable forms of communication. But you simply cannot force everyone to speak with the same voice. Human dialogue is too complicated, diverse and nuanced to be neatly categorized by some rather ham-fisted guidelines. You have to be careful with those boundaries; the narrower you make them, the more they start to look like you and your culture and no one else's, and that creates division. You drove a wedge in our community where one was not needed.

> I know we have lost the trust of many of you, and that trust must be re-earned over time by more than just words.

This, I think, is the truest thing you said. It's taken me a couple days to realize it, too. Because I really **want** to trust you, and it really hurts that I no longer do. I want this apology to be sufficient, but I don't really trust your sense of discernment or propriety going forward.

#### In short, I'm going to take a 3 month break from Stack Exchange in protest.

I'm just one developer and I rarely represent the majority. But I just want you to know that I'm logging out for the first time in almost 10 years, and I want you to know why.

I really hope that corporate reinstates Monica and issues the public apology she is still owed.

I really want SE and SO to succeed and include everyone who is willing to work in a diverse community. I hope the new CoC can be crafted without forcing divisions between people with amicable aims, who are willing to reasonably compromise, who can respectfully and even lovingly agree to disagree, even if that's not always comfortable.

I hope that the SE I log back into in 3-6 months is a better version than the one I've seen this past week.

---

### 3 months later.

Today I logged in for the first time in 3 months, and I'm disappointed. I had hoped that it would not require legal action for Monica to get a basic apology, but that's exactly what it took. Now both Monica and SE are under a gag agreement, so it is safe to assume that there will be no further updates and thus no real resolution for the community. Monica has still not been reinstated.

I missed my 10th anniversary. It's not a big deal, but it has caused me to reflect.

I've always been a stickler for the rules because I believed that they were crafted and policed by the community itself (at least the active part of it) and that they were what united us and focused our efforts. In an environment where nearly anything is possible, this shared vision was needed to prevent the community from tearing itself apart. But some very fundamental changes have taken place. Slowly at first, but now in much more tangible ways, requiring a change in my approach to this site.

#### My 10th Anniversary Resolutions

It's a new decade for me, in more than one sense, and I have made some new resolutions:

- **I will focus on fellow users going forward.** I will not rage quit, nor will I make a fuss about the status quo on meta. Instead, I will do my best to be a good neighbor and an honest citizen in this community.

  I will answer questions that I feel are interesting. I will ask questions that I feel are useful. I will leave constructive and helpful comments.

  I will do my best to avoid trouble, but I'm not going to go out of my way to keep up-to-date on the "rules" either.

  I will not worry about what a corporation thinks of my behavior, which is how I will think of Stack Overflow Inc from now on. I'll do what I think is right and, so long as *the corporation* doesn't kick me out, I'll continue contributing content.
- As *the corporation* has demonstrated that it has no real loyalty to the community and especially the community-elected leadership, I will no longer extend my loyalty to it.

  **I will suspend most moderation activities for the foreseeable future**, including the review queue, to which I contributed infrequently anyway; and close votes, down voting and flags which, combined, I cast frequently.

  As *the corporation* has taken direct ownership of the rules without regard for the community's input, and as it has taken on the mantle of summarily casting judgment on volunteers without regard for pre-existing procedures or precedent, it only makes sense that the rule-enforcement tasks now also belong to *the corporation*. I will no longer volunteer for what should be, under these new circumstances, a paid position. I'm sure that others will step up as mods, diamond or otherwise. Hopefully *the corporation* will pay them like employees since it has certainly started treating them as such.

I think, too, that this will be my last contribution to Meta. I have enjoyed posting here and on the SO meta and I hope some of my contributions have been helpful. To those who plan to continue fighting for a voice, I wish you well. I do hope that at some point *the corporation* might have a change of heart, but I will not hold my breath.

Comment: *"Moral zealotry leads to collateral damage, always."* Well said sir.

Answer (score 49):

**Deeds not Words**

Still, first of all: Thank you for the apology.

That said: Quite a **lot** of bad things accumulated to get the community to the boiling point. You adressed only but a few of them. What about the animated ads? What about the fingerprinting? What about the unilateral, retroactive (and probably not legal) licensing changes? Will you attempt to rectify those issues or will you sit back, hoping that the announced changes will be enough to "placate the natives" only to resume your previous course once things have calmed down.

Words are *cheap*, and while the apology is an important first step I (personally) will need to wait and see if more than token gestures will follow.

Comment: I would add to that having very lax rules about account creation to allow drive-by users that do not want to follow SE rules and the CoC, while punishing loyal and more contributing users with higher standards and more stringent rules.

Comment: @CharonX: Fullerton is telling you that there will be no deeds, only empathetic words. See my explanation [below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834).

Comment: That tweet is so disingenuous.  It is a classic straw-man argument.  The only deed that would begin to acknowledge a capacity to recognize when they have done wrong is to reinstate Monica (undo the wrong you did), and then put her through the moderator removal process, if there is any reason to even go there.

Answer (score 45):

This apology is more or less the apology made by Sara Chipps but with more details on the situation. It reads likes Stack Exchange whispering sweet nothings into our ears – yes, it acknowledges wrongdoing on the part of David Fullerton and the decisions he had made but the only remedies that are offered are **"We'll do better in the future"** if the community was really the:

> We recognize that the community is the **heartbeat** of Stack Overflow

Then why is there a problem in including the community's input the direction the company goes, and allowing us to set our own standards *(I know it's a big request to allow the community to set community standards)*?

Stack Exchange shouldn't call the community its *"heartbeat"* because the company has repeatedly shown us that *they could live without us*.

---

This post is nicely worded but untimely, it undercuts one of the apologies that is being made.

> we also acted at a time which **coincided with a Jewish holiday** which she and many other members of our community observe

Understandably, we have all been waiting for an apology (for a while), but **this apology coincides with a Jewish holiday** that Monica and many other members of our community observe, and you shouldn't apologize for doing the action previously while continuing the action in the apology.

---

Why should "Going forward, ... we gather input and feedback" be trusted:

> Going forward, we will be working with the community to overhaul how we gather input and feedback from our moderators and members of the community to make sure that your voices are heard and involved in the process

The community has been giving its input and feedback for the past couple weeks and there's been no action, just empty promises that we've heard before when Stack Exchange had made missteps "we'll do better in the future".

---

The apology reads lovely, great job on writing it, although, it says nothing but I'm sure **you'll do better in the future**.

The irony is that a large amount of the user base isn't upset and don't object to using someone else's pronouns if asked to, users are upset because Stack Exchange has continuously disrespected the active user base in hopes of new users. Displaying the community's anger as anger against LGBTQ+ individuals instead of we'll all anger at the ways the company disrespects its user base is deceptive (this isn't to discredit the problems the LGBTQ+ community faces).

Comment: "This apology coincides with a Jewish holiday" - it was posted on Sunday though? (Yom Kippur starts Tuesday night)

Comment: @npostavs I think there might be a time zone difference between you and me.

Comment: @npostavs I'm not an expert scholar of Judaism but to my knowledge, there is something called "Erev Yom Kippur" (the day before Yom Kippur) that is used for preparation and other traditions.

Comment: Monica responded quickly, laying out her timeframe --she was available Sunday evening, Monday, and Tuesday up until, I think, 5 pm-- and her willingness and eagerness to talk.  The only problem I see with the timing of the Sunday post from management was that it came with such a delay.  I think this answer could therefore be strengthened by removing the point about it being untimely.

Comment: +1, but I disagree with "_they could live without us_". It's more _they could live without many of us_ (but not without all of us). Without the majority of us SE would go the way so many Internet sites went in the past: into insignificance at last. The best and ultimate Ferrari Formula 1 car is never ever going to win the championship without gas station attendants, pit lane cleaners, mechanics, drivers and so on. One who develops a business model based on "we actually don't need them" should be fired in that very second.

Comment: @aparente001 Thank you for your thoughts but I believe that this message was still untimely. Yom Kippur is a major holiday in Judaism, the timing of the release of this message is the equivalent as to if It were released a day or two before Chrismas.

Comment: @StephanS - You would rather he had waited until after the holiday?  Are you sure about that?

Comment: @aparente001 Yeah, I personally think it would be more appropriate. You shouldn't say you'll stop doing something while you're doing it. I wouldn't take issue with the timing if there wasn't a part apologizing that the timing of Monica's firing was inappropriate.

Comment: @aparente001 it's like saying: "I promise I'll stop F***ing swearing". It's hypocritical, and shows the speaker doesn't actually intend to stop the thing they said they'll stop doing.

Comment: @StephanS - Okay, thanks for clarifying your opinion.  I absolutely disagree, since Monica and we were all going nuts due to management's silence.  Of course, it would have been better to get a response earlier, but I don't think it would have been good to wait until after this holiday to hear *something reasonable sounding* from management. // One thing I guess we can agree on is that we hope management arranges to have a real dialogue with Monica soon.

Comment: @aparente001 I guess we'll have to agree to disagree, although I did enjoy the civil back and forth, it was nice.

Comment: On the timing, had the followup come on Sunday when this was posted, and had it led to action, that would have been plenty of time before Yom Kippur.  That's not what happened, but even the mid-day-Tuesday email *could* have been fine if it had offered more than it did.  I would not have wanted him to delay everything until today, though I still feel like I haven't *gotten* much of anything here.

Answer (score 44):

What worries me the most here is the issue of *agency*. SE is nothing without its users: all of its value is created by its community; and yet, there is this for-profit company that has the legal right to call all the shots, and which has now demonstrated it is quite capable of making major mistakes. Anything we, as a community, create, might at any moment be re-cast into some new context that we find utterly unacceptable. Is it really a good idea for us to work for you for free?

Comment: "work for you for free?"  Quite a good question. Even my pitiful contribution on a couple of communities has translated into many hours... I almost said "with no remuneration", but the truth is that I have received from the SE community as much or more than I have contributed.  I can't say the same for the company though.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Many of us have received a great deal from the SE _community_... But why should we feel OK about this company that owns the results of our helping each-other? When they can so easily betray our trust, sabotage our community, and create a new environment for our content which no longer makes it acceptable for us to engage with it?

Comment: Exactly.  I was agreeing with your answer (+1 on it by the way).  I tried, in my comment, to make the distinction between the community and the company.  Did it not come across?  I myself am staying out of providing any useful content (participation in the other communities) until I see how this plays out.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I read your last sentence too hastily. I've also stopped contributing, after some months of highly active engagement. I wish we could have a community _owned_ replacement for SE. Perhaps something backed by multiple non-private universities, for example, with an open governance system.

Comment: By "free" you clearly mean only "monetary compensation". Presumably you get other things from SE, because here you are. If those other things that keep you coming back are no longer worth it, that's a personal decision you are free to make. But stop saying you work for free. It demonstrates a serious lack of gratitude.

Comment: Not downvoting because the message of your post is still relevant: reevaluating SE's worth.

Comment: @fredsbend I feel immense gratitude to the SE community. I guess SE the company were inspired and had a great attitude to begin with. But now we're in the money-grubbing phase, and I ask whether this reveals a fatal flaw in the entire enterprise.

Comment: @sesquipedalias The company needs a net income to function. Would you rather pay for SE? No? Then you need to learn that commercialization and monetization is not "money grubbing".

Comment: @fredsbend There are things that are best _not_ commercialised. The military. Prisons. How about adding shared human knowledge to the list?

Comment: @sesquipedalias There's no free lunch. Those things still *cost money*.

Comment: @fredsbend I suggest researching "prison industrial complex" (yeah, in order to do so, you have to filter out the insane communist and conspiracy-theory ravings; the cold, hard facts of the matter are horrific...)

Comment: @fredsbend please see my 2nd comment

Comment: @fredsbend  please see _all_ of my 2nd comment

Comment: Agreed.  I was rather swamped, and didn't find out about this mess till today.  But this is only the logical result of unwelcome changes over the past year. I just deleted every non-essential technical account, I can't just stay and contribute to this.

Answer (score 41):

I'm one of the users who felt personally hurt and betrayed by the company's recent actions. I have suspended moderation activities for a few days now, and today I was just about convinced that I could no longer act as a moderator in good conscience. I no longer wanted to be associated with SE, the company. You just changed my mind.

This is exactly what I had been hoping to see: a message written by one group of humans earnestly trying to communicate with another. This isn't the impersonal corporatespeak we've received in the past. This is an actual apology. You admit you dropped the ball and you are promising to do better. You are describing concrete actions you plan to take in the future. I do believe you mean this and I honestly hope you will succeed.

In any case, I wanted to thank you for posting this. It has restored at least some of my faith in SE as a company and lets me continue to believe that the values this place was built on are still alive in the heart of SE.

So thank you. For what it's worth, you have made me, at least, feel better than I have in almost two weeks.

## THANK YOU!

---

**Update**

Sadly, the days go by and you still haven't issued any sort of retraction or public apology for dragging the name of one of your users through the mud and making her a target. I'm still happy you at least issued a human apology, but there's a lot more work to do.

Comment: Glad you've changed your mind.

Answer (score 40):

Thank you. This is great to see, if a bit late.

I had taken the liberty to publish my own proposal for a turnaround plan ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334474/312691)), proposing five + one actions (see quote below).

**I am delighted to see that you committed to act on five of these six actions. I would suggest that action 1 is no less important, both to Monica herself as well as to other moderators. Knowing you won't throw a moderator under the bus publicly is key to protect them and regain their trust.**

Thanks again and we're looking forward to a new way of interacting between SO, its moderators and users.

> 1. retracting [libelous public statements](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/) that were made in the press if the internal review confirms they do not match the reality
> 2. publishing for discussion and quickly implementing a process to remove a moderator (why not start from [the existing process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology/334294#334294)?)
> 3. publishing for discussion and quickly implementing a process to reinstate a moderator (and could start from Isaac Moses's
>      [proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334282/publish-a-procedure-for-reinstating-a-removed-moderator))
> 4. running "Monica's case" through the new moderator reinstatement process and being as transparent as possible, even if in a sanitized
>      way to protect individual privacy
> 5. publishing the proposed new Code of Conduct for feedback and comments before implementation
>
> The underlying and fundamental issues behind this series of mistakes
>   need to be understood and addressed. This will likely imply changes in
>   syndicating proposals ahead of time, behavior changes from some SO
>   employees and possibly some personnel changes. This review should be
>   announced now, carried out quickly and its results announced
>   transparently.

Comment: It should not be a matter of running Monica through reinstatement process.  She should be reinstated, and then run her through the removal process, if there is even any reason to.

Answer (score 35):

This is the first communication I've seen from any of the Stack Exchange employees that seems sincere and heartfelt. (If I can use those two words next to each other without being too redundant.)

To me, it's the first sign that things can start to move in a positive direction rather than a negative one. I just hope that the spirit of this communication continues, and that the actions that take place in the coming weeks mirror the sentiment.

I only wish this kind of message could have been posted sooner. But, sooner or later, I'm glad to see it finally being conveyed at all.

Comment: Yeah, gotta appreciate a step in the right direction, albeit a small one. Will be following what steps are taken next.

Answer (score 35):

As a very "casual" user of a variety of Stack Exchange sites, this is the first I'm hearing of this situation and the events surrounding it. I do not want or intend to be dismissive of the severity of this situation, nor is this a "naysaying" post in opposition to the apology given, but I consider this a pivotal moment for Stack Overflow as a company. I've tried to do a bit of research to get up to speed on the topic of conversation and, while I'm certain there's much more to the story than I've personally read (there always is), this apology seems to be a good first step in the direction of healing what has apparently and unfortunately been a very divisive and hurtful series of events.

To be clear, I:

- do not know the moderator in question personally, professionally, or even casually through any interactions on the Stack Exchange network,
- am not myself a moderator, Community Manager, or related to Stack Overflow in any meaningful way other than being a question asker and sometimes answerer on various sites in the Stack Exchange network,
- am not myself a member of the LGBTQ+ community, and therefore do not personally feel directly affected by the proposed changes to the Code of Conduct.

So, you may be thinking, *"you really don't need to interject your opinion here... this doesn't affect you."*

The truth of the matter is, though, that it *does* affect me, as it affects *all* users and moderators of any of the sites in the Stack Exchange network, as well as employees of the company that owns them. The way that Stack Overflow ultimately handles this situation will speak volumes about its "character" and that of the people who own and operate the company itself. A company that stands behind its people and attempts to work out a reasonable solution in the face of adversity will do its best to ensure a high-quality experience for its clients/consumers/customers. They know and appreciate the value of the individual.

On the other hand, a company that treats its employees and/or volunteers with disrespect will do the same or worse to its clients/consumers/customers. Such a company's only true motivation is its profit/loss statement and the metrics that some number-cruncher has determined are appropriate. When an "incident" occurs with one of the company's employees (or volunteers, or any other such entity that represents it), it's much more likely that those "in charge" will overreact to any perceived or assumed wrongdoing with a minimal amount of investigation into the matter in their own efforts to minimize the impact (of course, this tactic frequently backfires).

Unfortunately, this last bit is what *appears* to have happened in this case. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but this is a very simplified description of the way I understand the situation: Allegations were raised against a moderator of some fairly egregious - and *reportedly* repeated - violations of the Code of Conduct. The "higher-ups" at Stack Overflow, by their own admission, took action - even to the point of bypassing their own internal procedures - without taking the time to fully investigate the allegations and research the details.

> In the absence of a clear process for handling this kind of situation, we should have taken inspiration from our existing Moderator Action Review Process. We made a decision to act quickly, which I personally approved, but in doing so skipped several critical parts of the process.
>
> ***-David Fullerton*** (from the OP)

At this point, whether or not the moderator in question did, in fact, violate the CoC is almost a secondary concern (I do not personally have an opinion on this matter as I'm not well-enough informed). The larger concern is why an apparently well-respected member and moderator of the Stack Exchange community was treated with such seeming disrespect and disdain by official representative(s) for the company. Bypassing and ignoring established protocols and procedures - even ones that don't *exactly* fit the specific situation - sets a dangerous precedent for future interactions with not only the moderation team and company employees, but also for the community as a whole.

PLEASE NOTE: I'm absolutely *not* trying to minimize the personal effects these incidents have had on the moderator in question. Based on my reading of what has occurred, the outcome is truly disturbing on a number of levels. However, I also know that there's very little that I can *do* personally in the way of "helping" aside from being a part of the discussion and, if necessary, "boycotting" Stack Overflow. I'm simply attempting to look at the entirety of the situation from as dispassionate a viewpoint as possible.

I certainly do not have any answers here and I truly hope that the sentiments expressed in Mr. Fullerton's apology are, in fact, as sincere as they sound. I *do* appreciate the clearly outlined apology which includes actual action steps that I can only assume are currently in progress. The Stack Exchange network - and the Stack Overflow site in particular - has been an invaluable resource to me over the years for which I am grateful. However, this incident has significantly diminished my overall opinion of the company and damaged the trust I once afforded it and the people behind it. In the end, the way in which this situation is handled going forward will make or break the company's reputation in the minds of a great many people. I sincerely hope that, when all is said and done, the statement on the company's about page will remain true:

> Stack Overflow is the largest, **most trusted** online community for anyone that codes to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers.
>
> **[About - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company)** (*emphasis mine*)

Comment: I will note that this is close to my first hearing about it as well. I first ran into it via [a question on Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/46314/23461). Turned out that I *should* have seen it earlier, but hadn't read far enough into Dennis's post about him stepping down. But oh boy, what a firestorm. *`...most trusted online community`* Ha! Well, I trust *the community* at least...but not the people running the servers. Haven't since...the time before the time that was before the time that was the time after the time that was the last last time (before the last CoC update).

Comment: @Draco18s - Honestly, I was completely unaware (blissful ignorance) of *any* such incidents at any time previous or current. As I said above, I'm an extremely "casual" user and am not involved with SE in any meaningful way. Hearing about this *does* give me a general cause for concern, but I'm reserving any sort of judgment at this time.

Comment: By that do you mean that you missed the last [Code of Conduct (The Welcoming) update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312038/313685), the [change to CC-BY-SA v4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/313685), the [removal of hot meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387546/1663383) / [HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316934/313685), [animated ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334144/313685), and [browser tracking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332229/313685)? I can understand having missed things, it took me a week to see this bit with Monica, but I'm just clarifying.

Comment: Correct. I apparently missed *all* of that. Now I guess I have some reading to do.

Comment: Good point about the treatment of Cellio. The apology is lots of talk but the actionable part is just a doubling-down on the termination, all things said and done. See also [my longer analysis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834) below.

Comment: @einpoklum - As someone who's about as "detached" from the situation (and SE/SO) as one can get, I intentionally did not want my post to play into any internal politics or anything about SE/SO for which I don't have any real, tangible referential knowledge or evidence. I wanted to look at it from as impartial and generic a PoV as I could. I hope it's not "as bad as all that", but after skimming through some of the historical issues posted above, I believe the "bigger picture" may be darker than many realize or are willing to admit. I would love to be proven wrong...

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat: I'm not much of an "SE politician" either, I'm just an opinionated long-time user :-P Anyway, my own experience leads to the same concerns as yours.

Comment: So, as a phone call with my mother made me realize, [the original appology is the worst-scored post on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/510152/worst-scoring-posts) by a factor of ***3.6*** (note that SEDE is cached weekly). Post #2? New ads. #3? The updated license. #4? New TOS. #5? Changes to HNQ. #8? New left nav (forgot about that one). #9? Licensing again (q). #11? Licensing again (a). #12: audio fingerprinting. Nine of the top twelve are from the last year or so, the other three are from 2011 or older. It isn't until #15 that we get another new one (ads/HNQ).

Comment: @Draco18s: [If it helps...](https://kera.name/articles/2019/10/mistake-overflow-one-companys-catalogue-of-errors/)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oof. I forgot about some of those other ones. I'd remembered the home page, but it never fit into my comments, but I'd forgotten the data breaches and unstarring/content removal fiascos entirely. Thanks for the article.

Comment: @Draco18s I wrote it specifically so that I never forget :)

Comment: From that page: "Many to this day consider Stack Overflow to be a horrible place to be, and will effortlessly spam out tales of how victimized they felt after their first experiences there (while ironically omitting the fact that they'd, in the meantime, indeed had their problem solved for free by volunteers)." +1000.

Comment: Wow... to be honest, at this point, the deeper I dive into the historical *faux pas* (to put a *very* light spin on it), the more I have to wonder if SO has *ever* been what I thought it was or what it proposed to be. I have really appreciated SO as a resource, and tried to contribute when possible, but the fact that my participation and contributions are monetized - even just visiting the site - to support an entity with a track record such as this is more than a little disconcerting. The community is *mostly* great, but there are certainly "issues" with what goes on behind the scenes.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat Its mostly been stuff that's happened in the last two years (give or take) that have been a problem. Before 2016 SO probably *was* what you thought it was (even if you didn't have an account).

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat Thanks for posting this, as it comes closer than anything else I've read to capturing my own exposure to events (casual user, unaware until recently).  I hope as you do, but also believe that in the corporate world, the only make-right for this kind of process abuse and resulting human damage is for someone to lose their paying job at the company.  Until that happens, I'm out.

Comment: @JohnPirie - My hopefulness is quickly eroding as time continues to stretch on with minimal response (and nothing "concrete") from SO corporate.

Answer (score 33):

> I’m responsible for that, and I’m sorry. We’ll be reaching out to her directly to apologize for the lack of process, privacy, and to discuss next steps. We’ll keep those discussions completely private unless we both agree to share any of it with the community.

I certainly hope along with an apology, Monica will be offered her Mod status again without having to go through any process.

Comment: _"without having to go through any process."_ That's not very likely. They didn't de-mod Monica for no reason at all (Not that I _know_ the reason, but still), and there are likely to be some conditions in case either party is interested in reinstatement.

Comment: Your thoughts seem are similar to mine after reading this latest version: _This is much better – but I'll believe when I see a diamond after Monica's name._ If she was demodded prematurely, she can be remodded prematurely.

Comment: @Cerbrus: The reason Monica was demodded was, to put it briefly, someone deliberately acting in the worst possible faith.  Monica did nothing wrong at all; the only wrongdoing was on the part of at least one, and likely several, staffmembers.  Monica deserves her diamond back - on _every_ site where she was robbed of it.  Please, staff - at the very, very least, give her that back.  She deserves it.

Comment: @Cerbrus, Without presenting *evidence* of Monica's alleged wrongdoings, if only to her fellow mods, such as myself, there is nothing to suggest that the accusations made against her are anything but a Big Lie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_lie).

Comment: MontyWild / @Sean: We don't know ___exactly___ what happened. We might never know. I don't think it's likely they're reinstate her "just like that".

Comment: Aren't you forgetting something, like, facts maybe? We don't have them. As hard as it is to imagine, Monica may have deserved it.

Comment: @Sean The reason Monica _was_ demodded wasn't a good one, but that doesn't mean it was entirely undeserved. Monica did, albeit unintentionally, violate the CoC and hurt people. It shouldn't have _got_ to that point, because SO should've asked her not to much earlier, but it is what it is.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: did we know for a FACT she broke the current CoC? Or even worse, are we talking about the future CoC?

Comment: @Cerbrus The *correct* process is to go through the de-modding process. If that process decides that she should have her mod status revoked, then--and only then--should she no longer be a mod. The reinstatement process is fundamentally different than the removal process. The former involves Monica apologizing the latter involves confirming she did anything wrong. Who apologizes for something they didn't do?

Comment: @Draco18s: I'm not taking a side here. Just stating that it's very unlikely that there aren't some steps to be taken from both sides if/before Monical will be / wants to be reinstated.

Comment: @souser12345 What she wrote was upsetting. It (obviously; it's Monica) wasn't written _in order_ to hurt people, but the combination of her status (the (earned) respect others gave her) and the way she argued her (purely grammatical – and I know people use this as an excuse, but Occam's Razor is on her side on this one) stance served to hurt people a _lot_. To continue to argue the way she did wasn't Nice (and it wasn't _just_ her… but that's another issue entirely). I'm not really able to say much more, because I don't want to reveal anything non-public without the consent of all parties.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 So what? Almost everything that you say and is worth the effort of saying is going to upset and hurt somebody. Perhaps the nicest thing we can do is stop talking to each other. As an alternative to people we can talk to Google. Unlike people, which is prone to cause us harm, Google can be trained to show us only what we want to see.

Comment: @user35594 : Actually, if you consider the post [carefully](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834), you'll notice that Fullerton is actually saying that no change in their previously planned course of actions is to be expected.

Comment: @Goyo What Monica was saying that hurt people wasn't, in my opinion, worth saying. She was only saying it because discussions had been lead in that direction, and people were arguing about it. (If Monica was in the _habit_ of saying things that hurt people, we wouldn't like her as much as we do (or, at least, _did_ before this all went down).)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You know what they say about opinions. As far as I can tell she was arguing about issues she care much about and is very sensitive to. "It wasn't worth saying" is not nice to her.

Comment: @Goyo I never said it wasn't important, or significant. I said it wasn't worth _saying_. As an extreme example: no matter how significant a breakthrough it is, it's not worth saying your half-a-decade-in-the-making theory of evolutionary gene propagation to a group of Young Earth Creationists.

Comment: You may be ignoring the fact that the main reason for ghosting, firing, and libeling Monica was to silence her while the new CoC is rushed into effect. The owners will not allow Monica to appear in TL until all CoC debate has closed,

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Strong claims. Can you back them up?

Comment: @sgf That's a different process. It doesn't quite account for the situation that might've merited Monica's demodding (which isn't quite the same as the reason she was demodded, but it's related); there wasn't a procedure for this situation.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 If it is relevant to the ongoing discussion then why not? And if it is not then the analogy does not seem to fit your own account "discussions had been lead in that direction, and people were arguing about it".

Comment: @Goyo As far as I can tell, she wasn't demoderated for the arguments (in which most of the hurtful writing was written by those other than her) but for… some other reason.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 This was not about why she was demodded but why you think she (partially?) deserved it. Which seems to be "the way she argued her stance"

Comment: @Goyo I don't think she deserved demodding at all. You don't start suspensions at a year, and you rarely suspend without a warning. If Monica had been treated like an ordinary user… but the system didn't permit that without hurriedly modifying some very mission-critical code, and they needed to act in a timely manner, so I don't really _blame_ anyone (though I won't hesitate if this happens again!). But what happened was just messed up. I'm glad they're taking actions to mitigate the damage now, even at the expense of our taking SO seriously.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I've still not heard why this was so urgent; have you?  It'd been nine days since I'd spoken in TL and four days since my last email (I was awaiting a reply), and I was otherwise going about my business on the network as normal.  Nobody mentioned a deadline to me, and employees neither said "this thing here is a CoC violation" nor warned me they considered my actions to be diamond-threatening.  (I even *asked* Sara about that on that day -- no answer.  I thought the strongest possible outcome was that I should leave TL, which I did on my own.) Feel free to contact me privately!

Answer (score 32):

But I do hope you realize that this latest incident was just that. This action against the moderators just set off a lava flow underneath the volcanic pile. That pile includes the arbitration arrangements, the license 'change', the constant ignoring of feature requests/discussions (pressure that's been building up for years). Unless Stack Overflow begins to handle these issues in a responsible manner, it's just another eruption waiting to happen. I think you need to go back and revisit these topics. Try fixing these things at a fundamental level before letting things just build up yet again.

I appreciate some effort on your part. However, I myself will reserve all caution until I see those kind of changes happening.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that Fullerton believes that the [only thing wrong is lack of welcoming and inclusivity and other than that no plans are changing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834).

Answer (score 31):

**I appreciate this statement.**  I appreciate that you are owning the mistakes that SE staff have made and taking responsibility for them (whether you personally were involved or not).

The harm that folks who use pronouns different from those assigned to them at birth experienced is real and I applaud SE for working towards the goal of making sure that gender identity is not a barrier to participating here.

**The harm that many in the Lavender aka queer aka LGBTQ (etc.) community experienced *because of SE's actions* is also real.  Not everyone is attuned to see it and not every space on here had those comments.  But it happened.**

As a queer community member who is not trans or nonbinary, I did feel personally attacked in the aftermath of this. (Almost) no one said anything personal to me, but I felt it all the same. It was enough to send me into panic attacks and needing a leave of absence from my moderator position. The hate is real.

So thank you for acknowledging this backlash and working to fix it.

I ask here for two things:

1. **Reinstate Monica to all of her former moderator positions right away.**  Then, talk with her privately and work out whatever you feel is necessary to work out and make further changes if required later.
2. **Extend the discussion period for the CoC changes.**  We're about to go into Yom Kippur, the holiest and most time and energy intensive day of the year (sunset Oct 8th through twilight Oct 9th, with time needed on either side).  I think you made the right decision to post this now, vs. waiting until Thursday, but the timing of the discussion means a lot of us can not participate much.  These changes are important; let everyone have a chance to weigh in.  Even those without a holiday may not log in every day.

Stack Exchange means a lot to me and I've been heartbroken over the reality that I might lose this community.  I've only been here a year, but I've put a lot of time and energy into it and am now a moderator.  I care deeply about the sites I'm involved in and want nothing more than to return to them and to my fellow users.  Having Monica as my co-moderator on Writing and a moderator on other sites makes Stack Exchange a better place.

Answer (score 31):

*" ... we made a series of mistakes ... "*

Other than *"should not have done this on a Friday"* what do you think the *mistakes* were/are?

> Enumerate what **you** consider the mistakes, because, *Mistakes were
>   made, I approved them, my bad ...* is not an apology.

If you think he listed the mistakes, he did not. He listed the side effects of the mistakes. He lists *We regret ...* [non-apologies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334294/148287)!

*we hurt ...* is not really the mistake, it is the consequences or side effect of the mistake. The fact that he will not even say something like *We unfairly removed Monica's moderation status and lied about why* tells you this is a non-apology.

[It is the exact opposite of an apology, putting the word apology in the title does not make it one.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334294/148287)

Comment: Reading the paragraphs after they seem to call out the four mistakes they made.

Comment: *we hurt ...* is not really the mistake, it is the consequences or side effect of the mistake. The fact that he will not even say something like *We unfairly removed Monica's moderation status and lied about why* tells you this is a non-apology.

Comment: To be fair, acknowledging the consequences is an essential part of an apology too, and they at least got a bit of that in there.

Comment: mentioning a consequence, but not apologizing for it is just implicit doubling down on what you did requires no apology.

Answer (score 31):

> That’s enough words for the moment,
>
> Now let me see some action!
>
> While you’re handing out the compliments,
>
> You should also make things happen.
>
> Since Poetry gave the gift of creation,
>
> Take your orders then from Poetry.
>
> You know what’s wanted here,
>
> We need strong [commitment] to appear:
>
> So brew me a [plan] right away!
>
> Tomorrow won’t do what’s undone today,
>
> We shouldn’t waste a minute, so
>
> Decide what’s possible, and just
>
> Grasp it firmly like a hoe,
>
> Make sure that you let nothing go,
>
> And work it about, because you must.

– Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, [Faust](https://www.poetryintranslation.com/PITBR/German/FaustIProl.php), Part I: Prelude, lns. 214–230 (1808).

Answer (score 30):

Thank you.

This reads like you actually thought about what you wanted to say before posting.

---

Trust needs to be rebuild and you could start with the following:

> Going forward, we will be working with the community to overhaul how we gather input and feedback from our moderators **and members of the community** to make sure that your voices are heard and involved in the process, not just informed after decisions have been made.

Great.

> - On Monday, October 7, we’ll be sharing a second draft of an update to our Code of Conduct with all moderators for feedback
> - On Thursday, October 10, the update to the Code of Conduct will be announced publicly

Ah... it seems I missed the part where the **members of the community** give their feedback to the proposed changes? We did it [last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct/) so this not only an oversight this time, it's actually a **step back** from what we had. Why do you always make it so hard for yourselves?

We don't want to dictate policy, this is *your* site, you are legally responsible, *you* decide. But you would have *so much more support* if you *hear people out* and *find a compromise* instead of forcing changes down their throat.

Comment: I guess (and hope) that the public announcement is meant to be the public “request for comments” instead of the moderator-only.

Comment: Good point. But that's [not even the half of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834).

Comment: Just to document... as of Oct 10, the CoC was posted, along with a FAQ that contained the myriad actual rules.  There was no request or opportunity for community involvement.  (As opposed to the perfunctory opportunity they granted the mods.)  It was a fait d'accompli.

Answer (score 30):

**This should be signed by the CEO.**

While this is an interesting development, I cannot help be skeptical about a post about a serious crisis that is **not** from the CEO.

With all due respect to David Fullerton, you are the CTO and while you certainly have a responsibility to deal with this issue, a statement from the CEO, clear and unequivocal, stating that the company screwed up, regrets it and will make it right would be a lot simpler and less open to more ambiguity that a statement about intentions and futures with no actual commitment to immediate action.  The company was intending to modify the CoC anyway (asking and taking advice would be better that forcing, of course), so that really doesn't count.

This is not a time for a CEO to try and keep their hands clean, but a time for them to show leadership.  There is no evidence that this is happening.  Caesar was not respected by his soldiers for staying out of the battle, but for appearing right in the middle of the fighting when it reached a crisis, leading from the front, not the back.

The suspicion is that, by not personally engaging, the CEO is demonstrating that they do not care about the community and see it as something they need have no contact with.  This, I feel, is a key issue - engagement by the company with the community must be committed to at all levels.

**EDIT 1**

As "Mad Scientist" (love that name - envy :-) ) points out the CEO joined mid-debacle.  Nonetheless, the current CEO does, IMO, need to touch base with the members (who write the material the site lives on - we're suppliers!) to confirm the direction is really coming from the top, not, as it were, from the middle.

I am, BTW, **not** of the personal belief that management heads are the heads that need to go. AFAIK, these people have served the site and community well to date (as did Monica). I want the root cause addressed, not those in the system that were (IMO) manipulated to achieve a political goals of a small number of individuals. It's certainly a sensitive issue that kicked this off, but how in the name of all sanity did that get escalated to removing someone who has served us so well? I do not believe in accidents without causes is the way I would would sum it up, and I think out of control political agendas are the cause - something that should never be a part of SE, but were put ahead of the health of the community this time.

No group were responsible, but I think a small number of selfish individuals were.  That's my impression from the evidence and my gut instinct from my life experience.

Some small number of people created this trouble for their own purposes and hurt the community.  I'm a simple person who likes simple solutions: those people are a cancer and need to go.  Others will differ in opinion and I respect your viewpoints.

**Monica Cellio - victimized and deserves justice.**

As with most people I am *appalled* (as should the company's lawyers be) by the disgusting public attacks on Monica Cellio.  To my mind the CEO must address this issue directly and promptly.

It is my feeling, and I doubt I am alone in this, that those who drove this action to oust Monica Cellio for their own political ends should be dealt with in kind.  Saying "sorry" without punishing the guilty is saying "sorry we were caught".  Only if the perpetrators of this are dealt with will the company be making a statement that it actually means its words.

Monica's reinstatement should be automatic, as should a public apology in the same press you attacked her in.  Why delay this?

Heads, in short, should roll.  I incline, after reading as much as I can about the development of Monica's removal, that there exists a clique within the company and community who drove this action for political reasons of their own.  I hope it is a small clique.  Those are the heads that need to do the rolling, IMO.

I'm not sure if Monica would want heads to roll, maybe not, but I'm pretty sure I am expressing a view held by many.

I am not asking for the removal of David Fullerton, Sara Chipps or Tim Post.  I do not have enough information to make a call on who, precisely, drove this car off the road, but someone did.  I am concerned there is an issue with a small minority of individuals who created and pushed this issue, not with the people they pushed (who probably should have known better, but I'm not perfect either).

Comment: The CEO changed in the middle of this, and the current CEO wasn't in the company when the original events happened.

Comment: "there exists a clique within the company and community who drove this action for political reasons of their own... [t]hose are the heads that need to do the rolling" - No. No heads need to be rolling. There is no "clique". There are people who have concerns, and raised them. Do *not* go around accusing them of malice for how SE mishandled the situation.

Comment: @user58 You call it how you see it, I call it how I see it.  "Raising concerns", IMO, should not have an endgame of getting people kicked out.  SE mishandled, but (IMO) they (and I don't have any particular people in mind - not enough detail released) forced this issue along.  You clearly disagree with that viewpoint, which is your right and I respect that.

Comment: @user58: The people who have concerns and raised them, and the people who fired Monica Cellio and who run SE Inc. are really not the same people.

Answer (score 28):

Being 'inclusive' should not be used to EXCLUDE others' rights! Nevertheless, SE, SO, etc should be used to share ideas and NOT a political platform.

I am 53 years old and have seen it all... I am going to guess that SE/SO has a new 'investor'.

I believe there should be a full disclosure (disclaimer) of who is funding SO/SE,etc, if at all. If there is one already please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I [have a few thoughts](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6733/30) about inclusion/exclusion and SE's choice to use their platform for activism. This apology is great as far as it goes and it's nice to see at least an first attempt to take ownership of the scenario, but it doesn't even touch on the core issue and I don't think it represents any change in overall direction. Better mod handling policies? Probably. Rooting out why this became an issue in the first place? Not so much.

Comment: It's not about pushing a political agenda, but answering to users who felt diminished because of their gender/sexual orientation.

Comment: How about this: https://ca.yahoo.com/news/hundreds-young-trans-people-seeking-help-return-original-001600553.html

Comment: The investor information is public. E.g. *["...backed by investors that include Andreessen Horowitz, Founder Collective, Index Ventures, Spark Capital, and Union Square Ventures"](https://www.alleywatch.com/profile/stack-overflow/)*. I would be surprised if there was any change before [the IPO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=15m57s).

Comment: It should probably be qualified with *main* investors (on the board of directors, with some real power ("influence")), as there may or may not be smaller insignificant private investors.

Comment: @IEatBagels who are the ones pushing a political agenda? After all, on SO the whole concept of your sexuality or gender is truly irrelevant and unwanted with regards to answers. I think the same applies ot the majority of sites here, except suddenly it appears to be very important to know who's LGBT and what they expect to be called. Just be respectful of others (all others, even Trump supporters), that's all that's needed.

Comment: @gbjbaanb "Just be respectful of others". Yes, seems simple enough right. But if some users are **telling you** they don't feel respected, something should be done about it, no?

Comment: @IEatBagels not necessarily some people will tell you what they think will further their cause without evidence. There needs to be a bit more than comments like "I feel personally attacked" - they may well do so, but if there is no evidence of that occurring, then its little more than emotional manipulation. To change the way the site works, there has to be some objectivity involved, feeelings are too easily led.

Answer (score 26):

This is a very good letter and appears to be sincere.  It's appreciated.

Much is still unknown, so I will wait to see results, but just an observation: the letter seems like SE may be doubling down on some significant issues that were simmering prior to recent events, and which fed the chaos.

- The network and its reputation were built on quality posts.  Certainly, we want new posters to feel welcome to the extent possible.  But making everyone feel welcome has been done at the expense of quality.  The ratio of good content to noise has degraded, heading in a direction where finding good content here will become too inefficient to support the network's reputation.  This has also led to losing and burning out experienced users and subject matter experts, reducing the network's ability to build quality content.  Making people feel welcome can't be the primary goal, as seems to be implied in the letter.  The issue of returning to a quality and meritocracy focus is one that's been raised for years that still seems to be taking a back seat to the feel-good objective.
- All users need to be treated with respect, and the new CoC includes specific focus on one group of users who have expressed that there is a problem getting that respect here.  The letter describes an intention to implement the new CoC after getting some feedback.  Nobody is against including language in the CoC to better address such issues.  But what was described some weeks ago had serious implementation issues that offered protection to one group at the cost of offense, hostility, even violation of religious principles, for other groups.  There is even a question about whether any form of personal matter should have a place in the purely technical sites.  I hope that the corporate objective for the new CoC is to ensure that it is something everyone can endorse.
- In addition, the letter talks about the process and the style by which Monica was fired, but it doesn't address the reason, which leaves moderators vulnerable.  Nobody seems to be aware of any action by Monica that should have triggered any consideration of her being fired in the first place.  That is something that needs to be honestly addressed, at least with the moderators.

It isn't my intention to downplay the importance of any issues or to rain on the parade.  Understandably, everything can't be fixed at once.  My concern is that the fixes may enshrine long-standing issues, pushing away more of the network's talent.  I hope I'm concerned about nothing.

Comment: Your bit about the meritocracy got my upvote. The main thing that attracted me to SE in the first place was how we didn't have to sift though so much chaff to get to a kernel of wheat. So yes, we need to remain polite, civil, and welcoming – but not at the expense of quality.

Answer (score 26):

<strike>Thankyou David for this genuine apology. It was sorely needed.</strike>
[Update 23 Oct 2019: This "apology" turns out to be a well-worded PR stunt: there's no admission of error in removing Monica, the second blockquote below has not been honoured, and Monica has not been reinstated. I withdraw my praise, and I've downvoted your post.]

***And thankyou to all the diamond mods and other users who took a principled and caring stand, without which this apology would not have appeared.***

> Third, we hurt the moderators and members of our communities. Community moderation is the backbone of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, and our moderators are a vital part of us creating a more welcoming and inclusive place.

This acknowledgement is, appropriately, listed third in order of importance, but I'm glad it's been said. Our diamond mods certainly do the heavy lifting, but I'm one of the *thousands* of regular non-diamond users who contribute our time and effort in helping keep SE running. Flagging spam, abuse and CoC violations; voting on review queues to close bad questions, delete non-answers, approve suggested edits, and reopen worthwhile questions; editing posts to improve them; adding comments to provide useful guidance (and a positive welcoming message) to new contributors; putting thought into site management and improvement, via site meta; and doing many more generally unnoticed little things that keep our favourite sites humming along.

I have been "on strike" since last week, withdrawing from all the community moderation tasks I would normally do on the four sites I'm most active on. I'm on strike both as the best statement of support that I could give to Monica and to the mods who had resigned or taken other action, and as a response to my own feelings of discouragement and vicarious abuse as a SE volunteer.

Your apology is a significant first step *towards* rebuilding my trust, but I need more than words: owning your mistakes is necessary but not sufficient. There are important **actions** you need to take, some of which I expect to happen urgently - your direct communication with Monica being one.

I'm hoping these actions over the next few weeks will be enough to demonstrate to people like me that **there really is** a genuine intention by the company to improve its game and to treat our community with real respect. I am, cautiously, looking forward to ending my strike action and returning to "normal duties" in community moderation. But you need to entice me back, and if you don't do so quickly and decisively, there's a real risk that I won't come back at all.

It's important for you to know this, not because I'm a key user, but because there are dozens - perhaps hundreds - of other users like me: passionate about our SE community, deeply disillusioned with the company, and on the verge of walking away.

> Going forward, we will be working with the community to overhaul how we gather input and feedback from our moderators and members of the community to make sure that your voices are heard and involved in the process, not just informed after decisions have been made.

A key test will be the new CoC. Will you involve us ordinary users in reviewing the draft, or will you simply inform us of the new rules we must abide by "after decisions have been made"?

I desperately hope we can take you at your word.
[Update 23 Oct 2019: it turns out that David's words were as empty as the company's ethics. The new CoC was imposed on us with no opportunity for broad community input, the farcical implementation has further alienated the SO/SE community and, most ironic and concerning of all, the process has created even greater difficulties for many of the diverse users the new CoC was supposed to protect.]

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, I get it: the new COC and the way it's been implemented might be cause to reconsider how I voted on this post, and the edit allows me to change my vote. Yes. Thankyou.

Answer (score 24):

> First of all, we hurt members of our LGBTQ+ community when they felt they couldn’t participate authentically and we didn’t respond quickly or strongly enough in supporting them.

No, First of all apologize to Monica. You harmed her first - apologize to her first. Don't pretend to "care" about the LGBT community and whistle to them first, showing "look how woke I am - I apologized first to you, and only then to Monica." No. Apologize to Monica first. Then to any others you have harmed.

It's easy to apologize to a community - there's no personal responsibility involved. Apologizing to a specific person is harder.

Comment: Aza left (and posted about LGBT+ moderators feeling unwelcome) before Monica was de-modded, so I don't think there's a clear-cut case that SO "harmed her first". @jwenting that is an incredibly uncharitable hyperbole.

Answer (score 22):

This entire post can be paraphrased as *Mistakes were made, I approved them, my bad ...* which is a **non-apology**.

Unless you specifically list what you think was done wrong and actually take action to re-mediate those wrongs and explain how they will be avoided in the future this is just more gas lighting marketing speak get back to the salt mines nothing to see here non-apology.

Answer (score 22):

I just got an email from Gitlab and thought it is pretty much a excellent PR template for the situation SE has ended up in.  Their response:

- is timely (reversal - 1 day, response - 7 days),
- the tone is much more respectful,
- the actions (particularly "we reversed course the next day" and encouraging collaboration) far more clearly describe both the thinking, reflection, and new plan to include *more* people in the decision, and
- communicates directly with the user base, rather than waiting for them to find our/back down/disappear.

I have removed context so you can fill it in in your head. :-)

**This is probably copyrighted but the email was not marked as private or confidential.  Nevertheless, I have duplicated it here for educational purposes only.**

> Dear [platform-name] users and customers,
>
> On [date of incident], we [describe action]. Based on considerable
>   feedback from our customers, users, and the broader community, we
>   reversed course the next day and removed those changes before they
>   went into effect. Further, [company] will commit to not [negative
>   action]. This clearly struck a nerve with our community and I
>   apologize for this mistake.
>
> So, what happened? In an effort to [describe intended positive
>   outcome], we decided to [describe intended action]. Clearly, our
>   evaluation and communication processes for rolling out a change like
>   this were lacking and we need to improve those processes. But that’s
>   not the main thing we did wrong.
>
> Our main mistake was that we did not live up to our own core value of
>   collaboration by including our users, contributors, and customers in
>   the strategy discussion and, for that, I am truly sorry. It shouldn’t
>   have surprised us that you have strong feelings about [proposal] and
>   many other topics, and we should have listened first.
>
> So, where do we go from here? The first step is a retrospective that
>   is happening on [date] to document what went wrong. We are reaching
>   out to customers who expressed concerns and collecting feedback from
>   users and the wider community. We will put together a new proposal for
>   improving the user experience and share it for feedback. We made a
>   mistake by not collaborating, so now we will take as much time as
>   needed to make sure we get this right. You can be part of the
>   collaboration by [reference for forum/chat/meta-article]. If you are a
>   customer, you may also reach out to your [company] representative if
>   you have additional feedback.
>
> I am glad you hold [company] to a higher standard. If we are going to
>   be transparent and collaborative, we need to do it consistently and
>   learn from our mistakes.
>
> Sincerely, [name] [title] [company]

Answer (score 21):

I'm so glad you said all this. [Looks like George's sample response was not all that farfetched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334263/404278). This is a complete and thorough that I'm taking to heart. I'm going to give you all the benefit of the doubt and assume this is sincere.

Thanks again. We needed this. In short, this is a godsend.

---

## Edit

I have to admit, this doesn't sit right. It seems suspicious that you posted this reply days after it should have been posted. It almost seems like Sara's post was something you're trying to cover up with this apology.

I'm not saying this isn't sincere - something is very wrong and I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: They can't cover up Sara's behavior; too many people saw, publicized, and downloaded it.  I assume it will be a topic of internal discussion and post-mortem at SE.  It is reasonable for a company that has made such a profound blunder to focus on next steps; it's not a coverup.

Comment: What's "suspicious" about it? They took their time to write a _proper_ apology. The time they sadly didn't take at the start of all this. I'd call that an improvement, instead of "suspicious".

Comment: This is two answers in one, and they are like _completely_ different from each other lol. Anyway is it possible that what your spidey senses are detecting is _emergency damage control_?

Comment: @connectyourcharger [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334596/176101) was the only thing left eating me. It took me a bit to identify it too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit - The whole thing reeks of damage control, literally cribbed from *Bumper Big Book of Managing Angry Peons*. The Non-Apology-Apology didn't work so now it's the Heartfelt-We-Share-Your-Pain-No-Really apology. Followed by bugger all action.

Comment: @Richard Or it's a genuine mea culpa following a realisation of the gravity of the situation. We'll see. Being vindictive about it won't help though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit - A couple of days ago the very same people were 'comfortable about their decision'. I see no reason to assume that they've had a conversion on the road to Damascus so the reason for this gubbins must simply be expectation management

Comment: I've [tried to put my finger on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834) - please consider whether that hits the spot.

Comment: this is a non-apology, to paraphrase it, *Mistakes were made, my bad ...* ... there is no acknowledgement of what was actually a mistake, other than *wish we did not do this on friday* ...

Answer (score 19):

A lot of folks have answered, and I apologise if I covered the same ground.

I saw this this morning, right after I woke up, and well, after having a lot to say, I had no idea what to.

It's a start. There's so much work to be done.

This has always been about doing right by one of our own. Monica's gone through a lot and I hope SE makes it right.

I do realise there's an idea that folks on meta - and not just this one - are troublemakers and miscreants. That we're the loud 0.1%. We're also folks that care about this place.

Also, it's been a long bumpy road. I hope the relationship between the folk who run the site and and all of us gets on the road to being mended. And that the message sent is well - even if y'all are the landlords, this isn't just any place - it's *home* and we care about it.

It's worth recognizing that there's folks who worked in this in the background - community members and staff (and a few folks who're both). I'm sorry I can't name all of you - there's a lot of you, and honestly, it's been a complete and utter period of productive chaos once folks got in gear.

Hopefully we can work out ways that we can work together and try to stop stuff like this going out of control.

Let's get the gang back together.

Comment: You do realize that Fullerton essentially [stated there's no reinstatement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834), right?

Answer (score 16):

Thank you, albeit: the journey hasn't even started. And of course, one wonders, what took you so long? Is it truly the outcry in the community that caused this move, or rather the damage to the **public** reputation/image of the company?! But I am not here to rant.

As all the other answers, and so many other postings here, and on other META sites have reminded us: the rift goes deep, and it grew over years. Every time *the company* made mistakes and just moved on, ignoring the breakage that decision created, every time, that rift grew deeper.

When we honestly look at the situation, there are easily 30, 50 "work items" that worry many members of the different communities.

Thus: that schedule about CoC updates and next steps: **give us more like that**.

Meaning:

1. I am asking *the company* to compile a list of "work items" that they think need to be addressed (MSE should give you *plenty* of inspirational input).
2. Then they should put up some kind of **poll** that allows to the community to give **its** priorities on these points.
3. Then align that input with the business plans and come up with an outlook/schedule when and how each "work item" will be addressed.
4. Every quarter or so, repeat that exercise.

**Walk the talk. Now. And for the months to come!**

And sure, that is a lot of work. But we will be with you, as long as we can *trust* you that you are with us.

Edit: oh, how easy it is to walk back.

> We didn't solicit feedback from the wider community on this change. We have a robust roadmap and we are selective in asking the community for feedback on specific releases.

That is the exact attitude everybody here is complaining about, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338239/285661) for context.

**You really still didn't get it.**

Comment: The journey hasn't even started because [they're not changing what they planned to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834). It's just flowery rhetoric.

Comment: @einpoklum I agree. Maybe my point is more like: I dont care that much any more what "they" do. I made up my mind what is important for me, and this answer here just expresses what I **hope and wish** will happen. I didn't say I consider this hope very realistic.

Answer (score 15):

First of all, thank you so much for this apology, it means a lot.

Second of all, could you share how things got as bad as they did? Was the team under a lot of stress that caused them to act a little more abrasive than they otherwise would have? Was this triggered by a "bad apple" who has since been removed? Did you get poor advice from a consultant that told you to do what you did? I'm not asking in order to bash or criticize, but to get some understanding into not only what a long-term solution might be, but how other organizations can avoid getting into this kind of mess at all.

Comment: Without specifics (ie evidence), this would just be more unsubstantiated claims. Specifically, *excuses*. We deserve reasons (the root of which is "reason", as in, "reasonable").

Comment: Why does the apology mean a lot to you when Fullerton says [they won't undo any of the things they're supposedly apologizing for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834)?

Answer (score 14):

Your post is like a breath of fresh air compared to what I've recently seen posted by the company here. As many others have already stated, thank you. Among the other answers, there are many questions, comments & suggestions expressed about various aspects stated in, or omitted from, your post, but I will mainly discuss the timing you provided of the CoC related changes, i.e.,

> - On Monday, October 7, we’ll be sharing a second draft of an update to our Code of Conduct with all moderators for feedback
> - On Thursday, October 10, the update to the Code of Conduct will be announced publicly
> - By Friday, October 11, we’ll share the processes for moderator removal and reinstatement with moderators for their feedback

As a non-moderator myself, who has been a member for just under a year, and who has only now mostly during the past week or so tried to catch up with what has been going on here & in the past, I don't know how realistic those timelines are. Nonetheless, I don't believe there's any hard & fast deadlines to complete any step in the process, so I suggest it's better to do it right rather than on time. If you find any step is taking more time than you expected, please adjust the schedule accordingly and let us know. As long as the process doesn't drag out for too long a time & you don't provide too many updates that don't pan out, I at least, and I trust most of the community, would appreciate the updates and the extra care to try to make good decisions.

Also, your words are a great start, and I hope they're also backed up with appropriate actions. If so, it'll help start building back trust from the community with the company. Also, I hope the company has begun to make a significant change in how they will deal with us, so there will in the future be increased communication and more transparency from the company, listening to & taking into account our feedback, and making appropriate adjustments as required, similar to what is requested in [A general call for increased transparency from Stack Exchange, Incꓸ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334134/a-general-call-for-increased-transparency-from-stack-exchange-inc%ea%93%b8).

I sincerely believe that by working together, we can continue to make the SE sites places where members will generally always feel welcome, be happy to participate and feel they are part of a community they want be involved with; the general public can continue to ask and/or find excellent questions and answers to solve their needs; and the company will prosper, both financially as well as with the good will from the members and the general public.

Answer (score 14):

Ok. Thanks for the apology. I'm not too sentimental like that, so I wasn't seeking it in the first place. All I really wanted from SE was a clear explanation with examples why you fired Monica. In this post, you say you'll only do that if you *both* agree? That's not reasonable. The only circumstance where keeping that information private would be if Monica admits fault and concedes her removal was just. Monica is equivalent to a public figure on SE. We deserve answers.

Comment: Think you misread: "unless both agree" only refers to future actions? / Moreover: Firing was 'shipping' a mod-removal. Violating the existing processes and expectations, and now admitted as 'mistakes'. Fine. In a working version-control system, one rolls back (posts on SE have that very feature). As firing was a fruit of the forbidden tree: why not reinstate M 'immediately?' That's what I wonder about. I only see that SE sees that as waste of time, as they still want "to stand by that decision"?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Why not immediately? Because they apparently *did* already consider firing her, now they agree to review that decision. That puts Monica somewhere in the process. [More thoughts on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps/334604#comment1096072_334604).

Comment: @fredsbend: But they considered firing her on what is apparently false cause. And got outed about it. And _still_ double down on the termination.

Comment: @fredsbend: Would appreciate your thoughts on my [own reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834).

Answer (score 14):

This is a peculiar flavored [mashup](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mashup) of [sidestepping](https://www.freethesaurus.com/sidestepping), [backpedaling](https://www.freethesaurus.com/backpedaling) and [extenuation](https://www.freethesaurus.com/extenuation).

Like seeing someone take a chug of a beer they find after a party, and it's full of butts.

Think, do, own it. When you get the order wrong it doesn't work.

Consider the impact of your actions and how they affect everyone. You can't fix some things by doing one thing or another; that applies before, during and after.

It is sometimes amazing what can be learned from another, and sometimes amazing what one forgets about their own.

Source: "[Learning Curves | Recognizing a Race-Friendly Dyno Graph](https://dsportmag.com/the-tech/learning-curves-recognizing-a-race-friendly-dyno-graph/)":

> "Getting In Shape
> A good percentage of the very-best engineers, racecar builders and engine tuners understand and use dyno graphs as outlined to improve a vehicle’s performance. However, there are a select few racecar and engine tuners that focus on the shape of the dyno curve to optimize controllability, traction and suspension stability.  Why should this be important to you? When you shift gears and it upsets tire grip, you get passed—if you are lucky. If unluckly, the loss of traction can result in a crash. Likewise, when you feed in throttle to launch your drag car or attempt to accelerate off a corner only to spin the tires, the finish line just got a lot closer, for the competition that just passed you. As the sample dyno charts will demonstrate, the shape and length of the power curve beyond peak horsepower plays a significant roll.".

Source: "[Racing Line](https://drivingfast.net/racing-line/)":

> "Introduction
>
> The racing line line depends on the following factors: braking point, turn in point, apex, and the position and direction of the next corner.
>
> It is important to remember that there is rarely a perfect line through any corner for all circumstances. It depends on the characteristics of your car, your cornering strategy and the conditions. If you’re racing, you may also have to react to the position of other cars on the track. You should experiment with different lines and learn from instructors and the people who know the track best.".

See how similar information and situations read differently. It's not just applying what you know but knowing how it is applied and what the result will be.

If you can't apply what you already know to various situations successfully then you either need to learn to do that, learn more, or learn to leave things alone.

Answer (score 14):

It seems to me that you brought this whole thing on yourselves.

This is a **technical** Q&A site, whose *bread and butter* is highly technical questions ranging from C-language rounding to server-farm emergency backup generators.  **Gender issues are highly unlikely to arise**.

Frankly, this site is positioned to unite everyone who does tech.

So why is SE, as a company, publicly making a spectacle of themselves *on gender identity* issues?

I've noticed SE has a very small minority of stacks of a very different nature - Interpersonal Skills, Parenting, and a few religious stacks. **These** are the sites where gender issues come up, and I'm particularly looking at Interpersonal Skills stack, because that seems to be a lightning rod for all sorts of things.  Take the Twitter debacle earlier, **which was fundamentally about SE's core/base customers considering the content to be out-of-place on this platform**.

The sway is mystifying: these sites (and their advocates) seem to be the "600 pound gorilla" of SE -- the company reacts emotionally, *even irrationally*, to anything that would threaten the status-quo of these particular stacks. It's almost as if an owner said "these sites must succeed at the expense of all else; I'll stake my company on it".

Coz that seems to be happening.

For SE to dig in their heels and say "We want to die on this hill", doesn't make much sense.

How about instead of dividing the community *over stacks that aren't even a good fit for the platform*... divide the platform!  Divest the troublesome stacks. Spin them off to someone who actually wants to be in the **social** Q&A business, which is a very different business than the technical Q&A business. That would basically make gender issues irrelevant at Stack Exchange.

I'm not saying StackExchange shouldn't care about gender issues, but maybe employees and investors who care about that should do their politicking at a personal level instead of embroiling the company.

Comment: Funny thing is these sites handle it gracefully. A lot of this is an attempt to get greater inclusiveness on SO. The twitter debacle itself was due to someone on SO taking offence to a HNQ.  On the other hand, divesting the smaller sites might be something some people want - simply cause they can't see past SO.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that SE have appointed one or two zealots to key positions over the past year or two, and now they're either not being reigned in, or the whole company is drinking the same kool aid.

Comment: _This is a technical Q&A site, whose bread and butter is highly technical questions ranging from C-language rounding to server-farm emergency backup generators._ No, that is wrong. You can say that most of the trafic is generated by the "technical" sites, but there are also of other sites where gender issues _might_ be a problem. So the main problem here is, that SE Inc. didn't communicate that well, they never told us that these problems arose not from SO, SF, SU, AskU... but from other sites (I don't care which!). To sum it up: **The communication of SE Inc is still severely broken!**

Answer (score 13):

Thank you for for your apology! It is much appreciated.

For me, the most important part is:

> I am more committed than ever to creating a welcoming and **inclusive community** across Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, and the mistakes we made over the past few weeks made that worse, not better. **I know we have lost the trust of many of you, and that trust must be re-earned over time by more than just words**.
>   <sub>by [David Fullerton](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/292385), emphasis mine</sub>

I want to say *Let's forget it*, but currently I can't. But with the above statement it seems I can in future.

I say this, because in the past you often said sorry, promised improvements, but forgot it a few month later. Just make sure you remember this statement in a year. And ten.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

> - On Monday, October 7, we’ll be sharing a second draft of an update to    our Code of Conduct with all moderators for feedback
> - On Thursday, October 10, the update to the Code of Conduct will be announced    publicly
> - By Friday, October 11, we’ll share the processes for    moderator removal and reinstatement with moderators for their    feedback

This seems like a poorly chosen order - the code of conduct should be reviewed by the moderators (including reinstated ones) before being enacted. How can that happen if the reinstatement is last?

Comment: The COC changes triggered off all of it. And honestly, looking at all this drama, I think the mods need some time to decompress. I know I do

Comment: Actually, I think this is the proper order, allowing mods to see the new CoC before having to decide whether to seek reinstatement.

Comment: @fredsbend Actually, an *elected* (as opposed to appointed, which happens on beta sites) moderator who has stepped down in good standing can request to have their moderator position reinstated. To allow that has been the policy of SE for a very long time. Moderators step down from time to time for a variety of reasons, far from all of them in protest of any action taken by SE. Stepping down is not a rage-quit. Also, nothing prevents a moderator who stepped down in good standing from a position as appointed on a beta site from running in a moderator election on that same site at a later time.

Comment: My issue is not with the *order* but the *duration.* There's no way that SO.Inc can incorporate feedback over a 3-4 day period.

Comment: Who said they're reinstating anyone?

Comment: I guess I assumed they would be reinstating moderators that were removed or that left voluntarily based on the fact that they are planning an official reinstatement process.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Non-reinstated ex-mods likely won't be able to see the new CoC revision to inform that decision.  There's no sign yet of reinstatements coming.  Also, it's unlikely that they are actually looking for any disagreement feedback or questions, because you can see what they did to Monica for asking questions, and they are mostly standing by that so far.

Answer (score 12):

> Every time I look at you I don't understand
>
> Why you let the things you did get so out of hand.
>
> You'd have managed better if you'd had it planned.
>
> Why'd you choose [a delay in] time [with] such a [bad hand]?

– Andrew Lloyd Webber, Tim Rice, [Jesus Christ Superstar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8piH8k-Ngh4) ([1970](http://www.metrolyrics.com/superstar-lyrics-jesus-christ-superstar.html))

Answer (score 11):

This response is long-awaited... But it feels heartfelt and meaningful.

As just another Stack Exchange community member: Thank you.

I'm certain I speak for many members when I say that I'm satisfied knowing that this event is being taken seriously, and my faith in Stack Exchange is starting to become restored.

In the future... I hope that it doesn't take this long to address an uproar of this magnitude. However, I think we should focus on forward movement with regards to the past.

I still hope SE becomes more [transparent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334134/a-general-call-for-increased-transparency-from-stack-exchange-inc%ea%93%b8), but that's a conversation for a different location, and a different time.

> By Friday, October 11, we’ll share the processes for moderator removal and reinstatement with moderators for their feedback

**Is there going to be any specific focus on the most recent moderator walkouts? Will those moderators be contacted privately to discuss possible reinstatement, assuming they're interested? If so, can you elaborate?**

Comment: "Will those moderators be contacted privately to discuss possible reinstatement, assuming they're interested? If so, can you elaborate?" - This is just speculation on my part, but assuming SE handles it like they handled the situation on the Workplace, it'll likely be up to the mods to request reinstatement, but SE will probably reinstate them if they do request it.

Comment: Would you mind bolding the whole last paragraph, please?

Comment: @aparente001 Good idea. Edited that.

Comment: You've been misled. It might feel nice, but it's [mostly a nothing-burger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834). Specifically - there is no reinstatement.

Comment: @einpoklum that's not true, moderators who did ask to be reinstated have been, the door is open.

Comment: @Tensibai: That's not what I meant. I was talking about a reinstatement through a nullification of the invalid dismissal - not a "kiss the ring" reinstatement upon penitent request.

Comment: @einpoklum I've no will to be reinstated. So that's doesn't sound a good idea  from my point of view.

Comment: @Tensibai: Fair enough, but Monica Cellio is who we're talking about here.

Comment: @einpoklum your comment doesn't sound talking about Monica specifically, specially not when the answer talk about the moderators who walked away. I can understand you think your answer address this, but it does not imho

Comment: you have drunk the kool-aid ...

Answer (score 11):

I am pleased to see this message from the CTO of Stack Overflow; it goes a long way toward correcting things. However, while what has been done so far is necessary, it is not sufficient.

It is critical to realize that certain important decisions should not be rushed, even if one has good intentions. I have to second what others have said that the moderators should have more time to review and respond to the new CoC before it is published. Another week would not be an excessive amount of time and would far better provide adequate time to respond and for any needed changes to be made before the new CoC is made public.

After publicly naming Monica as having been fired they need to publicly post a retraction and apology.

There have been several other issues, besides Monica's firing, that have upset the community, and rightly so. These other issues also need to be addressed.

Although Stack Overflow has made some reassuring statements, which certainly are good steps toward correcting their errors, we will have to see what they actually do over the coming weeks. It is their actions, not just words, that will show their true intentions.

EDIT:
I tend to be optimistic and willing to give people the benefit of the doubt. So when the CTO of Stack Overflow posted a better sounding apology with a promise of improvements to come I was hopeful and willing to wait and see what happened. It has been a month with no really substantial improvements in the numerous issues affecting these sites: [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper?noredirect=1&lq=1)
Therefore I must add my voice to others expressing their dissatisfaction with Stack Exchange. As shown in the link above there are a number of issues; there seems to be little that the average user can do, but this link has ideas on what can be done to help address one issue: [How can we help Monica Cellio?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337097/how-can-we-help-monica-cellio?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 8):

> On Monday, October 7, we’ll be sharing a second draft of an update to
> our Code of Conduct with all moderators for feedback
>
> On Thursday, October 10, the update to the Code of Conduct will be
> announced publicly

This is great, **really**.  Coming from one of the Moderator's who resigned, and then changed his mind and came back -- before this was issued BTW.  I do believe this should go a long was to prevent future events like this.

> I’m responsible for that, and I’m sorry. We’ll be reaching out to her
> directly to apologize for the lack of process, privacy, and to discuss
> next steps. We’ll keep those discussions completely private unless we
> both agree to share any of it with the community.

This is as much as you could ask for at the moment, and took a ton of courage to post.  Admitting, apologizing, owning, and attempting to rectify.  This make me very hopeful that our big community will survive and thrive.

*I do believe there is a road back for Monica* as I still believe her heart is **always** in the right place, and I hope that path back is acceptable to **all** involved.

Comment: I may not fully agree with you (the jury will be out for a while yet on any attempts to rectify), but this post lives up to the moniker it is posted under!

Comment: @Caleb I don't know for sure, but I feel as though SE will try to smooth this over with Monica. She used her real name here and her reputation suffered a hit when this all went down.

Comment: "This is as much as you could ask for at the moment, and took a ton of courage to post." I can't agree with that. They even went as far to have an SE employee speak to a [media outlet](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/) to name and shame Monica ("Cellio (she/her) would not use stated pronouns, which violates our current CoC."). This is at best hinted at ("privacy"). The accusation was made public, the apology (once they actually reach out to Monica) will be private ("unless we both agree to share any of it"). It's a step forward, but only a small one.

Comment: How is this "great"? It's the same thing they were going to do before this apology post. It's [we're sorry, but nothing changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334665/196834) kind of a thing.

Comment: @AnneDaunted based on my past experience this is a great step forward.  With a C level responding to this, I hold out hope for a resolution.

Comment: @einpoklum Time will tell.

Comment: It's been a week since we last heard anything official from SE. I think time told. I guess they're waiting it out till people accept that the old SE is dead, long live the new SE, and the ones who can't get cozy with the new one leave.

Answer (score 5):

"make it an even more welcoming and inclusive place"

Unless you are CIS Gendered, Heteronomative and Socially and Politically Conservative. Then, you can go pound sand.

(Or find an alternative that is welcoming and inclusive to those people groups.)

I understand the need to find some middle ground, but the ground chosen by SE is so far to the LGBTQ+ side that Monica was basically removed for a thought crime and the rest of us better get in line RIGHT NOW!

Comment: Did you see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334577/334566 ? Most LGBTQ+ people here were not happy about what happened with Monica or how the CoC changes were rolled out.

Answer (score 4):

Hey David and Stack Overflow,

This is a good step and thank you for this. It is great to see you acknowledge where you went wrong and what process you're going to work on to fix this.

One thing I've been trying to mention in posts but haven't seen addressed is **getting proper training** for your volunteer moderators.

There are courses in non-violent communication, conflict management and other areas of moderation you can pay for.

I think you are being unkind towards yourselves when you don't train moderators at all and then expect them to endure the empathy fatigue community moderation involves while behaving in a welcoming empathic way.

I think you can benefit from actually investing in moderators and community members. Issues like dealing with people from different cultures are not something people are born with.

Comment: Which side of this was looking for a way to co-exist in spite of disagreement in the first place? Which side kept actively reaching out for a resolution after it went sideways? I don't doubt training is something volunteer moderators could benefit from, but this is suggesting a solution to the wrong problem.

Comment: @Caleb both sides were reaching out for resolution after it went sideways and both sides could benefit from better communication and conflict resolution tools. Both sides were side of the conflict and both could benefit from said training.

Comment: We must have very different versions of what qualifies as "reaching out". Even the still active moderators have been protesting in droves for weeks now over the lack of reaching out or any serious engagement of the issues from SE's side.

Comment: In this particular matter, IMHO, it seems like SE staff should get those trainings you mentioned. I feel from this answer it somehow illustrates that moderator(s) are the guilty party in this occasion.

Comment: @Vishwa to be clear, I do not believe that moderators are the "guilty" party in this occasion. I believe that Stack Overflow needs to invest a lot more into their moderators and how seriously they take the content quality and inclusiveness on this network.

Comment: The bigger elephant in the room is yet SE being very lax on drive-by-users creation to inflate user numbers. This is being clearly abused by droves of people who do not agree and do not want to follow SE rules and policies, who do not need to be nice to moderators or longtime users, who just want a quick fix and do not want and need to invest on quality content. And that is undermining things much more than dealing with "different cultures". IMO, that ought to be dealt much sooner than "proper training". While that is not dealt with, I would not want to be on any moderator' s shoes.

Comment: Where is the actual "good step"? It doesn't look like they're planning to do something concretely different than before.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum if that's what you mean, you should say it clearly I think. you said *One thing I've been trying to mention in posts but haven't seen addressed is getting proper training for your volunteer moderators.*. Matter at hand occurs basically because the SE staff has no such training, discipline nor integrity. (not all). I agree that SE needs to invest more in **not only** moderators but all contributors alike.